# How to parse a string to an int in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing

What's the C++ way of parsing a string (given as char *) into an int? Robust and clear error handling is a plus (instead of [returning zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)).

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx They are very efficient and somewhat elegant

Comment: @Beh Tou Cheh, if you think it's a good way to parse int, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Same for C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c

Answer (score 183, accepted):

In the new C++11 there are functions for that: stoi, stol, stoll, stoul and so on.

```
int myNr = std::stoi(myString);
```

It will throw an exception on conversion error.

Even these new functions still have the **same issue** as noted by Dan: they will happily convert the string "11x" to integer "11".

See more: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: But they accept arguments than that, one of them being a point to size_t that's, if not null, is set to the first unconverted character

Comment: Yes, using the second parameter of std::stoi you can detect invalid input. You still have to roll your own conversion function though...

Comment: Just like the accepted answer did, but with these standard functions that would be much cleaner, imo

Comment: Keep in mind that the second argument in these functions can be used to tell whether the entire string was converted or not. If the resulting `size_t` isn't equal to the length of the string, then it stopped early. It'll still return 11 in that case, but `pos` will be 2 instead of the string length 3. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cabe25d64d2ffa29

Answer (score 231):

### What not to do

Here is my first piece of advice: **do not use stringstream for this**. While at first it may seem simple to use, you'll find that you have to do a lot of extra work if you want robustness and good error handling.

Here is an approach that intuitively seems like it should work:

```
bool str2int (int &i, char const *s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    ss >> i;
    if (ss.fail()) {
        // not an integer
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This has a major problem: `str2int(i, "1337h4x0r")` will happily return `true` and `i` will get the value `1337`. We can work around this problem by ensuring there are no more characters in the `stringstream` after the conversion:

```
bool str2int (int &i, char const *s)
{
    char              c;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    ss >> i;
    if (ss.fail() || ss.get(c)) {
        // not an integer
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

We fixed one problem, but there are still a couple of other problems.

What if the number in the string is not base 10? We can try to accommodate other bases by setting the stream to the correct mode (e.g. `ss << std::hex`) before trying the conversion. But this means the caller must know *a priori* what base the number is -- and how can the caller possibly know that? The caller doesn't know what the number is yet. They don't even know that it *is* a number! How can they be expected to know what base it is? We could just mandate that all numbers input to our programs must be base 10 and reject hexadecimal or octal input as invalid. But that is not very flexible or robust. There is no simple solution to this problem. You can't simply try the conversion once for each base, because the decimal conversion will always succeed for octal numbers (with a leading zero) and the octal conversion may succeed for some decimal numbers. So now you have to check for a leading zero. But wait! Hexadecimal numbers can start with a leading zero too (0x...). Sigh.

Even if you succeed in dealing with the above problems, there is still another bigger problem: what if the caller needs to distinguish between bad input (e.g. "123foo") and a number that is out of the range of `int` (e.g. "4000000000" for 32-bit `int`)? With `stringstream`, there is no way to make this distinction. We only know whether the conversion succeeded or failed. If it fails, we have no way of knowing *why* it failed. As you can see, `stringstream` leaves much to be desired if you want robustness and clear error handling.

This leads me to my second piece of advice: **do no use Boost's `lexical_cast` for this**. Consider what the `lexical_cast` documentation has to say:

> Where a higher degree of control is
>   required over conversions,
>   std::stringstream and
>   std::wstringstream offer a more
>   appropriate path. Where
>   non-stream-based conversions are
>   required, lexical_cast is the wrong
>   tool for the job and is not
>   special-cased for such scenarios.

What?? We've already seen that `stringstream` has a poor level of control, and yet it says `stringstream` should be used instead of `lexical_cast` if you need "a higher level of control". Also, because `lexical_cast` is just a wrapper around `stringstream`, it suffers from the same problems that `stringstream` does: poor support for multiple number bases and poor error handling.

### The best solution

Fortunately, somebody has already solved all of the above problems. The C standard library contains `strtol` and family which have none of these problems.

```
enum STR2INT_ERROR { SUCCESS, OVERFLOW, UNDERFLOW, INCONVERTIBLE };

STR2INT_ERROR str2int (int &i, char const *s, int base = 0)
{
    char *end;
    long  l;
    errno = 0;
    l = strtol(s, &end, base);
    if ((errno == ERANGE && l == LONG_MAX) || l > INT_MAX) {
        return OVERFLOW;
    }
    if ((errno == ERANGE && l == LONG_MIN) || l < INT_MIN) {
        return UNDERFLOW;
    }
    if (*s == '\0' || *end != '\0') {
        return INCONVERTIBLE;
    }
    i = l;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Pretty simple for something that handles all the error cases and also supports any number base from 2 to 36. If `base` is zero (the default) it will try to convert from any base. Or the caller can supply the third argument and specify that the conversion should only be attempted for a particular base. It is robust and handles all errors with a minimal amount of effort.

Other reasons to prefer `strtol` (and family):

- It exhibits much better [runtime performance](http://tinodidriksen.com/2010/02/16/cpp-convert-string-to-int-speed/)
- It introduces less compile-time overhead (the others pull in nearly 20 times more SLOC from headers)
- It results in the smallest code size

There is absolutely no good reason to use any other method.

Comment: strtol is not thread-safe because of the use of global variables for error state.

Comment: @JamesDunne: POSIX requires `strtol` to be thread-safe. POSIX also requires `errno` to use thread-local storage. Even on non-POSIX systems, nearly all implementations of `errno` on multithreaded systems use thread-local storage. The latest C++ standard requires `errno` to be POSIX compliant. The latest C standard also requires `errno` to have thread-local storage. Even on Windows, which is definitely not POSIX compliant, `errno` is thread-safe and, by extension, so is `strtol`.

Comment: I can't really follow your reasoning against using boost::lexical_cast. As they say, std::stringstream does indeed offer a lot of control - you do everything from error checking to determining base youfrself. The current documentation puts it like this: "For more involved conversions, such as where precision or formatting need tighter control than is offered by the default behavior of lexical_cast, the conventional std::stringstream approach is recommended."

Comment: Note, the identifiers `OVERFLOW` and `UNDERFLOW` are used for macros by `gcc` (and therefore `g++`) for compatibility with System V. To disable extensions to the standard such as this one, pass `-ansi` to `g++` at the command-line or makefile. http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=5407 http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Comment: Follow-up: The bug report at the first link indicates that -D_ISOC99_SOURCE will disable the extension, but the second link says -ansi will disable all. I posted too soon and have not yet gotten either to work.

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 (`llvm-gcc 4.2`) and had to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to disable the extension. This is likely not necessary on other systems.

Comment: This is inappropriate C coding within C++.  The standard library contains `std::stol` for this, which will appropriately throw exceptions rather than returning constants.

Comment: @fuzzyTew I wrote this answer before `std::stol` was even added to the C++ language. That said, I don't think it's fair to say that this is "C coding within C++". It's silly to say that `std::strtol` is C coding when it is explicitly part of the C++ language. My answer applied perfectly to C++ when it was written and it still does apply even with the new `std::stol`. Calling functions that may throw exceptions isn't always the best for every programming situation.

Comment: @DanMoulding , true, I didn't realize when writing that stol was c++11 only.  However, exceptions are the standard way of handling exceptional conditions in C++.  Returning error constants is a C paradigm that is generally frowned upon and unexpected in C++, adding barriers to debugging and sharing of code, and spreading visually bloating conditional checks.  It's needed in C because C has no exceptions.  Return values do often compile to faster code, so may be the best if the code is profiled to have a bottleneck around many exceptional conditions.

Comment: Not sure how prevalent C++11 is, but as the idiomatic C++ way of parsing int, I'm going to switch my accepted answer to `std::stol`.

Comment: @fuzzyTew: Running out of disk space is an exceptional condition.  Malformatted data files which are computer produced are an exceptional condition.  But typos in user input are not exceptional.  It's good to have a parsing approach which is able to handle normal, non-exceptional parsing failures.

Comment: Your `strtol()` wrapper is very similar to BSD's [`strtonum()`](https://github.com/syuu1228/openbsd-src/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/strtonum.c).

Comment: @Grault and @DanMoulding, is there a reason not to place a qualifying 'tag' before each of the `STR2INT_ERROR` enumerators (i.e. `enum STR2INT_ERROR { S2I_SUCCESS, S2I_OVERFLOW, S2I_UNDERFLOW, S2I_INCONVERTIBLE };`? Would this not be a simpler solution to the conflict?

Comment: @rtmh Yes. If I recall my state of mind correctly, I was upset at Apple for polluting the macro space by not doing something similar in their extension. Namespacing the macros without fuss, as you suggested, would probably be most practical.

Comment: @Grault It's funny you mention apple because I ran into it with MSVS as well. Irksome indeed, haha.

Comment: Should calling code use `errno` for error discrimination, changing code to `if ((errno == ERANGE && l == LONG_MAX) || l > INT_MAX) {
        errno = ERANGE; return OVERFLOW;
    }` would be a small amount of extra code to accommodate that.

Comment: You assign 0 to errno, but I don't see any other place where it gets an assignment.

Comment: @Yankee Most C library functions return a special value, such as -1, to indicate that an error occurred. Once you know an error has occurred, all you need to do is check errno to find out what the error code is. But no C library function may set errno to 0. And there are no return values from strtol which, by themselves, indicate that strtol returned an error. So errno alone must be used to determine if an error has occurred. Since strtol cannot set errno to 0 on success, errno must be explicitly set to 0 before calling strtol, then checked to see if it is still 0 afterward, to detect errors.

Comment: It sounds like this answer is recommending the use of `strtol`. I'm just confused by the `str2int` code sample given. Is this supposed to show the implementation of strtol? If so, then why is it named `str2int`?

Comment: Careful! Missed a case. `strtol` will allow arbitrary amounts of leading whitespace, but no trailing whitespace. I think we should probably disallow leading whitespace (add `isspace(*s)` to the inconvertible case) unless we consciously see a good reason for that not being handled at a higher level, and I think *if* we allow leading whitespace we should also allow trailing whitespace (do `for(; isspace(*end); end += 1);` after the call to `strtol`) unless we see a good reason for that inconsistency.

Comment: One other thing I dislike about `strtol` is that it treats leading zero as signalling octal when base is zero. By now humanity has enough experience with it to know that zero implicitly switching interpretation from decimal to octal causes far more bad than good. Some things are naturally octal (umask for example) but notably those things you *never* want to interpret as decimal. So I'd also do `if(base == 0) for(; s[0] == '0' && s[1] != '\0’; s += 1);` before the call to `strtol`.

Comment: One other final polishing touch I would personally probably do is `int saved_errno = errno:` before calling `strtol` and `errno = saved_errno;` in the success return path. This would make the behavior more consistent with the standard library functions, which might clobber a previous `errno` but never clear it back to zero.

Comment: Anyway, this answer is extremely good and should still be the accepted answer to this day.

Comment: What this (good one) solution lacks is the ability to work with non-zero-terminated strings (such as string_view).

Answer (score 70):

This is a safer C way than atoi()

```
const char* str = "123";
int i;

if(sscanf(str, "%d", &i)  == EOF )
{
   /* error */
}
```

C++ with standard library [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream): (thanks [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c#194478) )

```
int str2int (const string &str) {
  stringstream ss(str);
  int num;
  if((ss >> num).fail())
  { 
      //ERROR 
  }
  return num;
}
```

With [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#lexical_cast) library: (thanks [jk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c#194487))

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>

try
{
    std::string str = "123";
    int number = boost::lexical_cast< int >( str );
}
catch( const boost::bad_lexical_cast & )
{
    // Error
}
```

Edit: Fixed the stringstream version so that it handles errors. (thanks to CMS's and jk's comment on original post)

Comment: please updated your stringstream version to include a check for stringstream::fail() (as requested by the questioner "Robust and clear error handling")

Comment: Your stringstream version will accept stuff like  "10haha" without complaining

Comment: change it to (!(ss >> num).fail() && (ss >> ws).eof()) from ((ss >> num).fail()) if you want the same handling like lexical_cast

Comment: The C++ with standard library stringstream method doesn't work for strings such as 
"12-SomeString" even with the .fail()  check.

Comment: C++11 includes standard fast functions for this now

Answer (score 22):

The good 'old C way still works. I recommend strtol or strtoul. Between the return status and the 'endPtr', you can give good diagnostic output. It also handles multiple bases nicely.

Comment: Oh please don't use this old C stuff when programming C++. There are better/easier/cleaner/more modern/safer ways to do this in C++!

Comment: It's funny when people are concerned about "more modern" ways to solve a problem.

Comment: @Jason, IMO stronger type safety and error handling is more modern idea compared to that of C.

Comment: I've looked at the other answers, and so far nothing is obviously better/easier/cleaner or safer.

The poster said he had a char *. That limits the amount of safety you are going to get :)

Comment: @JMiller In fairness, in the case of C and C++ that's because the old fashioned ways usually have distinct flaws, ranging from the awkward, to the inefficient, to the downright unsafe. In `std::strtol`'s case, you have no way of knowing if you've successfully parsed a `0` or if the function failed unless you manually check if the string resolves to `0`, and by the time you've done that you're unnecessarily repeating work. The more modern approach (`std::from_chars`) not only tells you when the function fails, but _why_ it failed as well, which helps provide feedback to the end user.

Comment: 13 years later I am looking up this question, just to find my own answer. And I'll agree with @Pharap, std::from_chars, which didn't exist in 2008, is probably the better answer in C++ now.

Comment: @Pharap: I don't know what you mean by "string resolves to" but I think you've confused checking for a NUL `(char)0` with checking for a string that is `"0"`.

Comment: @BenVoigt No, I wasn't confusing `'\0'` with `'0'`. Saying "resolves to" was just the most succinct thing I could think to say at the time without going over the character limit. What I meant is that it's impossible to know if a `0` returned by `std::strtol` is indicating an invalid parse or a valid parse with a value of `0`, and that to be certain you'd have to do extra work, some of which would repeat work already performed by `std::strtol`. By "resolves to `0`" I mean "validly parses as `0`" as opposed to "does not parse".

Comment: @Pharap: But you don't have to repeat any of the parsing work.  You check the pointer stored to `endp`.  If it is equal to the pointer passed in, you got zero because parsing failed.  Otherwise the zero was a successful parsing result.  If you want to distinguish parsing the entire string from parsing a prefix (`"0zork"`) then check whether `*endp` is a NUL character.  At no point do you have to look at any of the digits inside the input string.

Comment: @BenVoigt Fair point, I had overlooked the fact that `str_end` was a pointer to a pointer and thus designed to be an 'out' parameter, I thought `str` and `str_end` were intended to act more like the `begin` and `end` iterators commonly used in `<algorithm>` functions. (Incidentally I find it strange that it's a `char * *` instead of a `const char * *` considering `str` is a `const char *`. That suggests the function may internally be casting away the `const`.) At any rate, `std::from_chars` is still more useful because its error reporting approach is more sane.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [Boost's `lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#lexical_cast), which [wraps this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c#194518) in a more generic interface.
`lexical_cast<Target>(Source)` throws `bad_lexical_cast` on failure.

Comment: Boost lexical_cast is extremely slow and painfully inefficient.

Comment: @Matthieu Updates to Boost have made improved performance quite a bit: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html  (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250795/very-poor-boostlexical-cast-performance )

Answer (score 16):

You can use the a stringstream from the C++ standard libraray:

```
stringstream ss(str);
int x;
ss >> x;

if(ss) { // <-- error handling
  // use x
} else {
  // not a number
}
```

> The stream state will be set to fail
>   if a non-digit is encountered when
>   trying to read an integer.

See [Stream pitfalls](http://www.horstmann.com/cpp/pitfalls.html) for pitfalls of errorhandling and streams in C++.

Comment: The C++ stringstream method doesn't work for strings such as "12-SomeString" even with the 'stream state' check.

Answer (score 16):

From C++17 onwards you can use `std::from_chars` from the `<charconv>` header as documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars).

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <charconv>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    char const * str = "42";
    int value = 0;

    std::from_chars_result result = std::from_chars(std::begin(str), std::end(str), value);

    if(result.error == std::errc::invalid_argument)
    {
      std::cout << "Error, invalid format";
    }
    else if(result.error == std::errc::result_out_of_range)
    {
      std::cout << "Error, value too big for int range";
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Success: " << result;
    }
}
```

As a bonus, it can also handle other bases, like hexadecimal.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [stringstream's](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)

```
int str2int (const string &str) {
  stringstream ss(str);
  int num;
  ss >> num;
  return num;
}
```

Comment: But this does not handle any errors. You have to check the stream for failures.

Comment: Right you have to check the stream 
if((ss >> num).fail()){
 //ERROR
}

Comment: The C++ stringstream method doesn't work for strings such as "12-SomeString" even with the 'stream state' check

Answer (score 8):

I think these three links sum it up:

- http://tinodidriksen.com/2010/02/07/cpp-convert-int-to-string-speed/
- ***http://tinodidriksen.com/2010/02/16/cpp-convert-string-to-int-speed/***
- ***http://www.fastformat.org/performance.html***

stringstream and lexical_cast solutions are about the same as lexical cast is using stringstream.

Some specializations of lexical cast use different approach see **http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/lexical_cast.hpp** for details.  Integers and floats are now specialized for integer to string conversion.

One can specialize lexical_cast for his/her own needs and make it fast. This would be the ultimate solution satisfying all parties, clean and simple.

Articles already mentioned show comparison between different methods of converting  integers <-> strings. Following approaches make sense:  old c-way, spirit.karma, fastformat, simple naive loop.

Lexical_cast is ok in some cases e.g. for int to string conversion.

Converting string to int using lexical cast is not a good idea as it is 10-40 times slower than atoi depending on the platform/compiler used.

Boost.Spirit.Karma seems to be the fastest library for converting integer to string.

```
ex.: generate(ptr_char, int_, integer_number);
```

and basic simple loop from the article mentioned above is a fastest way to convert string to int, obviously not the safest one, strtol() seems like a safer solution

```
int naive_char_2_int(const char *p) {
    int x = 0;
    bool neg = false;
    if (*p == '-') {
        neg = true;
        ++p;
    }
    while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
        x = (x*10) + (*p - '0');
        ++p;
    }
    if (neg) {
        x = -x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [C++ String Toolkit Library (StrTk)](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html) has the following solution:

```
static const std::size_t digit_table_symbol_count = 256;
static const unsigned char digit_table[digit_table_symbol_count] = {
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xFF - 0x07
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x08 - 0x0F
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x10 - 0x17
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x18 - 0x1F
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x20 - 0x27
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x28 - 0x2F
   0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, // 0x30 - 0x37
   0x08, 0x09, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x38 - 0x3F
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x40 - 0x47
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x48 - 0x4F
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x50 - 0x57
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x58 - 0x5F
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x60 - 0x67
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x68 - 0x6F
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x70 - 0x77
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x78 - 0x7F
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x80 - 0x87
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x88 - 0x8F
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x90 - 0x97
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0x98 - 0x9F
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xA0 - 0xA7
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xA8 - 0xAF
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xB0 - 0xB7
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xB8 - 0xBF
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xC0 - 0xC7
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xC8 - 0xCF
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xD0 - 0xD7
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xD8 - 0xDF
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xE0 - 0xE7
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xE8 - 0xEF
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, // 0xF0 - 0xF7
   0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF  // 0xF8 - 0xFF
 };

template<typename InputIterator, typename T>
inline bool string_to_signed_type_converter_impl_itr(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, T& v)
{
   if (0 == std::distance(begin,end))
      return false;
   v = 0;
   InputIterator it = begin;
   bool negative = false;
   if ('+' == *it)
      ++it;
   else if ('-' == *it)
   {
      ++it;
      negative = true;
   }
   if (end == it)
      return false;
   while(end != it)
   {
      const T digit = static_cast<T>(digit_table[static_cast<unsigned int>(*it++)]);
      if (0xFF == digit)
         return false;
      v = (10 * v) + digit;
   }
   if (negative)
      v *= -1;
   return true;
}
```

The InputIterator can be of either unsigned char*, char* or std::string iterators, and T is expected to be a signed int, such as signed int, int, or long

Comment: WARNING This implementation looks nice, but doesn't handle overflows as far as I can tell.

Comment: Code does not handle overflow.  `v = (10 * v) + digit;` overflows needlessly with string input with the text value of `INT_MIN`.  Table is of questionable value vs simply `digit >= '0' && digit <= '9'`

Answer (score 6):

If you have C++11, the appropriate solutions nowadays are the C++ integer conversion functions in `<string>`: `stoi`, `stol`, `stoul`, `stoll`, `stoull`.  They throw appropriate exceptions when given incorrect input and use the fast and small `strto*` functions under the hood.

If you are stuck with an earlier revision of C++, it would be forward-portable of you to mimic these functions in your implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I like [Dan Moulding's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154614), I'll just add a bit of C++ style to it:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>
#include <climits>
#include <stdexcept>

int to_int(const std::string &s, int base = 0)
{
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    long result = std::strtol(s.c_str(), &end, base);
    if (errno == ERANGE || result > INT_MAX || result < INT_MIN)
        throw std::out_of_range("toint: string is out of range");
    if (s.length() == 0 || *end != '\0')
        throw std::invalid_argument("toint: invalid string");
    return result;
}
```

It works for both std::string and const char* through the implicit conversion. It's also useful for base conversion, e.g. all `to_int("0x7b")` and `to_int("0173")` and `to_int("01111011", 2)` and `to_int("0000007B", 16)` and `to_int("11120", 3)` and `to_int("3L", 34);` would return 123.

Unlike `std::stoi` it works in pre-C++11. Also unlike `std::stoi`, `boost::lexical_cast` and `stringstream` it throws exceptions for weird strings like "123hohoho".

NB: This function tolerates leading spaces but not trailing spaces, i.e. `to_int("  123")` returns 123 while `to_int("123   ")` throws exception. Make sure this is acceptable for your use case or adjust the code.

Such function could be part of STL...

Answer (score 2):

I know three ways of converting String into int:

Either use stoi(String to int) function or just go with Stringstream, the third way to go individual conversion, Code is below:

**1st Method**

```
std::string s1 = "4533";
std::string s2 = "3.010101";
std::string s3 = "31337 with some string";

int myint1 = std::stoi(s1);
int myint2 = std::stoi(s2);
int myint3 = std::stoi(s3);

std::cout <<  s1 <<"=" << myint1 << '\n';
std::cout <<  s2 <<"=" << myint2 << '\n';
std::cout <<  s3 <<"=" << myint3 << '\n';
```

**2nd Method**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int StringToInteger(string NumberAsString)
{
    int NumberAsInteger;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << NumberAsString;
    ss >> NumberAsInteger;
    return NumberAsInteger;
}
int main()
{
    string NumberAsString;
    cin >> NumberAsString;
    cout << StringToInteger(NumberAsString) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**3rd Method - but not for an individual conversion**

```
std::string str4 = "453";
int i = 0, in=0; // 453 as on
for ( i = 0; i < str4.length(); i++)
{

    in = str4[i];
    cout <<in-48 ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154614/892771), esp because of the avoidance of exceptions. For embedded systems development and other low level system development, there may not be a proper Exception framework available.

Added a check for white-space after a valid string...these three lines

```
    while (isspace(*end)) {
        end++;
    }
```

Added a check for parsing errors too.

```
    if ((errno != 0) || (s == end)) {
        return INCONVERTIBLE;
    }
```

Here is the complete function..

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>
#include <climits>
#include <stdexcept>

enum STR2INT_ERROR { SUCCESS, OVERFLOW, UNDERFLOW, INCONVERTIBLE };

STR2INT_ERROR str2long (long &l, char const *s, int base = 0)
{
    char *end = (char *)s;
    errno = 0;

    l = strtol(s, &end, base);

    if ((errno == ERANGE) && (l == LONG_MAX)) {
        return OVERFLOW;
    }
    if ((errno == ERANGE) && (l == LONG_MIN)) {
        return UNDERFLOW;
    }
    if ((errno != 0) || (s == end)) {
        return INCONVERTIBLE;
    }    
    while (isspace((unsigned char)*end)) {
        end++;
    }

    if (*s == '\0' || *end != '\0') {
        return INCONVERTIBLE;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @chux  added code to take care of the concerns you mentioned.

Comment: 1) Still fails to detect error with input like `"  "`.  `strtol()` is not specified to set `errno` when no conversion occurs.  Better to use `if (s == end) return INCONVERTIBLE;`   to detect no conversion. And then  `if (*s == '\0' || *end != '\0')` can simplify to `if (*end)` 2) `|| l > LONG_MAX` and `|| l < LONG_MIN` serve no purpose - they are never true.

Comment: @chux On a mac, the errno is set for parsing errors, but on linux the errno is not set. Changed code to depend on the "end" pointer to detect that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this defined method.

```
#define toInt(x) {atoi(x.c_str())};
```

And if you were to convert from String to an Integer, you would just do the following.

```
int main()
{
string test = "46", test2 = "56";
int a = toInt(test);
int b = toInt(test2);
cout<<a+b<<endl;
}
```

The output would be 102.

Comment: idk. Writing a define macro around `atoi` doesn't seem like "the C++ way," in light of other answers like the accepted `std::stoi()`.

Comment: I find it more fun using pre-defined methods :P

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I've come across it so many times and, to date, have still not found a nicely templated solution having the following characteristics:

- Can convert any base (and detect base type)
- Will detect erroneous data (i.e. ensure the entire string, less leading/trailing whitespace, is consumed by the conversion)
- Will ensure that, regardless of the type converted to, the range of the string's value is acceptable.

So, here is mine, with a test strap.  Because it uses the C functions strtoull/strtoll under the hood, it always converts first to the largest type available.  Then, if you are not using the largest type, it will perform additional range checks to verify your type was not over(under)flowed. For this, it is a little less performant than if one properly chose strtol/strtoul.  However, it also works for shorts/chars and, to the best of my knowledge, there exists no standard library function that does that, too.

Enjoy; hopefully someone finds it useful.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>

static const int DefaultBase = 10;

template<typename T>
static inline T CstrtoxllWrapper(const char *str, int base = DefaultBase)
{
    while (isspace(*str)) str++; // remove leading spaces; verify there's data
    if (*str == '\0') { throw std::invalid_argument("str; no data"); } // nothing to convert

    // NOTE:  for some reason strtoull allows a negative sign, we don't; if
    //          converting to an unsigned then it must always be positive!
    if (!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed && *str == '-')
    { throw std::invalid_argument("str; negative"); }

    // reset errno and call fn (either strtoll or strtoull)
    errno = 0;
    char *ePtr;
    T tmp = std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed ? strtoll(str, &ePtr, base)
                                              : strtoull(str, &ePtr, base);

    // check for any C errors -- note these are range errors on T, which may
    //   still be out of the range of the actual type we're using; the caller
    //   may need to perform additional range checks.
    if (errno != 0) 
    {
            if (errno == ERANGE) { throw std::range_error("str; out of range"); }
            else if (errno == EINVAL) { throw std::invalid_argument("str; EINVAL"); }
            else { throw std::invalid_argument("str; unknown errno"); }
    }

    // verify everything converted -- extraneous spaces are allowed
    if (ePtr != NULL)
    {
            while (isspace(*ePtr)) ePtr++;
            if (*ePtr != '\0') { throw std::invalid_argument("str; bad data"); }
    }

    return tmp;
}

template<typename T>
T StringToSigned(const char *str, int base = DefaultBase)
{
    static const long long max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    static const long long min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();

    long long tmp = CstrtoxllWrapper<typeof(tmp)>(str, base); // use largest type

    // final range check -- only needed if not long long type; a smart compiler
    //   should optimize this whole thing out
    if (sizeof(T) == sizeof(tmp)) { return tmp; }

    if (tmp < min || tmp > max)
    {
            std::ostringstream err;
            err << "str; value " << tmp << " out of " << sizeof(T) * 8
                << "-bit signed range (";
            if (sizeof(T) != 1) err << min << ".." << max;
            else err << (int) min << ".." << (int) max;  // don't print garbage chars
            err << ")";
            throw std::range_error(err.str());
    }

    return tmp;
}

template<typename T>
T StringToUnsigned(const char *str, int base = DefaultBase)
{
    static const unsigned long long max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

    unsigned long long tmp = CstrtoxllWrapper<typeof(tmp)>(str, base); // use largest type

    // final range check -- only needed if not long long type; a smart compiler
    //   should optimize this whole thing out
    if (sizeof(T) == sizeof(tmp)) { return tmp; }

    if (tmp > max)
    {
            std::ostringstream err;
            err << "str; value " << tmp << " out of " << sizeof(T) * 8
                << "-bit unsigned range (0..";
            if (sizeof(T) != 1) err << max;
            else err << (int) max;  // don't print garbage chars
            err << ")";
            throw std::range_error(err.str());
    }

    return tmp;
}

template<typename T>
inline T
StringToDecimal(const char *str, int base = DefaultBase)
{
    return std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed ? StringToSigned<T>(str, base)
                                             : StringToUnsigned<T>(str, base);
}

template<typename T>
inline T
StringToDecimal(T &out_convertedVal, const char *str, int base = DefaultBase)
{
    return out_convertedVal = StringToDecimal<T>(str, base);
}

/*============================== [ Test Strap ] ==============================*/ 

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <iostream>

static bool _g_anyFailed = false;

template<typename T>
void TestIt(const char *tName,
            const char *s, int base,
            bool successExpected = false, T expectedValue = 0)
{
    #define FAIL(s) { _g_anyFailed = true; std::cout << s; }

    T x;
    std::cout << "converting<" << tName << ">b:" << base << " [" << s << "]";
    try
    {
            StringToDecimal<T>(x, s, base);
            // get here on success only
            if (!successExpected)
            {
                    FAIL(" -- TEST FAILED; SUCCESS NOT EXPECTED!" << std::endl);
            }
            else
            {
                    std::cout << " -> ";
                    if (sizeof(T) != 1) std::cout << x;
                    else std::cout << (int) x;  // don't print garbage chars
                    if (x != expectedValue)
                    {
                            FAIL("; FAILED (expected value:" << expectedValue << ")!");
                    }
                    std::cout << std::endl;
            }
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
            if (successExpected)
            {
                    FAIL(   " -- TEST FAILED; EXPECTED SUCCESS!"
                         << " (got:" << e.what() << ")" << std::endl);
            }
            else
            {
                    std::cout << "; expected exception encounterd: [" << e.what() << "]" << std::endl;
            }
    }
}

#define TEST(t, s, ...) \
    TestIt<t>(#t, s, __VA_ARGS__);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "============ variable base tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int, "-0xF", 0, true, -0xF);
    TEST(int, "+0xF", 0, true, 0xF);
    TEST(int, "0xF", 0, true, 0xF);
    TEST(int, "-010", 0, true, -010);
    TEST(int, "+010", 0, true, 010);
    TEST(int, "010", 0, true, 010);
    TEST(int, "-10", 0, true, -10);
    TEST(int, "+10", 0, true, 10);
    TEST(int, "10", 0, true, 10);

    std::cout << "============ base-10 tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int, "-010", 10, true, -10);
    TEST(int, "+010", 10, true, 10);
    TEST(int, "010", 10, true, 10);
    TEST(int, "-10", 10, true, -10);
    TEST(int, "+10", 10, true, 10);
    TEST(int, "10", 10, true, 10);
    TEST(int, "00010", 10, true, 10);

    std::cout << "============ base-8 tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int, "777", 8, true, 0777);
    TEST(int, "-0111 ", 8, true, -0111);
    TEST(int, "+0010 ", 8, true, 010);

    std::cout << "============ base-16 tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int, "DEAD", 16, true, 0xDEAD);
    TEST(int, "-BEEF", 16, true, -0xBEEF);
    TEST(int, "+C30", 16, true, 0xC30);

    std::cout << "============ base-2 tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int, "-10011001", 2, true, -153);
    TEST(int, "10011001", 2, true, 153);

    std::cout << "============ irregular base tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int, "Z", 36, true, 35);
    TEST(int, "ZZTOP", 36, true, 60457993);
    TEST(int, "G", 17, true, 16);
    TEST(int, "H", 17);

    std::cout << "============ space deliminated tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int, "1337    ", 10, true, 1337);
    TEST(int, "   FEAD", 16, true, 0xFEAD);
    TEST(int, "   0711   ", 0, true, 0711);

    std::cout << "============ bad data tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int, "FEAD", 10);
    TEST(int, "1234 asdfklj", 10);
    TEST(int, "-0xF", 10);
    TEST(int, "+0xF", 10);
    TEST(int, "0xF", 10);
    TEST(int, "-F", 10);
    TEST(int, "+F", 10);
    TEST(int, "12.4", 10);
    TEST(int, "ABG", 16);
    TEST(int, "10011002", 2);

    std::cout << "============ int8_t range tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int8_t, "7F", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max());
    TEST(int8_t, "80", 16);
    TEST(int8_t, "-80", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::min());
    TEST(int8_t, "-81", 16);
    TEST(int8_t, "FF", 16);
    TEST(int8_t, "100", 16);

    std::cout << "============ uint8_t range tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(uint8_t, "7F", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max());
    TEST(uint8_t, "80", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max()+1);
    TEST(uint8_t, "-80", 16);
    TEST(uint8_t, "-81", 16);
    TEST(uint8_t, "FF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max());
    TEST(uint8_t, "100", 16);

    std::cout << "============ int16_t range tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int16_t, "7FFF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max());
    TEST(int16_t, "8000", 16);
    TEST(int16_t, "-8000", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::min());
    TEST(int16_t, "-8001", 16);
    TEST(int16_t, "FFFF", 16);
    TEST(int16_t, "10000", 16);

    std::cout << "============ uint16_t range tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(uint16_t, "7FFF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max());
    TEST(uint16_t, "8000", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max()+1);
    TEST(uint16_t, "-8000", 16);
    TEST(uint16_t, "-8001", 16);
    TEST(uint16_t, "FFFF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max());
    TEST(uint16_t, "10000", 16);

    std::cout << "============ int32_t range tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int32_t, "7FFFFFFF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max());
    TEST(int32_t, "80000000", 16);
    TEST(int32_t, "-80000000", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min());
    TEST(int32_t, "-80000001", 16);
    TEST(int32_t, "FFFFFFFF", 16);
    TEST(int32_t, "100000000", 16);

    std::cout << "============ uint32_t range tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(uint32_t, "7FFFFFFF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max());
    TEST(uint32_t, "80000000", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max()+1);
    TEST(uint32_t, "-80000000", 16);
    TEST(uint32_t, "-80000001", 16);
    TEST(uint32_t, "FFFFFFFF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max());
    TEST(uint32_t, "100000000", 16);

    std::cout << "============ int64_t range tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(int64_t, "7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max());
    TEST(int64_t, "8000000000000000", 16);
    TEST(int64_t, "-8000000000000000", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min());
    TEST(int64_t, "-8000000000000001", 16);
    TEST(int64_t, "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16);
    TEST(int64_t, "10000000000000000", 16);

    std::cout << "============ uint64_t range tests ============" << std::endl;
    TEST(uint64_t, "7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max());
    TEST(uint64_t, "8000000000000000", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()+1);
    TEST(uint64_t, "-8000000000000000", 16);
    TEST(uint64_t, "-8000000000000001", 16);
    TEST(uint64_t, "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16, true, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());
    TEST(uint64_t, "10000000000000000", 16);

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl
              << (_g_anyFailed ? "!! SOME TESTS FAILED !!" : "ALL TESTS PASSED")
              << std::endl;

    return _g_anyFailed;
}
```

`StringToDecimal` is the user-land method; it is overloaded so it can be called either like this:

```
int a; a = StringToDecimal<int>("100");
```

or this:

```
int a; StringToDecimal(a, "100");
```

I hate repeating the int type, so prefer the latter. This ensures that if the type of 'a' changes one does not get bad results. I wish the compiler could figure it out like:

```
int a; a = StringToDecimal("100");
```

...but, C++ does not deduce template return types, so that's the best I can get.

The implementation is pretty simple:

`CstrtoxllWrapper` wraps both `strtoull` and `strtoll`, calling whichever is necessary based on the template type's signed-ness and providing some additional guarantees (e.g. negative input is disallowed if unsigned and it ensures the entire string was converted).

`CstrtoxllWrapper` is used by `StringToSigned` and `StringToUnsigned` with the largest type (long long/unsigned long long) available to the compiler; this allows the maximal conversion to be performed.  Then, if it is necessary, `StringToSigned`/`StringToUnsigned` performs the final range checks on the underlying type. Finally, the end-point method, `StringToDecimal`, decides which of the StringTo* template methods to call based on the underlying type's signed-ness.

I think most of the junk can be optimized out by the compiler; just about everything should be compile-time deterministic. Any commentary on this aspect would be interesting to me!

Comment: "use largest type"-->  why `long long` instead of `intmax_t`?

Comment: Confident you want `if (ePtr != str)`.  Further, use `isspace((unsigned char) *ePtr)` to properly handle negative values of `*ePtr`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a parsing function that parses a complex number from a string which can be in a form 3+i4. Since I didn't find any best solution that handles all the combinations, I decided to write a parser of my own using overloaded >> operator on std::string.

```
struct complex
{
   int a = 0, b = 0;

   complex& operator+=(const complex& other)
   {
      a += other.a;
      b += other.b;

      return *this;
   }

   complex operator+(const complex& other)
   {
      complex cmp(other);
      cmp += *this;

      return cmp;
   }

  complex operator+(const complex& other) const
  {
      complex cmp(other);
      cmp += *this;

      return cmp;
  }

  friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const complex& cmp);
  friend inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, complex& cmp);
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const complex& cmp)
{
   os << cmp.a << "+i" << cmp.b;
   return os;
}

inline std::string operator>>(const std::string& stream, int& value)
{
  int temp = 0;
  bool b = false;
  std::string::const_iterator it = stream.cbegin();

  for (; it != stream.cend(); ++it)
  {
    if (std::isdigit(*it))
    {
        temp *= 10;
        temp += static_cast<int>(*it - '0');
        b = true;
    }
    else if (b)
    {
        ++it;
        break;
    }
    else 
    {
        continue;
    }       
  }

  value = temp;
  return stream.substr(it - stream.cbegin(), stream.cend() - it);
 }

inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, complex& cmp)
{
  std::string s;
  std::getline(is >> std::ws, s);

  s >> cmp.a >> cmp.b;

  return is;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::cout << static_cast<int>('0') << std::endl;

  complex x, y;
  std::cin >> x;
  std::cin >> y;

  complex z = x + y;
  std::cout << z << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

In C, you can use `int atoi (const char * str)`,

Parses the C-string str interpreting its content as an integral number, which is returned as a value of type int.

Comment: As I linked to `atoi` in the question, I'm aware of it. The question is clearly not about C, but about C++. -1