# C++ IsFloat function

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

Does anybody know of a convenient means of determining if a string value "qualifies" as a floating-point number?

```
bool IsFloat( string MyString )
{
   ... etc ...

   return ... // true if float; false otherwise
}
```

Comment: If that's supposed to be C++ you mean "bool", "true" and "false" and not "BOOL" etc.

Comment: He's probably using Windows APIs, ...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you can't use a Boost library function, you can write your own isFloat function like this.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

bool isFloat( string myString ) {
    std::istringstream iss(myString);
    float f;
    iss >> noskipws >> f; // noskipws considers leading whitespace invalid
    // Check the entire string was consumed and if either failbit or badbit is set
    return iss.eof() && !iss.fail(); 
}
```

Comment: This (and all the duplicate solutions) will not work on "3.14 hello". You have draing the stream to make sure the number is not followed by any non-whitespace.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that and one other bug I found.

Comment: Don't forget to forbid initial whitespace with noskipws.

Comment: Awesome, we're designing isFloat by committee.  :)

Comment: Fair enough...  In that case I think it needs some sort of "hump" for food and water storage over long periods, in case of drought...  :)

Comment: Nice.  "A camel is a horse designed by a committee," for anyone who doesn't get the reference.  I just happened to have http://blogs.msdn.com/mikechampion/archive/2006/12/21/the-json-vs-xml-debate-begins-in-earnest.aspx open in another tab. :)

Comment: @macrocosme As it should.

Comment: Why should an int be considered a float exactly?

Comment: @macrocosme Why shouldn't it be? `float f = 256;` compiles, doesn't it?

Comment: I get the point. Your solution is valid for the question, which was general enough. I was just mentioning that in case one wants to differentiate between floats and ints, we need something slightly different. e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/14117/

Comment: This does not work for a string that is `nan`, which is a legal representation of a float.

Answer (score 12):

You may like Boost's lexical_cast (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

```
bool isFloat(const std::string &someString)
{
  using boost::lexical_cast;
  using boost::bad_lexical_cast; 

  try
  {
    boost::lexical_cast<float>(someString);
  }
  catch (bad_lexical_cast &)
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

You can use istream to avoid needing Boost, but frankly, Boost is just too good to leave out.

Comment: please don't use exceptions as a flow-of-control mechanism

Comment: He's not using exceptions for flow-of-control.  He's catching a vexing exception ( http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx ).

Comment: It's not a "vexing" but a "boneheaded" exception. Checking !iss.fail is correct, see Bill the Lizard above.

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4654718/531840) I modified the function to check if a string is a floating point number. It won't require boost & doesn't relies on stringstreams failbit - it's just plain parsing.

```
static bool isFloatNumber(const std::string& string){
    std::string::const_iterator it = string.begin();
    bool decimalPoint = false;
    int minSize = 0;
    if(string.size()>0 && (string[0] == '-' || string[0] == '+')){
      it++;
      minSize++;
    }
    while(it != string.end()){
      if(*it == '.'){
        if(!decimalPoint) decimalPoint = true;
        else break;
      }else if(!std::isdigit(*it) && ((*it!='f') || it+1 != string.end() || !decimalPoint)){
        break;
      }
      ++it;
    }
    return string.size()>minSize && it == string.end();
  }
```

I.e.

```
1
2.
3.10000
4.2f
-5.3f
+6.2f
```

is recognized by this function correctly as float.

```
1.0.0
2f
2.0f1
```

Are examples for not-valid floats. If you don't want to recognize floating point numbers in the format X.XXf, just remove the condition:

```
&& ((*it!='f') || it+1 != string.end() || !decimalPoint)
```

from line 9.
And if you don't want to recognize numbers without '.' as float (i.e. not '1', only '1.', '1.0', '1.0f'...) then you can change the last line to:

```
return string.size()>minSize && it == string.end() && decimalPoint;
```

However: There are plenty good reasons to use either boost's lexical_cast or the solution using stringstreams rather than this 'ugly function'. But It gives me more control over what kind of formats exactly I want to recognize as floating point numbers (i.e. maximum digits after decimal point...).

Comment: However this is still not correct - both nan and +inf, inf, -inf should be specifiable too as they are valid floating point numbers as per IEEE standard.

Answer (score 5):

I recently wrote a function to check whether a string is a number or not. This number can be an Integer or Float.

You can twist my code and add some unit tests.

```
bool isNumber(string s)
{
    std::size_t char_pos(0);

    // skip the whilespaces
    char_pos = s.find_first_not_of(' ');
    if (char_pos == s.size()) return false;


    // check the significand
    if (s[char_pos] == '+' || s[char_pos] == '-') ++char_pos; // skip the sign if exist

    int n_nm, n_pt;
    for (n_nm = 0, n_pt = 0; std::isdigit(s[char_pos]) || s[char_pos] == '.'; ++char_pos) {
        s[char_pos] == '.' ? ++n_pt : ++n_nm;
    }
    if (n_pt>1 || n_nm<1) // no more than one point, at least one digit
        return false;

    // skip the trailing whitespaces
    while (s[char_pos] == ' ') {
        ++ char_pos;
    }

    return char_pos == s.size();  // must reach the ending 0 of the string
}


void UnitTest() {
    double num = std::stod("825FB7FC8CAF4342");
    string num_str = std::to_string(num);

    // Not number
    assert(!isNumber("1a23"));
    assert(!isNumber("3.7.1"));
    assert(!isNumber("825FB7FC8CAF4342"));
    assert(!isNumber(" + 23.24"));
    assert(!isNumber(" - 23.24"));

    // Is number
    assert(isNumber("123"));
    assert(isNumber("3.7"));
    assert(isNumber("+23.7"));
    assert(isNumber("  -423.789"));
    assert(isNumber("  -423.789    "));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I always liked `strtof` since it lets you specify an end pointer.

```
bool isFloat(const std::string& str)
{
    char* ptr;
    strtof(str.c_str(), &ptr);
    return (*ptr) == '\0';
}
```

This works because the end pointer points to the character where the parse started to fail, therefore if it points to a nul-terminator, then the whole string was parsed as a float.

I'm surprised no one mentioned this method in the 10 years this question has been around, I suppose because it is more of a *C-Style* way of doing it. However, it is still perfectly valid in C++, and more elegant than any stream solutions. Also, it works with "+inf" "-inf" and so on, and ignores leading whitespace.

EDIT

Don't be caught out by empty strings, otherwise the end pointer will be on the nul-termination (and therefore return true). The above code should be:

```
bool isFloat(const std::string& str)
{
    if (str.empty())
        return false;

    char* ptr;
    strtof(str.c_str(), &ptr);
    return (*ptr) == '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**[EDIT: Fixed to forbid initial whitespace and trailing nonsense.]**

```
#include <sstream>

bool isFloat(string s) {
    istringstream iss(s);
    float dummy;
    iss >> noskipws >> dummy;
    return iss && iss.eof();     // Result converted to bool
}
```

You could easily turn this into a function templated on a type `T` instead of `float`.  This is essentially what Boost's [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) does.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty solution using [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof):

```
bool isFloat(const std::string& s) {
    try {
        std::stof(s);
        return true;
    } catch(...) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1233.33.33 is not a float number.  It is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine you'd want to run a regex match on the input string. I'd think it may be fairly complicated to test all the edge cases.

[This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) has some good info on it. If you just want to skip to the end it says: 
`^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$`

Which basically makes sense if you understand regex syntax.

Answer (score 2):

With C++17:

```
bool isNumeric(std::string_view s)
{
    double val;
    auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(s.data(), s.data() + s.size(), val);
    return ec == std::errc() && p == s.data() + s.size();
}
```

Both checks on return are necessary. The first checks that there are no overflow or other errors. The second checks that the entire string was read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods described in [How can I convert string to double in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392981/how-can-i-convert-string-to-double-in-c), and instead of throwing a `conversion_error`, return `false` (indicating the string does not represent a `float`), and `true` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
int isFloat(char *s){
  if(*s == '-' || *s == '+'){
    if(!isdigit(*++s)) return 0;
  }
  if(!isdigit(*s)){return 0;}
  while(isdigit(*s)) s++;
  if(*s == '.'){
    if(!isdigit(*++s)) return 0;
  }
  while(isdigit(*s)) s++;
  if(*s == 'e' || *s == 'E'){
    s++;
    if(*s == '+' || *s == '-'){
        s++;
        if(!isdigit(*s)) return 0;
    }else if(!isdigit(*s)){
        return 0;
    }
  }
  while(isdigit(*s)) s++;
  if(*s == '\0') return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with other responses is **performance**

Often you don't need every corner case, for example maybe nan and -/+ inf, are not as important to cover as having speed. Maybe you don't need to handle 1.0E+03 notation. You just want a **fast** way to parse strings to numbers.

Here is a simple, pure std::string way, that's not very fast:

```
size_t npos = word.find_first_not_of ( ".+-0123456789" );
if ( npos == std::string::npos ) {
   val = atof ( word.c_str() );
}
```

This is slow because it is O(k*13), checking each char against 0 thur 9

Here is a faster way:

```
bool isNum = true;
int st = 0;
while (word.at(st)==32) st++;    // leading spaces
ch = word.at(st);
if (ch == 43 || ch==45 ) st++;   // check +, -

for (int n = st; n < word.length(); n++) {
  char ch = word.at(n);
  if ( ch < 48 || ch > 57 || ch != 46 ) {
     isNum = false;
     break;   // not a num, early terminate
  } 
}
```

This has the benefit of terminating early if *any* non-numerical character is found, and it checks by range rather than every number digit (0-9). So the average compares is 3x per char, O(k*3), with early termination.

Notice this technique is very similar to the actual one used in the stdlib 'atof' function: 
http://www.beedub.com/Sprite093/src/lib/c/stdlib/atof.c

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick function which supports scientific notation. It's not the prettiest, but it works.

```c
bool IsFloat(const char* str, unsigned int maxLen = -1)
{
    bool sawD = false;  //decimal
    bool sawE = false;  //exponent
    bool sawES = false; //exponent sign
    int i = 0;

    while (i < maxLen)
    {
        char c = str[i];
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
        {
            if (!sawD && !sawES && !sawE && c == '.') {
                sawD = true;
            }
            else if (!sawES && !sawE && c == 'e' || c == 'E') {
                sawE = true;
            }
            else if ((i == 0 || !sawES) && c == '+' || c == '-') {
                if (i != 0)
                    sawES = true;
            }
            else if (c == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I raced (almost) every function on the page.
Each function was ran through a loop 1 million times, comparing 21 different strings each loop. String list is below.
I also included a truth table to show what each function resulted with. Blank is true, x is false.

I found it pretty interesting how each function performed so differently.
Really goes to show how using the std::string functions can really slow your code down. And also how brutally slow try catch is, Emil's function took a whopping 17.7 minutes to complete!

| User | Time(ms) | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Me | 427 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| Hayashi | 3062 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| ramakarl | 24003 | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| j_random | 108702 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| nedb | 7313 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| yang | 31649 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| constantin | 52918 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| bill the liz | 108558 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| Robben | 112998 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| Emil | 17.7 min |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x |  |  |  |  |  |

**String List**

1. 10.1
2. -10.1
3. 0.11
4. -0.11
5. 0.0
6. -0.0
7. 0
8. -0
9. 10
10. -10
11. 10.11e-10
12. -10.11e-10
13. 10.11e+10
14. Hello Float
15. Hello1234
16. Hello10.11
17. 1234Hello
18. 1234 Hello
19. 10.11Hello
20. 10.11 Hello
21. 10.1.0

Answer (score 1):

```
bool IsFloat (std::string& str)
{
    // erase trailing spaces
    const std::string white_space = " \r\n\t\v\f";
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(white_space) + 1);

    bool result = false;

    try 
    {
        size_t pos;
        const float num = std::stof(str, &pos);
        if (pos == str.size())
        {
            result = true;
        }
            
    }
    catch (...) 
    {}

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof.html) and then have special handling for `0.0`, but I don't think that counts as a particularly good solution.

Comment: No, it doesn't, since it fails for something like "0.0".  Look up strtod(), which can be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question on SO.  Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200090/how-do-you-convert-a-c-string-to-an-int) for suggestions (that question discusses string->int, but the approaches are the same).

Note: to know if the string can be converted, you basically have to do the conversion to check for things like over/underflow.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use an istringstream and return true/false based on the result of the stream operation. Something like this (warning - I haven't even compiled the code, it's a guideline only):

```
float potential_float_value;
std::istringstream could_be_a_float(MyString)
could_be_a_float >> potential_float_value;

return could_be_a_float.fail() ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the level of trust, you need and where the input data comes from.
If the data comes from a user, you have to be more careful, as compared to imported table data, where you already know that all items are either integers or floats and only thats what you need to differentiate.

For example, one of the fastest versions, would simply check for the presence of "." and "eE" in it. But then, you may want to look if the rest is being all digits. Skip whitespace at the beginning - but not in the middle, check for a single "." "eE" etc.

Thus, the q&d fast hack will probably lead to a more sophisticated regEx-like (either call it or scan it yourself) approach. But then, how do you know, that the result - although looking like a float - can really be represented in your machine (i.e. try 1.2345678901234567890e1234567890). Of course, you can make a regEx with "up-to-N" digits in the mantissa/exponent, but thats machine/OS/compiler or whatever specific, sometimes.

So, in the end, to be sure, you probably have to call for the underlying system's conversion and see what you get (exception, infinity or NAN).

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to ignore leading whitespaces as that is what the `atof` function does also:

> The function first discards as many
>   whitespace characters as necessary
>   until the first non-whitespace
>   character is found. Then, starting
>   from this character, takes as many
>   characters as possible that are valid
>   following a syntax resembling that of
>   floating point literals, and
>   interprets them as a numerical value.
>   The rest of the string after the last
>   valid character is ignored and has no
>   effect on the behavior of this
>   function.

So to match this we would:

```
bool isFloat(string s) 
{ 
    istringstream iss(s); 
    float dummy; 
    iss >> skipws >> dummy; 
    return (iss && iss.eof() );     // Result converted to bool 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I was looking for something similar, found a much simpler answer than any I've seen (Although is for floats VS. ints, would still require a typecast from string)

```
bool is_float(float val){
    if(val != floor(val)){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

or:

```
auto lambda_isFloat = [](float val) {return (val != floor(val)); };
```

Hope this helps !

ZMazz

Comment: From the question: determine if a **STRING** value "qualifies" as a floating-point number

Comment: I'm aware, nonetheless most comparisons are between ints and floats to avoid overflow -- the question is already answered w Boost.  I'll qualify my description of it, though I assumed it was obvious.

Comment: So if val is 1.0, then `floor(1.0)` is also 1.0, in which case the function would return false..