# Requiring valid float input from stdin to have precision of 2 in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

Let us say that we are reading a float with std::cin or from a file, and want to enforce the condition that it has two trailing decimal places:

E.g. 
4.01 (valid) 
4.001 (invalid - has three trailing decimal places) 
a,47 (invalid, has two non [0-9] characters in 'a' and ',') 
#556.53 (invalid, has '#')

(Just for context, in my example, I am parsing from a text file with several entries separated by spaces, validating each input, and storing them in a struct for further processing.)

How do we do it?

Comment: You don't mention the language you're using. But this sounds like a job for regular expressions. Something like `\d+\.\d{2}`

Comment: C++ has regexes these days. Are you insisting that the values have exactly two decimal fraction digits, or at most two?

Comment: I am insisting that it has exactly two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I found this from other sources in stackoverflow.

[C++ How to check an input float variable for valid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271315/c-how-to-check-an-input-float-variable-for-valid-input)

Here is the implementation. We read as string and only accept if any of the characters not digits (in perl, I suppose we could simply do a regex non-match [0-9]).

Apparently, the find_first_not_of method in string does this for us:

```
  std::string a;

  if(!(std::cin>>a)){
    std::cout << "Invalid float entry " << std::endl;
  }

  if(a.find_first_not_of("1234567890.-")!=std::string::npos){
    std::cout << "Invalid string to float" << std::endl;}
```

Next, we verify that the string has two decimal places by searching for the location of the decimal point.

```
  if(a.size()-a.find(".")!=3){
    std::cout << "Valid float but must have two decimal places \n";
  }else{
    std::cout << "Accept - valid float and has two decimal places \n";
  }
```

Finally, we convert to float using stof.

```
float u = stof(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C++ compiler and standard library which implement C++11, then you can use a regular expression, which is very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string pattern("[-+]?\\d+\\.\\d\\d$");
    std::regex reg(pattern);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
      std::cout << argv[i]
                << (std::regex_match(argv[i], reg) ? " matched\n" : " didn't match\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That test program takes the values as arguments rather than reading them from a file or stream, but modifying it to use the `istream` is trivial. There is no need to convert the string to a C-string; the first argument to `regex_match` can also be a `std::string`, or it can even be a pair of iterators whose value_type is `char`. In this case it just happened to be convenient to use a `char*`.

[See it live on coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3319083bff16172)

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for the tip on regex_match.