# Validation for float in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, infinite-loop

I am getting input as a float. For example if the user is entering in 3.5 then it works fine.  If user enters in 3.X or any other characters it is causing an infinite loop. is there any way in which i can validate the variable so that user can enter only numbers? I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: "its giving an infinite loop" what's the mysterious "it" that gives you an infinite loop? Please clarify, and perhaps post some code.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned how you are reading the user input, e.g. `scanf` ?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to read the data as a string, then convert it to a float, and see of the entire input string was consumed in that conversion. Boost [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) (for one example) can automate most of that for you.

Comment: which header file i need to add to use this code? will it work in gcc?

Comment: `boost/lexical_cast.hpp`. Yes it works with gcc. If you don't have Boost you can download from boost.org. You can also get pre-built libraries for Windows from [boostpro Computing](http://www.boostpro.com/download/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any sample code, so we can see what you're doing, but I
suspect from the symptoms that you're doing something like:

```
while ( ! input.eof() ) {
    double d;
    input >> d;
    //  do someting with d...
}
```

There are two problems with this: the first is that once an error occurs
(because `'X'` cannot be part of a `double`), the stream memorizes the
error until it is explicitly cleared, so all following input also fails
(and no further characters are extracted from the string).  When you
have a format error in a stream, it is necessary to reset the error
state before continuing.

The second problem with the above is that `input.eof()` doesn't mean
much until after input has failed; it's not a very useful function.
What you probably want to do is:

```
double d;
while ( input >> d ) {
    //  do something with d
}
```

This will stop reading on the first error.  If you want to recover from
errors and continue, then you need something more elaborate:

```
double d;
while ( input >> d || !input.eof() ) {
    if ( input ) {
        //  do something with d...
    } else {
        //  format error...
        input.clear();      //  reset the error state...
        //  advance the stream beyond the error:
        //  read to next white space (or EOF), or at least
        //  advance one character.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it's often more robust to do as others have suggested,
read the input line by line, then scan the line:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
    std::istringstream l( line );
    double d;
    if ( l >> d >> std::ws && d.get() == EOF ) {
        //  do something with d...
    } else {
        //  format error...
        //  we don't have to clear or skip ahead, because we're
        //  going to throw out the istringstream anyway, and the
        //  error didn't occur in the input stream.
    }
}
```

This imposes a much more rigorous format: one value per line, but if
you count the lines, you can output the line number in the error
message; the person who has to correct the bad input will appreciate
that.

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{
  double x = boost::lexical_cast<double>(str); // double could be anything with >> operator.
}
catch(...) { oops, not a number }
```

from: [How to determine if a string is a number with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c)

Comment: which header file i need to add to use this code? will it work in gcc?

Comment: @srinathmkce, it will work with gcc. You need to use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/fp_facets/examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best way for reading a double value from input and assuring it's well formed is reading the input as a string, and then parsing it using the standard [`strtod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/) function included in the `stdlib` library.

For a more detailed explanation on some different possibilities when parsing that string you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c) other post.

Comment: will strtod function work in gcc?

Answer (score 0):

Your post i somewhat unclear, but from what I understand, i think you should use `strtof`.
Get your data from the user as String, than use the function to convert to float and check if succeeded by comparing the pointers.

for more info check the man pages for `strtof`.

Comment: will this function work in gcc complier?

Comment: Yes it will, here's the man page [link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof)

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string a;
  cin>>a;
  float v=strtof(a.c_str(),NULL);
  cout<<v;
} The above code runs in g++ but in gcc it is showing some error. what i have to change?

Comment: What does the error says?

You really should be more verbose.

Comment: /tmp/cc3vq32Q.o: In function `main':
test1.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'

Comment: test1.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `std::cin'
test1.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
test1.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const'

Comment: sorry, its too big.. i couldnt understand the error .