# Create a linked list from space separated input

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a linked list from space separated integer input.

Input:

1. Number of nodes
2. Space separated input

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter number of nodes";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\nEnter data"<<endl;
    int temp;
    lNode *head = NULL;
    while(cin>>temp)
    {
        CreateLinkedList(&head,temp);
    }
    PrintLinkedList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Here I am not getting how to limit the user input to the number of nodes which he has given as first input. Is there any other way to get user input?

Comment: `while(n-- && (cin>>temp))` seems like a possible idea.

Comment: What's not working as you expect?

Comment: @WhozCraig Shouldn't this be `--n`??

Comment: @g-makulik No. If n==1 going in the pre-decrement will drop it to zero and no data will be read. The post-decrement is intentional. side-effect note, btw. `n` will be (-1) when this loop breaks.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yup, just noticed that as well ...

Comment: @WhozCraig: It is not reading any input after the count has exceeded, but the user is able to enter any number of integer until he presses enter. Can we limit the input to n?

Comment: As-written the user must input at least `n` items. Anything beyond that will stay in the input stream. You can clear out unwanted data with `.ignore()`, but if you want actual interactive limits you're going to have to rethink how this is done. It sounds to me like what you're really fighting is std::cin buffering. Warning: **do not flush std::cin.**. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Actually I want to limit the user from entering data after he has entered n values. Any suggestions?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4654636/942596) link should help. How to determine a string is a number. Also use a for-loop to limit the number of entries.

Comment: You cannot stop the user typing, and you cannot stop what the user is typing from appearing in the console window. If you want to do that you are going to have to use much more advanced techniques than `cin`. Really I think you should stop worrying about trivial I/O issues and concentrate on the main point of your program which is *linked lists*.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the input as a string:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
```

Then you can separate the entered numbers in the line using stringstream so you should include the sstream library (eg. `#include <sstream>`):

```
stringstream ss(line);
int number;

while(ss >> number) {
    ... do whatever you want to do with the number here ...
}
```