# Is there a boost lexical_cast equivalent of C# TryParse?

Tags: c#, c++, exception, boost

Intro (from Eric Lippert Blog)
:

> Vexing exceptions are the result of unfortunate design decisions.
>   Vexing exceptions are thrown in a completely non-exceptional
>   circumstance, and therefore must be caught and handled all the time.
>
> The classic example of a vexing exception is Int32.Parse, which throws
>   if you give it a string that cannot be parsed as an integer. But the
>   99% use case for this method is transforming strings input by the
>   user, which could be any old thing, and therefore it is in no way
>   exceptional for the parse to fail. Worse, there is no way for the
>   caller to determine ahead of time whether their argument is bad
>   without implementing the entire method themselves, in which case they
>   wouldn't need to be calling it in the first place.

Now the important part:

> This unfortunate design decision was so vexing that of course the
>   frameworks team implemented TryParse shortly thereafter which does the
>   right thing.

From MSDN Int32.TryParse:

> Return Value Type: System.Boolean true if s was converted
>   successfully; otherwise, false.

So colleague recenly was working on some small bit of code that required checking if a string is a number so after thinking about it and realizing there is no good C++ solution(basically it is a for__each/find_if or boost:lexical_cast try catch) I thought how nice it would be to have `is_convertible` or something from boost?

Ofc i can wrap boost `lexical_cast` and return true at the end of try block and return false at the end of catch block but I prefer existing practice :) solutions.

Comment: As an aside, note that while Eric’s article is very compelling it’s not logically coherent: the exceptions he describes as necessary evils (“exogenous”) aren’t actually necessary – just consider IO: C++ IO streams manage very well to model these conditions without use of exceptions, which Eric describes as necessary.

Comment: sorry I never cared about iostreams (and dont understand the hate they get :D) Do you talk about the fact that they have good(), bad(),... functions?

Comment: Essentially, yes. By default, they signal failure state not via exceptions but via flags, even such states that would raise an “exogenous” exception in .NET.

Comment: idk to be honest I would prefer one uniform way of doing stuff in c++, but  tbh I dont have enough exp with return codes/flags/exceptions so my opinion doesnt really matter. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use boost, then you could use [`boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.try_lexical_convert):

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast/try_lexical_convert.hpp>

std::string str("1.2");
double res;
if(boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert<double>(str, res)){
   //everything normal
}
else{
   //we got a problem
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*> So colleague recenly was working on some small bit of code that required checking if a string is a number so after thinking about it and realizing there is no good C++ solution*

In C++11 you have `std::stol` and/or `std::stod`, which may do what you need.

*Update*
If you don't want to use exceptions, then `strtol(str, &endp)` will do the conversion.

You can check if `str == endp` after the call; if they're the same, then no conversion was possible (since endp will point to the beginning of the unconverted portion of the string)

Like this:

```
strtol(str, &endp);
if (endp==str) { /* no conversion occurred */ }
```

Comment: Hi like I said in Q I prefer not to ab/use try/catch : "Ofc i can wrap boost lexical_cast and return true at the end of try block and return false at the end of catch block but I prefer existing practice :) solutions. "    docs for strol: Exceptions

    std::invalid_argument if no conversion could be performed
    std::out_of_range if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type.

Comment: In that case, take a look at `std::strtol`

Comment: " If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned (0L)." , so isNumber = str=="0" || strtol(str);, but thet woont work for "00","000"... :(

Comment: You can check the end_ptr returned. If it's the same as the pointer you passed in, then no conversion occurred.

Comment: `strtol(str, &endp ); if (endp==str) {}` no conversion occurred.

Comment: hi, please update your answer with last comment so I can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Not really, to be honest, as far as I am aware there is no `try_lexical_cast` but there is two things you can do.

Own is use streams and test that the extraction was successful, not that in most cases `lexical_cast` uses streams anyway internally:

```
 std::string str="56.7";
 std::istringstream ss(str);
 double d;
 if(ss >> d) {
     //passed
 }
 else //failed
```

Or of course as you mention you can wrap `lexical_cast`