# isalpha always returns 0

Tags: c++, string, int, atoi

Here's the code that I'm using it to check whether `key` is a number:

```
string key;
cin>>key;
if(isalpha(atoi(key.c_str())) == 0)
{
     //do something
}
else
    //do something else
```

No matter what I input, `isalpha` always `== 0`.
I tried treating it like a boolean by using `if(isalpha(atoi(key.c_str())))` but it does the same thing.

The key is supposed to be an `int`, but `cin.fail()` and `!(cin>>key)` didn't work either.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `isalpha` tests a char... you are converting a string to an int, and then testing the int for some odd reason.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm using it to check if something is a number. It's to prevent errors.

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion, Something like `try {std::stoi(key);} catch (IForgetWhichException) {//not a number}` will work. Alternatively, `boost::lexical_cast` will also throw an exception for a bad conversion and `strtol` will give error information.

Comment: I thought `.c_str()` turns it back to a char * temporarily @Cthulhu

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question... Anyway, here's an example of it "working": http://ideone.com/xDucNT.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth but if I try something like '1' it doesn't work. I tested 65 like you did and it did though.

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion: yes, that's because the code you've written is (alas) nonsense.  `isalpha` expects a `char`, and checks whether its value corresponds to the ASCII code for an alphabetic character.  So unless your string contains a text representation of such an ASCII code, it will return 0.

Comment: Just check after `c_str()` if input is `> 'a' and < 'z'` and similarly for `A` and `Z`.

Comment: Oh, are these all strings with a length of 1?

Comment: @chris they arent, also according to my compliler stoi isn't part of std.

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion, It's part of C++11 and some versions of libraries with GCC don't quite have it without some extra compiler options.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `key` is a C++ string.

```
string key;
```

This converts the C++ string to a C string.

```
key.c_str()
```

This converts the C string to a number.  An integer.   (`0` if the value can't be converted)

```
atoi(key.c_str())
```

And this checks whether that number is the ASCII code for a letter

```
isalpha(atoi(key.c_str()))
```

You're converting a C++ string to a C string to an integer to an ASCII value, and then checking whether that value is a letter of the alphabet (which won't tell you if it's a number, only whether it's "a letter" or "not a letter")

The if statement you've written will be true only when the user enters **something that is not the numeric ASCII value of a letter**.   E.g. entering `65` will go to the else clause, because `65` is the ASCII code for `'A'`

Try the suggestion @chris kindly offers.

```
try
{
    int the_number = std::stoi(key);
    //do something
}
catch( std::exception& )
{
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining key with no contents and use its t_str method immediately in a case that it returns a char pointer to empty array. Therefore atoi always returns zero.

Please refer here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

On the given example key is empty and atoi parameter is invalid such that atoi always returns zero

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test if the input is numeric or not-:

```
string key;
cin>>key;
if (key.size() && isalpha(*(key.c_str()))
{
    //do something with non-numeric input
}
else
    // numeric input, use atoi to get integer value
```

Comment: If the input was an int, the code would enter the else branch of the if statement. I'm assuming the user cannot be trusted to do the right thing :)

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion careful, that code will assume that `@` or `!abc` or `5andwich` is a number.

Comment: This checks whether the input string is longer than 0 characters AND whether the first character is one of the following: `a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z`, which doesn't seem to be useful validation at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if I use a `for` loop and treat the string as an array, I can check each letter to make sure if it's a number or not.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) for determining whether the string contains a number isn't very lucky choice. If you want to make sure that your string contains only digits, then the best you can do is to iterate through its characters and check each character (you could use [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)).

Then for extraction of integral value from this string, in C++11 you can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), otherwise you could use  [`std::istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/):

```
int val;
std::string key;
// ...
if (std::istringstream(key) >> val)
{
    // success
}
else
{
    // failure
}
```

which will will end up with *success* when `key` starts with a string representing a number. So it will also work for strings like `42abc`, `0x21zzz`, etc. Then it depends on your specific situation, but maybe you won't even need any previous validation in this case.

Related question that might help: [How to determine if a string is a number with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4654636/1168156)

Answer (score 0):

As @suspectus did except iterating through each character in the string and using `isDigit` instead so it doesn't think `!` or `@` is a number.

```
for(int i = 0; i<key.size(); i++)
{
   if(!(isdigit(key[i])))
   {
      //fails
   }
}
```