# CIN to either string or int variable then to overloaded constructor functions

Tags: c++, string, int, auto, cin

Total newb here, so go easy :) I've googled and can't really seem to find an elegant solution to this. I'm doing some coding to learn a few concepts.

I have a class - called 'sally' which has a constructor which is overloaded twice
i.e. my sally.cpp is:

```
#include "sally.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


sally::sally()
{
}
sally::sally(int x)
{
    inputvarint = x;
    cout << "you have an int of value: " << inputvarint << endl;
}

sally::sally(string y)
{
    inputstring = y;
    cout << "you have a string that is: " << inputstring << endl;
}
```

in my main.cpp if I create the object `sally myobj;` and then call the function via the object, i.e. `sally.myobj(55)` I get the correct constructor firing off and telling me I have an INT of value whatever, or if I go `sally.myobj("johhny")` I get the other constructor going and telling me I have a string that says "johnny", so that part I get fine.

What I would like to know is, is there an elegant way I can use CIN to take input from a user, and either pass it straight to the object - without using a variable ( i've tried and can't get it to work ).

Basically, I'd like the user to be able to enter either a string, or an int and use that in the sally.myobj(); call, and let the constructor(s) do the work of figuring out what type of data it is.

things like:
`auto x = 0;` and then `cin >> x` don't work as the initial declaration was an int, so it stays like that.

Is there a way to declare a variable without a type and assign it a type based on the input from CIN?

Apologies if the answer to this is blindingly obvious, but i'm at the very beginning of my journey ( I'm up to about tutorial 40 of this guy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvC1WCdV1XU ) and also reading C++ Primer by Stanley Lippman ( 5th edition ) and The Object-Oriented Thought Process by Matt Weisfield. They are my only resources at present ( that and google ).

Thanks in advance

Seb

EDIT:

After seeing some of the responses below, it helped me figure out what can/can't be done and I've tackled it this way using a parsing function which utilises some Regex, and if string content is deemed to be INT then converts it and places it into a new variable and off to the constructor:

Sally.cpp:

```
#include "sally.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

sally::sally()
{
}
sally::sally(int x)
{
    inputvarint = x;
    cout << "Constructor output: you have an int of value: " << inputvarint << endl;
}

sally::sally(string y)
{
    inputstring = y;
    cout << "Constructor Output: you have a string that is: " << inputstring << endl;
}
void sally::StringParser(string x){

regex e("^[0-9]+$"); //test if the string starts with ends with and has a whole lot of numbers in between, i.e. and INT of any length

bool match = regex_match(x, e);

if(match){
    cout << "you have an int" << endl;
    int newvar = atoi(x.c_str());
    sally::sally(newvar);
}
else {sally::sally(x);}


}
```

then I simply `sally myobj;` and `myobj.StringParser(x);` whereby x is the input from CIN and the Parsing function takes care of the rest and passes it to the constructors.

I'm sure I could build this out a bit with a SWITCH statement with different REGEX's to handle floats etc and then create additional constructors. But For now, I *seem* to have found a solution.

Keen to see if there are any issues with my approach.

Comment: C++ is statically typed. You cannot enter "either an integer or a string". You *always* enter a string. *Sometimes* it may make sense to parse that string as an integer. But that has to be decided at runtime.

Comment: In other words, what you're looking for is a *parser* (or a "lexer" perhaps).

Comment: @Kerrek SB - your comments about parsing gave me a lightbulb moment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is really no way to do that.

What you *can* do is read the input as a string, and then try to convert it to an integer with e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and if it succeeds you have an integer.

---

An alternative which does not throw exceptions is to use [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) instead.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't like the idea of using exceptions to handle normal input parsing logic... I would reserve use of `stoi` for situations where you *know* that you have a string representation of an integer...

Comment: @KerrekSB Then `std::strtol` might be a better solution?

Comment: Yes, that one gives you error handling as part of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think c++ variables must always have a type. IN this case is better to save it as a string and then evaluate it. 
If its a number, convert to int and pass to the constructor:
If its not a number pass the string to the constructor
You can check if its a number using something like this:

```
bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
  std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
  while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

from [How to determine if a string is a number with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c)

For converting the string to an int, there a various ways, but you can try this one:

```
string str = "123";
int numb;
istringstream ( str ) >> numb;
```

So the final idea would be something like:

```
get input as a string
if(input is a number)
{
  convert to number;
  call constructor;
}
else
  call constructor with the string
```

Hope helped you out.

Comment: Unfortunately even this approach still leaves the ambiguity between an 2 and "2". Using the suggested method there's no way to construct **sally("7")** as it will always turn into **sally(7)** instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just assumed that if the input was 7 or any other digit, then it goes as sally(7).

Comment: This was very useful. @mikyra you are right about that, but then, only the user would know if they intended their (7) to be an int or string. I guess I could program in some kind of escape character in case a user wanted to enter a number as a string, and handle it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is not one specific to **C++**,. but a general problem regarding input **encoding**.

Without adding some additional information to your input it is **impossible** to achieve the desired operation.

As you are reading character input if given the input '**2**' there is no chance to make difference between to following two usage scenarios:

- you want to call **sally (2)**
- you want to call **sally ("2")**

You will have to supply some additional (type) information in the input to distinguish between this two cases ("i:2" and "s:2" for example) and try to parse the indicated value.