# How to validate an integer properly in C++?

Tags: c++, validation

I want to validate the input by user to make sure it's an integer (fully). I've tried a few methods, like !cin, but none of them work properly..

Most of methods fail to validate input like this:

```
32tgf
```

When there is a number first and then letters, it doesn't fail, but it takes it as valid entry..

Note: It's a project for college and it's specified that the variable should be of type int.

Comment: You say you've tried methods... where is the code?  How were you unable to find any of the dozens of good existing answers here on StackOverflow?

Comment: What syntax? Leading '+|-' sign? Does it handle hexadecimal, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read into a string, then use e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) to both convert to an integer and validate the input.

Or read into a string, put that string in a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) which you use to extract the integer. Then check if there's anything more in the `istringstream`.

I'd recommend the first method though.

Comment: This still won't work for a case of 32tgf.  The functions you mention will stop at the first non-digit character.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, but they do have arguments that return the position where it stops. If it's not at the end then you don't have a valid input.

Comment: @Thomas: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16575025/103167

Comment: @JoachimPileborg According to the documentation for std::stoi, it takes "31337 with words" as "31337" which is invalid entry in my case.

Comment: @BenVoigt: see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol, unless you can quote from the C++ standard, any algorithm that stops at the first non-digit character satisfies these functions, but still fails with the test case.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Look at the CODE I linked you to.  It handles the test case perfectly fine.

Comment: Demo: http://ideone.com/wZ1fuF

Comment: std::strtol is a C++11 function and I can't use C++11 for this exercise.. any alternative options?

Comment: @user2699298 `std::stoi` is a C++11 function. `std::strtol` is way older.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's weird, because when I go to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoll/ it has a C++11 icon on it.

Comment: @user2699298 `strtoll` compared to `strtol`. One for `long long`, the other (old one) for `long`.