# Prompt user for positive number, and continues to prompt the user until they enter a positive number c++

Tags: c++

```
//review3
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int number;
int main()
{
        cout << "Enter a positive number" << endl;
        cin >> number;
        while (number < 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter a positive number" << endl;
        }
        if (number > 0)
        {
            cout << "Awesome job!" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This is my code so far. I started with an else if but if the user entered a negative number the program would simply close. I changed this to a while loop and got stuck in an infinite loop. Before I had an if and else if statement. I need to continue to prompt the user until they enter a positive number in c++.

Comment: Just put cin >> number; inside the while loop. Below the cout statement.

Comment: So what's your question? You just kind of stopped in the middle of telling us what your question is.

Answer (score 3):

Your `while()` loop doesn't continue to prompt for input, that's why you're getting an infinite loop - because `number` never changes!

You can put the input operation into the `while()` loop like this:

```
while (cin >> number && number < 0)
{
    cout << "Enter a positive number: " << endl;
}

if (cin)
{
    cout << "Awesome job" << endl;
}
```

Thus, during each iteration of the loop the user will be prompted for input.

We check the state of `cin` afterwards to make sure that the above loop didn't stop because of invalid input (or no input at all).

Comment: And what happens if the user enters `"abc"`.  I'd make the loop condition `while ( !(std::cin >> number) || number < 0 )`, and then, in the loop, if there was an error on cin, clear it and ignore the erroneous input.  (Of course, if the error was due to end of file, because the input was redirected from a file, this will lead to an endless loop as well.  So perhaps it should be `while ( (!(std::cin >> number) && !std::cin.eof()) || number < 0 )`.  With an additional check after the loop, since you don't want to output success if the input was redirected from an empty file.)

Comment: And of course, if he's using this solution, he should initialize `number` to something negative before entering the loop.

Comment: @JamesKanze Good idea. But when you say "additional check after the loop", do you mean like my `if (cin)`? Or should it be `if (!cin.eof())`?

Comment: `cin`.  If we break out of the loop, we've either encountered end of file (which means that both `!cin` and `cin.eof()` are true), or we've successfully read a non-negative number, in which case, `cin` is true, but `cin.eof()` may be either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "Pleaase enter a positive number." << std::endl;
        std::string buf;
        int x = -255;
        std::cin >> buf;
        x = std::atoi(buf.c_str());
        if(x > 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Awesome Job!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior if the user enters `"abc"`.

Comment: I am sure that can be fixed by properly initializing x. Lemme fix that real fast!

Comment: So instead of undefined behavior, you have an endless loop.

Comment: How is that going to create an endless loop? It will loop until the correct value is given. Then, it will break out of the loop using that break keyword. It will then display, "Awesome Job!"

Comment: As soon as the user inputs something which isn't a number, `std::cin` will set `failbit`, and all further operations will be no-ops.

Comment: Now I understand. I am a bit confused though, because that code always works for me!
Otherwise, one could also do std::string x and then atoi/stoi

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number;
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a positive number" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    if (number < 0) {
    cout << "Enter a positive number" << endl;
    }
    else {
    cout << "Awesome job!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: More undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you get number or string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c)

sure in this case you should get input to string variable. If you want to convert it to integer you can use [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this snippet . Use `#include <ctype.h> or <cctype>`

```
while(1){
  cin>>number;
  if(number<0 || isalpha(number)) return 0;
  cout<<"Awesome Job";
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior if the user enters `"abc"`.