# Reading a file containing characters in parentheses into a vector of integers

Tags: c++11, vector, integer, text-files, ifstream

I am attempting to read in a file containing characters enclosed in parentheses into a vector of integers.

My text file:

```
(2 3 4 9 10 14 15 16 17 19)
```

Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main(){
  ifstream file;
  file.open("moves.txt");

  vector<int> V;
  char c;

  if (file){
    while (file.get(c)){
      if (c != '(' && c != ')' && c != ' ')
        V.push_back(c - '0');
    }
  }
  else{
    cout << "Error openning file." << endl;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
    cout << V[i] << endl;
}
```

My Output:

```
2
3
4
9
1
0
1
4
1
5
1
6
1
7
1
9
-38
```

Desired output:

```
2 
3 
4 
9 
10 
14 
15 
16 
17 
19
```

What is causing the separation of two digit numbers and why is there a negative number at the end of my output?

Comment: You are reading a character at a time, and converting any non-paren, non-whitespace to a number. Why do you wonder that each character is handled separately? Anyway, take a look at formatted input functions `>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't read characters one by one : read a line, and parse the numbers within it.

By using the `is_number` (c++11) function of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4654718/3510483) :

```
bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(),
        s.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}
```

You can read line by line with [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and then stream the numbers to a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) can be used to convert a string to an integer :

```
 std::string line;
 while(std::getline(file, line))
 {
    line.replace(line.begin(), line.begin() + 1, "");
    line.replace(line.end() - 2, line.end() - 1, "");
    std::string numberStr;
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while (ss >> numberStr){
      if (is_number(numberStr))
        v.push_back(std::stoi(numberStr));
    }
 }
```

You'd have to make the replace more robust (by checking the presence of parentheses at these positions)