# How to forbid the inclusion of non-numbers?

Tags: c++, input

I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i=0;
float reader,  tot = 0;

while(i!=10)
{
    cout << "Insert a number: " << endl;
    cin >> reader;

    if(cin)
    {
        tot += reader;
        i++;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Error. Please retry." << endl;
        cin.clear();
    }
}

cout << "Media: " << tot/i << endl;

return 0;
}
```

In the IF() i want the user to insert ONLY FLOAT VALUES in "reader" variable.
I want that if the user inserts a number, the program continues... else the program should re-ask to the user to insert a correct value.

How to do this checking the INPUT? I tried with a TRY CATCH but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question was asked in [this thread][1]. Have a look at their solutions.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c

Comment: @bruestle2 You should recognize the differences of mini markdown in comments vs markdown in answers. Also we don't have _threads_, but questions and answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original program was fine except you need to skip over that bad input when you get an error. Simply clearing the error is not enough:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits> // include this!!!

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i=0;
float reader, tot = 0.0f; // tot needs to be float

while(i!=10)
{
    cout << "Insert a number: " << endl;

    if( cin >> reader )
    {
        tot += reader;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error. Please retry." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        // Then you ned to skip past the bad input so you
        // don't keep tripping the same error
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}

cout << "Media: " << tot/i << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The function `cin.ignore()` ignores as many input characters as possibly up until the end-of-line character `'\n'`. The `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` function tells us the maximum number possible characters that can be stored in an input buffer.

If it is confusing an alternate way to skip the bad input would be to simply read up to the next line into a `std::string`.

```
    else
    {
        cout << "Error. Please retry." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        // Then you need to skip past the bad input so you
        // don't keep tripping the same error
        std::string skip;
        std::getline(cin, skip); // read the bad input into a string
    }
```

Comment: OH FINE! It works! But, can you explain me what does cin.ignore(...) do?

Comment: @Michele I added a little explanation about the `cin.ignore()` function. I also added an alternative that is less efficient but maybe more understandable.

Answer (score 3):

> *"How to do this checking the INPUT?"*

It's already ensured by

```
cin >> reader;
```

that only valid `float` values can be entered by the user. The way to check for validity is

```
if( cin >> reader ) {
   tot += reader;
   i++;
}
else {
   cout << "Error. Please retry." << endl;
   cin.clear();
   std::string dummy;
   cin >> dummy; // <<< Read invalid stuff up to next delimiter
}
```

Here's the [fully working sample](http://ideone.com/a8s1Yx).

---

> *"I tried with a TRY CATCH but it didn't work."*

To get exceptions from `std::istream` operations, set the [`std::istream::exceptions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) mask.

Comment: Or, more succinctly: `if (cin>>reader)`. Also, you will often want to `std;:cin.ignore(largenumber, '\n')` to ignore remaining input on the same input line. Finally, you will not want to retry if the state is `eof()` or `bad()`. +1

Comment: Uhm... when I insert an incorrect value (just like a letter) the program says to me: "Error. Please retry." CONTINUALLY!

Comment: @Michele Sorry I've been missing eating up the bad characters from the wrong input. See update.

Answer (score 2):

Just check the result of `operator>>`:

```
if (cin >> reader) {
    // user gave you a float
    tot += reader;
    i++;
}
else {
    cout << "Error. Please retry." << endl;

    // clear the error flag on cin, and skip
    // to the next newline.
    cin.clear(); 
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: Which technically is equivalent to `if (cin)` it the original code.

Comment: THANKS! But, in this way, when I insert an incorrect value (like a letter) the program prints "Error. Please retry." continually!!!

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Exactly equivalent, yeah, but I think this is safer - keep the condition and action together.

Comment: @Michele One question per question please!

Comment: @Barry I updated the source code as you said... still does not work!

Comment: @Michele Even with the `ignore()`?

Comment: @Michele please stop shouting at everyone.