# Simplest way to check for any number in a string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What would be the easiest and simplest beginner friendly way to check for any number in a input string, if it finds number return error.

Comment: Define "any number". 1? -1? 123.123? ---12.84e19? three? 零番目?  ①?

Comment: Need more details. Are you checking that a string contains no digits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a string is a number with C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way will be to check the entire string, character by character and see if it is a number of not.

```
std::string yourString;

for(int i=0;i<yourString.size();i++)
{
    if(yourString[i]<='9' && yourString[i]>='0')
    {
         std::cout << "Err" << std::endl;
         break;
    }
}
```

Another solution will be to use a regex. A regex that check if a number is present is \d

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called isdigit, which checks whether its input is a decimal digit. Hope this helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        string s = "abc1abc";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if(isdigit(s[i])) {
                        cout << "Found numer at pos: " << i << endl;
                        return -1;
                }
        }
        return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/). Just look for a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 or 0 and if you find one return an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::find_if` and `std::isdigit` to check whether a string has a number or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool hasNumber(std::string const& s)
{
   return (std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return std::isdigit(c); }) != s.end());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   for ( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i )
   {
      if ( hasNumber(argv[i]) )
      {
         std::cout << "'" << argv[i] << "' contains a number.\n";
      }
      else
      {
         std::cout << "'" << argv[i] << "' does not contain a number.\n";
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

When run with:

```
./prog abcd12 12akdk akdk1dkdk akske
```

The output is:

```
'abcd12' contains a number.
'12akdk' contains a number.
'akdk1dkdk' contains a number.
'akske' does not contain a number.
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple:

```
boost::algorithm::any(str, std::isdigit)
```

And if you don't link with boost:

```
std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isdigit)
```