# Test for data types in C++

Tags: c++

Please, how do I test for data types in C++, for instance if am expecting an input from a user and I want to check if the user enter an int, a double, a char or a boolean.

Comment: What's `5` ? int or char? or double?

Comment: This might help, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c

Comment: If you read the input into a `std::string`, you can test each type with [`boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html).

Answer (score 0):

You read the input into a string ([`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)), then attempt to parse it. [`strtod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) checking if it parses as a double (via the end pointer). If that fails, [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) to check if it parses as an int. I *assume* you mean "true" / "false" for the bool so you'd do a string `==` on those. And if all that fails, use it as a verbatim string.

All that is highly fragile, of course. The user might enter decimal commas or decimal points. He might add a whitespace after "true". All that stuff...

If you are looking for *real* parsing, [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) would be the place to look for, but that is very involved and more for production-level parsers so I doubt that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yaaa, you are right I was actually looking for something simpler, just like in PHP where you can use var_dump() to get the data type of a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately plain old data types in C++ are just raw bytes of memory. No meta information.