# if condition too long and including for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, if-statement

Hi I am a C++ beginner and here is a problem I am facing when writing a function.

The bool function `isData` is used to see whether the array members are all numbers. Usually the size will be 11 or 9 or 7 so I don't want to hard code it. But I am not sure whether for loop work in if condition. And I will be so grateful if you can show me an easier way to do this.

```
bool isData(string temp[], int size)
{
  if(
      for (int i;i<size;i++) 
      {
        59 > +temp[i].at(0) && +temp[i].at(0) > 47 || +temp[i].at(0) == 45
      }
    )
    {
      return true;
    }
  else 
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably don't know `std::all_of` ? I assume you're working from a quite old C++ tutorial, since that `string[]` is about 20 years old. That predates even the 1998 variant of C++, while `std::all_of` is only 6 years old (2011)

Comment: You can't use a for loop as a condition of an if statement.  The condition needs to be an expression and a for loop is not an expression.

Comment: Additionally, a test for `is_digit` is more legible than checking the ASCII values yourself. And checking for `== '-'` would be more legible than checking against 45.

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c

Comment: `for (int i;i<size;i++)` What is `i`'s initial value?

Comment: You could use a lambda in the if, but why not just make it a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loops doesn't result in `true` or `false`, so `for` in an `if` won't work.

instead, run all elements in a for loop and return `false` if you find a non-number. Otherwise, return `true`.

*Pseudo code* for that would be something like this

```
bool isData(String temp[], int size) {
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        if( hasOnlyDigits(temp[i]) ) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`hasOnlyDigits` is a function that would take in  `string` and check if it's a valid number.

Here is a one liner for *positive numbers*. `bool hasOnlyDigits = (temp[i].find_first_not_of( "0123456789" ) == string::npos);`

It's non trivial to implement a function which handles **all** inputs like `+.23`, `-33--33`. Implement a function that can handle inputs within your input constraints.

I'll update this answer if I find a robust way to check.

Comment: @JanKhonski Thanks :). There was a typo there. I edited it now.

Comment: OK, but consider negative numbers as well.

Comment: what if there is a string --33-33. It will pass your test. Create a unit test for a method isNumber.

Comment: @JanKhonski I'm solving that and I'll be back with an edit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried it and it works perfectly for now. And thanks for the detailed explanation:-)

Answer (score 1):

if (boolean_expression)
You cannot put expression that returns nothing inside of **if**.

```
bool isData(string temp[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        char* p;
        long converted = strtol(temp[i], &p, 10);
        if (*p) 
        {
            // conversion failed because the input wasn't a number
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And check this:
[How to determine if a string is a number with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c)

For double you need to use **strtod** and instead of long use double.

Comment: Worse, a `for` statement is not an expression at all.

Comment: `if (*p)`? Did you mean `if (p)`?

Comment: @Jan Khonski will this handle negative and decimals?

Comment: I added a link how to check if a number. **strtod** - it will return double https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575025/4587961

Comment: @BoundaryImposition **if (*p)? Did you mean if (p)?** - No. if (p) will be true even when conversion is successful.

Comment: @JanKhonski: What are you trying to achieve with `if (*p)`?

Comment: if `temp` is either a number (and only a number), or empty, `p` will be pointing at `\0`.  If `temp` is not a number, or is a number follwed by non-numerical characters, `p` will be pointing at said character.  I think he probably wanted `!*p` since a 0 here indicates success.

Comment: Although I'm not sure what the for loop is for, since he's running `strtol` on the exact same thing every time.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I checked the link and almost understand how it works. It is just when I put that into my codes and run it, there will be an error suggestion says that the "temp" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char"...so I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile with C++11 then you can use `std::stoi`. Similar to one of the answers above but with better error checking and ensuring loop runs over the whole array of strings.

```
bool isData(std::string temp[], int str_size)
{

    bool ret_val = false;
    size_t current_len, processed_len;
    for (int i=0; i < str_size; i++) {
        current_len = temp[i].size();
        try {
            int hidden_num = std::stoi(temp[i], &processed_len);
            std::cout << hidden_num << std::endl;
            if (processed_len == current_len) {
                ret_val = true;
                continue;
            }
        } catch (std::invalid_argument& e) {
            std::cout << "Non-integer input at index " << i << std::endl;
            ret_val = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unnecessary:

```
if (...some complicated boolean expression...) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

All you need to do is:

```
return ...some complicated boolean expression...;
```