# How do I successfully clear streams?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a program that needs to find abundant, deficient and perfect numbers - according to Greek numerology. What represents an issue here is ensuring that only natural numbers are inserted; more specifically making sure that there are no letters inserted.
I tried checking if stream was "broken", if true, print appropriate message. It works, but only once, and I can't figure out why.
Here's the code.

```
 #include <iostream>
 int main ()
{
double n(0);
int sum(0);
int i(0);

std::cout << "Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: ";
std::cin >> n;

int n1 = n;
do {
    for(i = 1; i < n1; i++) {
        if(n1 % i == 0) {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    if(!std::cin) {
        std::cout << "Not a natural number!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: ";
    }
    else if(n != int(n)) {
        std::cout << "Not a natural number!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: ";
    }
    else if(n1 < 0) {
        std::cout << "Not a natural number!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: ";
    }
    else if(suma < n1) {
        std::cout << "Number " << n << " is deficient!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: ";
    }
    else if(suma > n1) {
        std::cout << "Number " << n << " is abudant!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: ";
    }
    else if(suma == n1) {
        std::cout << "Number " << n << " is perfect!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: ";
    }
    suma = 0;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    std::cin >> n;
    n1 = int(n);
} while(n != 0);
std::cout << "Goodbye!";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you accept `double`s, only to reject non-integers later on?

Comment: It appears to work only when the value is inserted with the `cin` that's outside the loop.

Comment: @Quentin How else do I check if it's a natural number? It mustn't have any decimal spaces. If I declare it as an `int`, anything that user enters after the `.` won't even be stored in memory, preventing me from checking the nature of a number.

Comment: How will `n` ever be input a second time if you `std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); std::cin >> n;`? How can a user ever time his input between the `.ignore` and subsequent `cin`??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4654636/16582

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin those two lines will "recover" the stream.

Comment: @ravenspoint Not allowed to use functions, it's for a college course. We're switching from C to C++, so nothing but basics is allowed for completing the task.

Comment: Nothing gets more basic than the standard c library

Comment: I don't understand, what is the purpose of `n != int(n)`?  The `n` variable is already an int.  The `cin >> n` will only input an integer.  So what is the meaning of `n != int(n)`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `n` is a `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be one of logic. You prompt for reinput of `n`, then

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
std::cin >> n;
```

That will not "recover" the stream, that will discard the user input of `'n'` leaving you stuck. It appears you need to reorder your input and loop to handle the input once per iteration. Something similar to the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {

    double n(0);

    do {
        int sum(0);
        int i(0);

        std::cout << "Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: ";
        std::cin >> n;
        int n1 = n;

        for(i = 1; i < n1; i++)
            if(n1 % i == 0)
                sum+=i;

        if(n != int(n))
            std::cout << "Not a natural number!" << std::endl;
        else if(n1 < 0)
            std::cout << "Not a natural number!" << std::endl;
        else if(sum < n1)
            std::cout << "Number " << n << " is deficient!" << std::endl;
        else if(sum > n1)
            std::cout << "Number " << n << " is abudant!" << std::endl;
        else if(sum == n1)
            std::cout << "Number " << n << " is perfect!" << std::endl;

        sum = 0;

    } while(n != 0);

    std::cout << "Goodbye!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Neither `.ignore` or `.clear` are necessary. Leading whitespace is ignored for numeric conversion and `.clear` simply sets `'goodbit'` on the stream which has the effect of clearing all error flags. (see [std::basic_ios::clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)) There is also no real need to check `if (!std::cin)`. It doesn't hurt, it is just superfluous to your code.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inputnumber
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 128
Number 128 is deficient!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 30
Number 30 is abudant!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 37
Number 37 is deficient!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 2
Number 2 is deficient!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 1
Number 1 is deficient!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 10
Number 10 is deficient!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 12
Number 12 is abudant!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 0
Number 0 is perfect!
Goodbye!
```

I'm not 100% clear on your goal, so if I misunderstood, please drop a comment and I'm happy to help further.

---

**Making Your Input Discard Non-Numbers**

Rose, after the discussions in the comments, it appears your issue was with `n1` being assigned `0` in the event there was an input error (like a cat stepping on the keyboard resulting in `";sdkfgj"` being input). That too can be handled, and you were on the right track looking at both `.clear` and `.ignore`. Hereto, there is a bit of logic in how you put that together.

When faced with the problem of "How do I make sure the user only enters 'X'?", the normal approach is to loop continually until the user input satisfies the conditions you have set for accepting input. Here, you want a numeric value input. So the approach would be to loop, prompting for input, and then checking the stream state after the user inputs a value. If the stream is in error, you need to `.clear()` the error, and then `.ignore(..., ...)` up to the `'\n'`. (you can use the values in `<limits>` to disable the character count check and discard whatever number of characters may be present)

This leaves a slight problem. You are looping for input within a loop to begin with. If the user enters `0` to indicate here would like to exit, then you must break both loops to get to `"Goodbye!\n";`. While you can set flags, etc., the lowly `goto` is still the standard, and efficient, way to jump out of nested loops.

Putting it altogether, now understanding a bit more about your problem, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main (void) {

    double n(0);

    do {
        int sum(0), n1(0);

        while (n1 == 0) {
            std::cout << "Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: ";
            std::cin >> n;
            if (!std::cin) {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),
                                '\n');
            }
            else if (n == 0)
                goto alldone;
            else
                n1 = n;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < n1; i++)
            if (n1 % i == 0)
                sum += i;

        if(n != int(n))
            std::cout << "Not a natural number!" << std::endl;
        else if(n1 < 0)
            std::cout << "Not a natural number!" << std::endl;
        else if(sum < n1)
            std::cout << "Number " << n << " is deficient!" << std::endl;
        else if(sum > n1)
            std::cout << "Number " << n << " is abudant!" << std::endl;
        else if(n1 && sum == n1)
            std::cout << "Number " << n << " is perfect!" << std::endl;

        sum = 0;

    } while(n != 0);

    alldone:;
    std::cout << "Goodbye!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inputnumber
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: apples
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: banannas
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 128
Number 128 is deficient!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 96
Number 96 is abudant!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: foo
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 2
Number 2 is deficient!
Enter a natural number or 0 for exit: 0
Goodbye!
```

Let me know if that is the area that was giving your problems.

Comment: Yeah, but if you enter a letter, it'll crash. It has to send the same message as it does for `<0` and `!=int(n)`

Comment: No, it won't, it will assign `0` to `n1` and clear the stream. (try it -- enter `"apples"` for one of the numbers)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is true since C++11. Before that, the value was left unchanged, and in this particular case, undefined.

Comment: I guess it was my bad for not being clear enough. My sole problem was assignment of `0` to `n1`.

Comment: You fix that with `else if(n1 && sum == n1)` (if you want to avoid outputting `0` as `perfect`)

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much it, I eventually did it, but your solution is a bit more prettier for the eye to look at it. Thanks alot!

Comment: Sorry it took a while to snap to the part of the right part of the problem that was giving you trouble. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

So the only problem was assignment of `0` to `n1`. When the stream "gets broken", that is it receives input that doesn't corresponds to the variable type, it get's to an undefined state, which has to be cleared with `.clear` and `.ignore`, which again, leaves it hanging with `0` value, resulting in ending the loop.
My solution is perhaps the most primitive one out there. Just assign a random integer value to `n1`, and case closed. It will not affect other `if`s, as only the first one will be executed, and it will also prevent loop from breaking.
So just: 
     `if(!(std::cin >> n)) {
            std::cout << "Not a natural number!" << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            n = 1;
        }`

Comment: See my updated answer. I added a section for you on just that point.