# How to Print input value

Tags: c++

I have the following bit of code that I'm using to check whether an input is a multiple of 3, 5 or Both. If the user does not enter a number I would like it to print the value stored in UserInput. At the moment it is just returning 0, any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int UserInput;

    cout << "Please enter a number:";
    cin >> UserInput;

    if (!cin) {
        cout << UserInput;
    }

    else if ((UserInput%3 == 0) && (UserInput%5 == 0)) {
             cout << "FizzBuzz";
    }

    else if (UserInput%3 == 0) {
             cout << "Fizz";
    }

    else if (UserInput%5 == 0) {
             cout << "Buzz";
    }

}
```

Comment: What did you enter?

Comment: Have a look at this to check whether ```cin``` is a number or not : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c

Comment: *If the user does not enter a number I would like it to print the value stored in `UserInput`.* In that case, `UserInput` will be set to zero if you use C++11 or later. Do you really want to print that or do you want to print what the user entered?

Comment: I am completely new to C++ so still learning the basics, @RSahu I want it to print what the user enters.

Answer (score 1):

If the user input cannot be read into an `int`, `cin` is placed in a fail state and nothing is read. The contents of `UserInput` are useless to you. You will have to take `cin` out of the error state with [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) and read the stream into something guaranteed to be able to hold the user's input like a `std::string`.

```
if (std::cin >> UserInput) // Get input and make sure input was read check for good input
{
    // do the fizbuzz thing.
}
else
{
    std::cin.clear(); // remove the error flags set by reading a non-number
    std::string badinput;
    getline(std::cin, badinput); // read the bad input.
    std::cout << "User input: " << badinput << std::endl; // write the bad input 
}
```