# How can I check if the data in a string is a number on C++?

Tags: c++, string, validation, numbers, stringstream

I am new to C++ . If the user enters a string with different information that is separated by a delimiter, eg `#`, and I use string manipulation to extract the info into different variables, how would I check if one of the string variables contain a number? In the simplest way possible (beginner).

eg.

```
John#Doe#51
Name - John
Surname - doe
Age - 51
```

How do I make sure that the user typed a number for age?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a string is a number with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::stoi()` or related function checking for errors, or put the extracted string into a `std::istringstream` and read an integer from it using `operator>>` checking for errors.

Or, just use `std::istringstream` to parse the entire delimited string to begin with. No need to extract substrings and convert them manually.