# c++ parse int from string

Tags: c++, string, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

I have done some research and some people say to use atio and others say it's bad, and I can't get it to work anyways.

So I just want to ask flat out, whats the right way to convert a string to a int.

```
string s = "10";
int i = s....?
```

Thanks!

Comment: you probably meant (`std::`)`string s = "10"`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200090/how-do-you-convert-a-c-string-to-an-int and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c

Comment: @lijie - maybe, but I never say that in my code... should I be?

Comment: @adam - hmm, look like great solutions, unfortunatly no stackoverflow results came up on google, and i didn't see those when I was typing in my question.

Comment: @kralco626: i mean the quotation marks. you want to convert the _string_ "10" into the integer 10, right?

Comment: @kralco626: yes the search isn't always that successful :/

Comment: I suggest starting parseinttostring.stackexchange.com. It's not the depth of the answer but the number of people asking this question.

Comment: parsestringtoint.stackexchange.com or parseintfromstring.stackexchange.com you mean :)

Comment: wow... never had a question closed on me before... boy do I feel like a failure...

Comment: I'm yet to see a solution that someone has not called either inefficient or unsafe... I think the best solution is just to use Java! `int num = Integer.parseInt(new String("10"));`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

- In C++11, use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) as:

  ```
   std::string s = "10";
   int i = std::stoi(s);
  ```

  Note that `std::stoi` will throw exception of type `std::invalid_argument` if the conversion cannot be performed, or `std::out_of_range` if the conversion results in overflow(i.e when the string value is too big for `int` type). You can use [`std::stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or [`std:stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) though in case `int` seems too small for the input string.
- In C++03/98, any of the following can be used:

  ```
   std::string s = "10";
   int i;

   //approach one
   std::istringstream(s) >> i; //i is 10 after this

   //approach two
   sscanf(s.c_str(), "%d", &i); //i is 10 after this
  ```

Note that  the above two approaches would fail for input `s = "10jh"`. They will return 10 instead of notifying error. So the safe and robust approach is to write your own function that parses the input string, and verify each character to check if it is digit or not, and then work accordingly. Here is one robust implemtation (untested though):

```
int to_int(char const *s)
{
     if ( s == NULL || *s == '\0' )
        throw std::invalid_argument("null or empty string argument");

     bool negate = (s[0] == '-');
     if ( *s == '+' || *s == '-' ) 
         ++s;

     if ( *s == '\0')
        throw std::invalid_argument("sign character only.");

     int result = 0;
     while(*s)
     {
          if ( *s < '0' || *s > '9' )
            throw std::invalid_argument("invalid input string");
          result = result * 10  - (*s - '0');  //assume negative number
          ++s;
     }
     return negate ? result : -result; //-result is positive!
}
```

This solution is slightly modified version of [my another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620437/string-const-char-size-t-to-int).

Comment: In general I'd avoid `atoi` in user-provided input, since, when you get a 0, you don't know if it is because the string contained `"0"` or because it was invalid.

Comment: Atoi and itoa often cause problems so I would recommend avoiding these functions. I would use boost or stringstream instead.

Comment: good for a quick project though because of it's simplicity

Comment: I'm yet to see a solution that someone has not called either inefficient or unsafe... I think the best solution is just to use Java! `int num = Integer.parseInt(new String("10"));`

Comment: Yes Java has robust library for such common tasks. However your Java example is wrong - You shouldn't allocate new instance for string literals.

Comment: ah yes, I was thinking C# where there is a difference.

Comment: uh what? in C# you'd write `int.Parse("10")` (or use `TryParse` to avoid an exception)

Comment: BTW std::stoi doesnt work in lastest cygwin c++ compiler (as for 14NOV2015)

Answer (score 14):

You can use [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
std::string s1 = "10";
std::string s2 = "abc";
int i;

   try   {
      i = boost::lexical_cast<int>( s1 );
   }
   catch( boost::bad_lexical_cast & e ){
      std::cout << "Exception caught : " << e.what() << std::endl;
   }

   try   {
      i = boost::lexical_cast<int>( s2 );
   }
   catch( boost::bad_lexical_cast & e ){
      std::cout << "Exception caught : " << e.what() << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: boost lexical_cast is very very very slow. also they fact that it requires exception handling makes it even more cubersome to use. only good for input that comes in at user speeds, nothing else.

Comment: @dman: indeed lexical_cast is slower than atoi/strtol/sscanf but 1) the OP did not ask about the fastest way (and the question is tagged c++) 2) lexical_cast is generic solution and being part of Boost can tell you some things about the quality of the implementation 3) bad_lexical_cast exception provides you with a way to detect conversion errors, small price to pay for proper error handling 4) if lexical_cast your bottleneck it's pretty easy to implement a specialization for your data types

Comment: +1 on this. I like your argument, and I actually like the solution. Being a Java person I like try catch and would likely use this solution in the future.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/).

```
string s = "10";

// create an input stream with your string.
istringstream is(str);

int i;
// use is like an input stream
is >> i;
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no "right way". If you want a universal (but suboptimal) solution you can use a `boost::lexical cast`.

A common solution for C++ is to use `std::ostream` and  `<< operator`. You can use a `stringstream` and `stringstream::str()` method for conversion to string.

If you really require a fast mechanism (remember the 20/80 rule) you can look for a "dedicated" solution like [C++ String Toolkit Library](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html)

Best Regards,
Marcin

Comment: "There is no'right way'" - you gotta love a language where there is no "right way" to parse a string... :(

Answer (score 7):

Some handy quick functions (if you're not using Boost):

```
template<typename T>
std::string ToString(const T& v)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << v;
    return ss.str();
}

template<typename T>
T FromString(const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    T ret;
    ss >> ret;
    return ret;
}
```

Example:

```
int i = FromString<int>(s);
std::string str = ToString(i);
```

Works for any streamable types (floats etc). You'll need to `#include <sstream>` and possibly also `#include <string>`.

Comment: This is the solution boost::lexical_cast uses

Comment: Actualla boost::lexical_cast doesn't use the original std string-streams, but some tweaked stream class that should make it a little faster than these functions. Also it includes error-checking (including the check if the input was fully consumed by the extraction operator), so it's much safer to use than those two functions.