# C++ Read int from istream, detect overflow

Tags: c++, stream

If I read an integer from a istream using the >> operator, and the represented integer larger than INT_MAX then the operation just returns INT_MAX.

I am currently doing a comparison against INT_MAX to detect the overflow, but if the operation is inputted "2147483647" then it will return an error when in reality there was none and the result is valid.

Example: http://ideone.com/4bXyGd

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <climits>

int main() {
    std::istringstream st("1234567890123"); // Try with 2147483647
    int result;

    st >> result;

    if (result == INT_MAX)
        std::cout << "Overflow!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What is the ideologically correct way to do this?

Comment: Workaround: use `long long`.

Comment: Declare, that valid input is up to `2147483646`, not up to `2147483647` :) (2147483647 is MAX_INT on your platfrom)

Comment: You should prefer `<limits>` over `<climits>` when using C++. `INT_MAX` is replaced by `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Comment: @Lol4t0, since this is part of a scanner for C source code files, I don't think that will work. Good idea @H2CO3, not guaranteed to work (though I don't know of a system where a `long long` is the same size as an `int`, the standard does allow it).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442658/c-parse-int-from-string

Comment: @CarlNorum, In which case INT_MAX is different. It's not that specific number that is causing problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For general parsing failures (including the number being too large or too small) you can simply check the [fail bit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) of the stringstream has been set. The easiest way to do this is:

```
if (!st) {
    std::cout << "Could not parse number" << std::endl;
}
```

Before C++11 there was no way to check specifically for overflow or underflow using this method. However in C++11 if the parsed value would be too large or too small small for the type, the result will be set to the largest value the type can hold (`std::numeric_limits<Type>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<Type>::min()`),  in addition to the fail bit being set.

So in C++11 to check if the value was too large or small you can do:

```
if (!st) {
    if (result == std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) {
        std::cout << "Overflow!" << std::endl;
    } else if (result == std::numeric_limits<int>::min()) {
        std::cout << "Underflow!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Some other parse error" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to read the value as a string and then convert it into an integer. During the conversion, you can catch whether the value fits within the range of the type you're converting to.

`boost::lexical_cast` is a good library for this. It will throw an exception if the value cannot fit in the target type.

Comment: If I'm going to read it into a string first then I could just do a string comparison against the max value.