# how can I check integer overflow in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

I want to know how to determine overflow in C/C++. if my input for integer is 9999999999999999999999 , It is a very big number and if I run the below code I will get a garbage output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to know , if the input is a big number, I can output "Input is too big" .

Note that, I have already checked [How to detect integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c) . But the question is different from my one.

Comment: Is this C or C++? In C++ you should probably use stream operations following [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116690/c-read-int-from-istream-detect-overflow).

Comment: This question is not at all a duplicate of that one.  That one is about detecting overflow happening due to arithmetic operations.  This question is about handling string input which, if parsed as an integer, would not fit into the specified integer type.

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787892/overflow-over-scanf8s-string

Comment: @rightfold: C and C++ share a common subset.  Don't remove C++ tags from questions about code which lies in that subset. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158450/retagging-c-questions-as-c-without-consulting-asker

Comment: @Kninnug , I have checked that question. My question is different from it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Thank you for understanding my question.

Comment: Any solution would work for me. Either in C or C++ @DavidBrown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, read the input in a string and then, depending of the length, make a decision. You can encode in string the limits of integer, long long etc and if the input has the length (the number of figures) equal or less than one of your string limits, move one with the comparison and if it is smaller than the string representation of a limit, you can safely convert it to an integer type.

**UPDATE**

or if you prefer you can use stream operators in C++ as David Brown suggested...

Comment: @Md.Al-Amin have you checked David Brown's answer? It is a pretty way to check for what you want, just take a look at the first response for the linked question.

Comment: Yes, I checked David Brown's answer. But I didn't get it. I want to take input from the terminal, I mean stdin.

Comment: @Md.Al-Amin very well, read the input using std::cin in a std::string and then call the **istringstream** initialization constructor with the string you read as a parameter. Check this page for more details about **istringstream** : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/

Comment: Sure, I will :) @asalic

Comment: Checking the number of digits isn't enough. For example if `INT_MAX ==  2147483647`, you'd eliminate any number above `999999999`.

Comment: @KeithThompson No I wouldn't because I would take into account the numbers with 10 digits and less not numbers with 9 digits and less. If it has 9 or less it is okay no comp is needed, if it has 10, then do the comparison...

Comment: You don't say how to do the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

As posted in comments there is a way to detect overflow after arithmetic operation, which is partially helpful in this case:

What you can do is to read char by char and check for overflow at every step:
(Not sure if you use C or C++, either include `<limits>` or `<limits.h>`)

```
int x=0;
while(1){
 char c='\0';
 scanf(" %c",&c);
 if (c<'0' || c>'9')
  break;//Input finished
 if (!willOverflow(x,c-'0'))
  x=x*10+c-'0';
 else
  break;//Overflow would happen, handle code belongs here
}

int willOverflow(int cur,int next){//Perform your overflow check
//for example i would use
 return ((INT_MAX-next)/10)<cur);
}
```

Comment: I do not think it is the right test anyway, but you let the arithmetic overflow happen when you write `(x*10+(c-'0'))`. Signed arithemtic overflow is undefined behavior, this allows the compiler to generate the code it wants, including to optimize away the entire test and `else` branch.

Comment: You are right, the overflow check "might" or "might not" work. I have modified the check. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Yes, I think it is fine now. There are more versions than you might want to see (both correct and incorrect) in the answers to a “challenge” by John Regehr: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/914

Answer (score 2):

This catches other errors as well as overflow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    try {
        std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<int>(line) << "\n";
    } catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Boost of course is non-standard, you'll have to install it for your system. Failing that, or if you want the library function to distinguish input "99999999999" from "123abc" for you then you'll have to use `std::stoi` or `std::strtol`. Both are somewhat less convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check for overflow of numbers read from input, but `scanf` is not the way to do it. Calling `scanf("%d", &n)` when the input number is too big to be represented as an `int` actually has *undefined behavior*. (IMHO this is very unfortunate, and makes `scanf` nearly impossible to use safely for numeric input.)

But the `strto*` functions:

- `strtol` (for `long`)
- `strtoll` (for `long long`)
- `strtoul` (for `unsigned long`)
- `strtoull` (for `unsigned long long`)
- `strtof` (for `float`)
- `strtod` (for `double`)
- `strtold` (for `long double`)

though they're a bit more difficult to use, have well defined behavior for all inputs.

Use `fgets` to read a line of input, then use one of the `strto*` functions to convert the input to a number of the appropriate type.

On overflow, these functions return the minimum or maximum value of the appropriate type and set `errno` to `ERANGE`. You should set `errno` to `0` before the call. (Checking `errno` setting lets you distinguish between an overflow and an actual input of, say, `2147483647`.)

Read the man documentation for the appropriate function for the gory details.

Since there's no `strtoi` function for `int`, you can use `strtol`, check whether the input was a valid `long`, and then check whether the `long` value is in the range `INT_MIN` .. `INT_MAX`; similarly for `unsigned int` and `strtoul`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading in a string and then checking the string is the way to go, if you need to check for such a thing.