# Why i am getting output in cout (0 16) even i dont enter any input value in cin

Tags: c++, input, output, cin, cout

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int a;
int b;
cin >> a >> b;
cout << a <<" "<<b;     
}
OutPut: 0 16
```

Your help will be apreciated Thanks in Advance!
i tried by putting different input value , the results are ok , but if i dont enter any cin value the                                     results on cout are making me confuse so i want to clear it!

Comment: How do you *run* the program?

Comment: What do you type (before pressing Enter) that makes `std::cin` go bad? It is likely that you are entering non-numeric characters. That will cause `std::cin` to fail, and your variables `a` and `b` will not be updated. Since `a` and `b` are not initialized, in theory, they could hold any random values. When `std::cin` fails, those random values are what `std::cout` will display.

Comment: Try `if (cin >> a >> b) { cout << a << " " << b; }`

Comment: On a different note: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Any learning resource that tells you to use this should be thrown away.

Comment: You haven't described what input you are providing.   But, `cin >> a >> b` first attempts to read `a`, and then `b`.  if an error occurs when extracting `a`,  then `a` will be set to zero and the stream will be in an error state.   That error state will cause the subsequent reading of `b` to fail, and leave `b` unmodified.    Since `b` is uninitialised, it's initial value is indeterminate (and accessing that value causes undefined behaviour) - a value of `16` is one possibility, but not the only possibility.

Comment: Even this little bit of code shows you the importance of checking your input before continuing to use it. There is one thing you should never forget when coding **"Never trust your input"**.

Comment: *"f i dont enter any cin value the results on cout are making me confuse ..."* See the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41623168/12002570)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it reaches the end-of-file on std::cin and it causes an internal error. Instead of throwing an exception or blocking, it goes ahead without modifying anything. What you are seeing is uninitialized garbage.

You can see what this program does:

```
    #include <iostream>
    int main(){
        int a = -1;
        int b = -2;
        std::cout << std::cin.good() << std::endl;
        std::cin >> a; 
        std::cout << std::cin.good() << std::endl;
        std::cin >> b;
        std::cout << std::cin.good() << std::endl;
        std::cout << a <<" "<<b;     
    }
```

Outputs:

```bash
1
0
0
-1 -2
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Gbc4zj4ve

Compare that with when you add input to cin, eg `1 2`

```bash
1
1
0
1 2
```

https://godbolt.org/z/j6e9Erqrr

Comment: Nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.