# Ignoring integers that are next to characters using sscanf()

Tags: c

Sorry for the simple question, but I'm trying to find an elegant way to avoid my program seeing input like "14asdf" and accepting it just as 14.

```
if (sscanf(sInput, "%d", &iAssignmentMarks[0]) != 0)
```

Is there an easy way to prevent `sscanf` from pulling integers out of mangled strings like that?

Comment: You mean is there a way to have sscanf only pick up the numeric characters in a string like that? You might also want to clarify whether you want "53sd2" to return 53 or 532.

Comment: Sorry I should be more clear, I want "14asdf" to be recognized as invalid input, as would "53sd2". I only want to recognize integers that stand alone (at least space delimited) with no non-digit characters touching them.

Comment: This would be easy in C++. Maybe the 'c++' tag should be removed from this question? @AdamWathan, do you want only answers that work in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly stop `sscanf()` from doing what it is designed and specified to do.  However, you can use a little-known and seldom-used feature of `sscanf()` to make it easy to find out that there was a problem:

```
int i;

if (sscanf(sInput, "%d%n", &iAssignmentMarks[0], &i) != 1)
    ...failed to recognize an integer...
else if (!isspace(sInput[i]) && sInput[i] != '\0')
    ...character after integer was not a space character (including newline) or EOS...
```

The `%n` directive reports on the number of characters consumed up to that point, and does not count as a conversion (so there is only one conversion in that format).  The `%n` is standard in `sscanf()` since C89.

For extracting a single integer, you could also use `strtol()` - carefully (detecting error conditions with it is surprisingly hard, but it is better than `sscanf()` which won't report or detect overflows).  However, this technique can be used multiple times in a single format, which is often more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You want to read integers from strings. It is easier to do this with `strtol` instead of `sscanf`. `strtol` will return, indirectly via `endptr`, the address just after the last character that was succesfully read into the number. If, *and only if*, the string was a number, then `endptr` will point to the end of your number string, i.e. `*endptr == \0`.

```
char *endptr = NULL;
long n = strtol(sInput, &endptr, 10);
bool isNumber = endptr!=NULL && *endptr==0 && errno==0;
```

(Initial whitespace is ignored. See a [strtol man page](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtol.3.asp) for details.

Comment: I added some text to the answer in order to explain the code. I hope you don't mind @Serge-appTranslator. Feel free to edit further or remove it.

Comment: What? text? Why not commenting the code while you're at it! :-) Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 2):

This is easy. No fancy C++ required! Just do:

```
char unusedChar;
if (sscanf(sInput, "%d%c", &iAssignmentMarks[0], &unusedChar) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` isn't that smart.  You'll have to read the input as text and use `strtol` to convert it.  One of the arguments to `strtol` is a `char *` that will point to the first character that isn't converted; if that character isn't whitespace or 0, then the input string wasn't a valid integer:

```
char input[SIZE]; // where SIZE is large enough for the expected values plus
                  // a sign, newline character, and 0 terminator
...
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
{
  char *chk;
  long val = strtol(input, &chk, 10);
  if (*chk == NULL || !isspace(*chk) && *chk != 0)
  {
    // input wasn't an integer string
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is about `sscanf`, not `scanf`, and hence the data is already in a string. See @Serge's answer.

Comment: This isn't correct: you can use `[fs]scanf()` for this OK: you just need to attempt reading something after the number and check the number of elements read.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use c++ specific capabilities, there are more clear ways to test input strings using streams.

Check here:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.2

If you're wondering, yes this did come from another stack overflow post. Which answers this question:
[Other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200090/how-do-you-convert-a-c-string-to-an-int)