# why is the sort() not working?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I got this simple program read in a string like "13 11 9 10". I wanna split string then sort them. however the sort() seems not working, any help?
input: 13 11 9 10
, output: 13 11 9 10 
Thanks!

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> split(string s)
{
    istringstream iss(s);
    vector<int> result;

    do{
        string sub;
        iss>>sub;
        if(sub!="")
            result.push_back((int)atoi(sub.c_str()));
    }while(iss);

    return result;
}
int main(void)
{   
    string s;
    while(cin>>s)
    {
        vector<int> vec;
        vec=split(s);
        sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout<<vec[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/c42d25b1ae979db4044c8cb4b5d3cb51 it works.

Comment: The problem is not with `std::sort()`, but with your `split(string)` method.

Comment: The problem is at `cin>>s`, which already splits your input string. Try something like `getline()` instead.

Comment: @iammilind: Nope, the split method is okay.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Not really.  It has at least two errors: it accesses `sub` without checking if the read has succeeded, and it doesn't verify anything.  (Of course, since it will never be passed a string with any white space in it, it will never find more than one entry.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `cin >> s` stops at the first whitespace.

In other words, if you type `1 4 2 3`, `s` contains `1` only, and not the entire line.

Instead, use the following to read the entire line:

```
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

Comment: In addition, don't use atoi, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200090/how-do-you-convert-a-c-string-to-an-int

Comment: I find it worth mentioning that I don't see `std::stoi` anywhere in the link, or the duplicate of it. That's probably the best method if it's available.

Comment: @chris If it's available; it's part of C++11.  And from the specification, it seems to suffer from the same problems as `atoi`: no real error checking is possible.  In the end, you've got to go with `strtol`, setting `errno` to 0 before hand, and passing a pointer to a place where `strtol` will store the end pointer, then verifying that `errno == 0 && end != start && *end == '\0'`.

Comment: @JamesKanze, No error checking? It has two possible exceptions to throw in the case of an error: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol. If that's why you added real there, it's still possible to catch them and handle them in the same way as you would a bad result from `strtol`.

Comment: @chris It only throws an error if `strtol` reports an error.  That covers the case where `errno != 0` above (I suppose---the standard doesn't say what "reports an error" means with regards to `strtol`.)  You still have the problem of something like `"abcxyz"`, where `strtol` simply returns `0`, without reporting an error.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I thought that would be taken care of by `std::invalid_argument`, and it [looks like it is](http://ideone.com/A1oK2).

Comment: @chris According to the standard, "Throws: `invalid_argument` if `strtol`, `strtoul`, `strtoll` or `strtoull` reports that no conversion could be performed.[...]"  According to the C standard, given `"abcxyz"`, the function should return `0`, and _not_ report an error.  (This surprised me too, but I was recently bitten by it  You need extra concerning how much data was used to generate the return value.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, Well, I see your point then. Is that a bug with (a possibly older version of) GCC? I don't have `stoi` on my 4.7.1 so I can't check there.

Comment: @chris `std::stoi` is a C++11 function, so it's likely that most people don't have it.

Comment: Sorry, Cicada; that got a bit longer than I was expecting. @JamesKanze, Yes, 'twould be nice, but that's the reality. I don't even have it *with* C++11 yet. Thanks for the standard reference to that, though.

Answer (score 0):

your main section of code is incorrect, cin already splits data into parts, use cin.getline with buffer or what Cicida suggests above, my working code looks like this:

```
string s;
char buffer[ 256 ];
do
{
    cin.getline( buffer, 255 );
    s.assign( buffer );
    vector<int> vec;
    vec=split(s);
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<vec[i]<<endl;
    }
}while( !s.empty( ));
```