# C++ sort out negative output

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hi could someone point me out what's wrong with this code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int convstrg(char* str) {
   int output = 0;
   char* p = str;
   for (int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++) {
      char c = *p++;
      if (c < '0' || c > '9')
        continue;
      output *= 10;
      output += c - '0';
   }   
   return output;
}

int main(){
    char x[] = "1xx23";
    printf("%d\n", convstrg(x));
    return 0;
}
```

The code should return an integer when the output is string integer. But it seems i getting weird number such as 0.

this are few test case, some of it works some didn't

```
"123" -> 123
"23xyz" -> 23
"" -> 0
"abc" -> 0
"-1" -> -1
```

Thanks

EDIT

Ok now i sort out all the cases expect for negative string..

Comment: @icabod problems is negative numbers for "-1" i get 1 in return

Comment: You have no logic for handling negative values - you'll need to add that. But since this is C++ why are you even re-inventing the wheel like this (and using C-stye coding) when there are much better alternatives that require no coding?

Comment: @novavent: Yeah, just saw that it wouldn't work for the negative, so deleted my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

- You are never checking to see if the leading character is `-` thus you can not expect to have negative numbers parsed correctly.
- You should **break** `if (c < '0' || c > '9')` instead of **continue**. Otherwise the parsed value from `12xyz123` will be very strange.
- I hope you know there are built-in functions for parsing an integer from a string for instance using `std::atoi` or using a `std::stringstream`. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/200090/812912) for more details.
- You can also use third-party library like `boost::lexical_cast` like so `boost::lexical_cast<int>(x)`

Comment: i would like todo without using build in function

Comment: @novavent that is why I added also errors I found in your code. Still it is good to have all options in the answer as your question never stated you want to do it without using built-in functions.

Comment: "12xyz123" this case actually return a correct answers, look at here http://codepad.org/41KhzOrP

Comment: @novavent I don't think this is the correct value for parsing 12xyz123, but that's your call. I believe you should either return 0 indicating that the parsing failed or only return 123.