# Very poor boost::lexical_cast performance

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

Windows XP SP3. Core 2 Duo 2.0 GHz.
I'm finding the boost::lexical_cast performance to be extremely slow. Wanted to find out ways to speed up the code. Using /O2 optimizations on visual c++ 2008 and comparing with java 1.6 and python 2.6.2 I see the following results.

**Integer casting:**

```
c++: 
std::string s ;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    s = boost::lexical_cast<string>(i);
}

java:
String s = new String();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    s = new Integer(i).toString();
}

python:
for i in xrange(1,10000000):
    s = str(i)
```

The times I'm seeing are

c++: 6700 milliseconds

java: 1178 milliseconds

python: 6702 milliseconds

c++ is as slow as python and 6 times slower than java.

**Double casting:**

```
c++:
std::string s ;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    s = boost::lexical_cast<string>(d);
}

java:
String s = new String();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    double d = i*1.0;
    s = new Double(d).toString();
}

python:
for i in xrange(1,10000000):
    d = i*1.0
    s = str(d)
```

The times I'm seeing are

c++: 56129 milliseconds

java: 2852 milliseconds

python: 30780 milliseconds

So for doubles c++ is actually half the speed of python and 20 times slower than the java solution!!. Any ideas on improving the boost::lexical_cast performance? Does this stem from the poor stringstream implementation or can we expect a general 10x decrease in performance from using the boost libraries.

Comment: -1 for immature editorializing and lack of perspective

Comment: I removed the 'pathetic' comment, I agree that it was unnecessary. Interestingly, some work seems to have been done in fixing lexical_cast http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1375. So this means if you were to use this library in 2006 when people stopped maintaining it, you would see an additional 3-6x degradation in performance. While no doubt the library writers are exceptional C++ programmers, it would be helpful to step back and ask if providing a library of such genericity makes efficiency impossible. Consider the STL in contrast, where the efficiency and generality are preserved.

Comment: @Barry Kelly: As a longtime C++ programmer I would have said "That's pathetic!" too if I'd seen those results! @Burkhard: I wish there was a way to downvote pointless hairsplitting comments like yours.

Comment: @Nathan : Just to thank you for this Link : http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1375 . Very enlightning. You should put it directly as an edit of your question.

Comment: The following article has a detailed set of results comparing boost lexical_cast and a variety of other methods, the results speak for themselves. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx

Comment: it would be cool if u could (after 2y LOL) redo the tests with new boost version 1.47 notes: "Better performance and less memory usage for many combinations of Source and Target types (#5564, #5417, #4397, #5350, #5576).
"

Comment: The current version of boost is not slow : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html Maybe you can redo your tests and update the question?

Comment: i did some tests in 1.50 with BOOST_LEXICAL_CAST_ASSUME_C_LOCALE defined. The comparison between int lexical_cast<char*/string> and atoi is still large, on my system it's about 3 times slower than atoi

Comment: It looks like Boost Spirit the the fastest method so far when considering parsing.

Comment: @j_random_hacker at least we can upvote the guy criticising the one doing pointless hair splitting.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

## Edit 2012-04-11

[rve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79455/rve) quite rightly commented about lexical_cast's performance, providing a link:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

I don't have access right now to boost 1.49, but I do remember making my code faster on an older version. So I guess:

1. the following answer is still valid (if only for learning purposes)
2. there was probably an optimization introduced somewhere between the two versions (I'll search that)
3. which means that boost is still getting better and better

## Original answer

Just to add info on Barry's and Motti's excellent answers:

### Some background

Please remember Boost is written by the best C++ developers on this planet, and reviewed by the same best developers. If `lexical_cast` was so wrong, someone would have hacked the library either with criticism or with code.

I guess you missed the point of `lexical_cast`'s real value...

### Comparing apples and oranges.

In Java, you are casting an integer into a Java String. You'll note I'm not talking about an array of characters, or a user defined string. You'll note, too, I'm not talking about your user-defined integer. I'm talking about strict Java Integer and strict Java String.

In Python, you are more or less doing the same.

As said by other posts, you are, in essence, using the Java and Python equivalents of `sprintf` (or the less standard `itoa`).

In C++, you are using a very powerful cast. Not powerful in the sense of raw speed performance (if you want speed, perhaps `sprintf` would be better suited), but powerful in the sense of extensibility.

#### Comparing apples.

If you want to compare a Java `Integer.toString` method, then you should compare it with either C `sprintf` or C++ `ostream` facilities.

The C++ stream solution would be 6 times faster (on my g++) than `lexical_cast`, and quite less extensible:

```
inline void toString(const int value, std::string & output)
{
   // The largest 32-bit integer is 4294967295, that is 10 chars
   // On the safe side, add 1 for sign, and 1 for trailing zero
   char buffer[12] ;
   sprintf(buffer, "%i", value) ;
   output = buffer ;
}
```

The C `sprintf` solution would be 8 times faster (on my g++) than `lexical_cast` but a lot less safe:

```
inline void toString(const int value, char * output)
{
   sprintf(output, "%i", value) ;
}
```

Both solutions are either as fast or faster than your Java solution (according to your data).

#### Comparing oranges.

If you want to compare a C++ `lexical_cast`, then you should compare it with this Java pseudo code:

```
Source s ;
Target t = Target.fromString(Source(s).toString()) ;
```

Source and Target being of whatever type you want, including built-in types like `boolean` or `int`, which is possible in C++ because of templates.

### Extensibility? Is that a dirty word?

No, but it has a well known cost: When written by the same coder, general solutions to specific problems are usually slower than specific solutions written for their specific problems.

In the current case, in a naive viewpoint, `lexical_cast` will use the stream facilities to convert from a type `A` into a string stream, and then from this string stream into a type `B`.

This means that as long as your object can be output into a stream, and input from a stream, you'll be able to use `lexical_cast` on it, without touching any single line of code.

### So, what are the uses of `lexical_cast`?

The main uses of lexical casting are:

1. Ease of use (hey, a C++ cast that works for everything being a value!)
2. Combining it with template heavy code, where your types are parametrized, and as such you don't want to deal with specifics, and you don't want to know the types.
3. Still potentially relatively efficient, if you have basic template knowledge, as I will demonstrate below

The point 2 is very very important here, because it means we have one and only one interface/function to cast a value of a type into an equal or similar value of another type.

This is the real point you missed, and this is the point that costs in performance terms.

### But it's so slooooooowwww!

If you want raw speed performance, remember you're dealing with C++, and that you have a lot of facilities to handle conversion efficiently, and still, keep the `lexical_cast` ease-of-use feature.

It took me some minutes to look at the lexical_cast source, and come with a viable solution. Add to your C++ code the following code:

```
#ifdef SPECIALIZE_BOOST_LEXICAL_CAST_FOR_STRING_AND_INT

namespace boost
{
   template<>
   std::string lexical_cast<std::string, int>(const int &arg)
   {
      // The largest 32-bit integer is 4294967295, that is 10 chars
      // On the safe side, add 1 for sign, and 1 for trailing zero
      char buffer[12] ;
      sprintf(buffer, "%i", arg) ;
      return buffer ;
   }
}

#endif
```

By enabling this specialization of lexical_cast for strings and ints (by defining the macro `SPECIALIZE_BOOST_LEXICAL_CAST_FOR_STRING_AND_INT`), my code went 5 time faster on my g++ compiler, which means, according to your data, its performance should be similar to Java's.

And it took me 10 minutes of looking at boost code, and write a remotely efficient and correct 32-bit version. And with some work, it could probably go faster and safer (if we had direct write access to the `std::string` internal buffer, we could avoid a temporary external buffer, for example).

Comment: What actually happens inside lexical_cast so it is so slow?

Comment: Why not read the source, or Neil's explanation, and find out for yourself?

Comment: @stepancheg : The "slowness" of the lexical_cast can be attributed to the stream object constructed to handle the transformation from Source into stream, and then stream into Target. This is *the* very general solution, suitable for all cases, but not always performance-oriented. The specialization above enable the user to enhance performance when needed (remember: "Premature Optimization is the root of all Evil").

Comment: @ stepancheg, lexical_cast is implemented through iostream, as a component of the standard library, whose design was not meant only to be a fast. I wouldn't say it's slow, rather, if speed is your concern, you surely have other alternatives in c++, boost.spirit 2.1 to name just one.

Comment: @paercebal: Thanks for the suggestions on the C solutions and the detailed explanation. While no performance guarentees are mandatory, it doesn't give me confidence in the efficiency of this library for casting purposes in a generic fashion (who knows it might be 100x slower for something else). Can you think of examples where lexical_cast would be within the ballpark (~2x) of the specialized case. If I told you that std::vector could be anywhere from 5x to 20x slower than the specific case, I bet you would have very low confidence in using the library.

Comment: @Nathan : The problem is that we must balance safety, extensibility and speed. This means that we are not supposed to use an object outside its performance aim, and expect to have it perform best than another, more adapted object.

Comment: @Nathan: If you need performance for your specific case, then you can achieve almost C-like raw performance (as I did) by specializing the function, and hiding dirty details inside an inline function (as I did). Now, you should not become obsessive for something like a simple lexical cast, unless it was marked as speed bottleneck of your application. In this case, you must understand what's going wrong (copies, allocations, etc.?), and only then you must write a feature best adapted to your needs.

Comment: @Nathan: As for the vector being 20x slower than other processing, and all this kind of object comparison, it can be difficult to make comparisons in the same context (as you tried when comparing a "toString" with a "lexical cast"). Vectors can be quite efficient, but STL offers you a lot of containers, so you should choose the one adapted to your needs and algorithms. A good exercise would be to try a manipulation of vectors of integers in Java and in C++,, and explain the difference...

Comment: I haven't profiled this, so I can't say for sure, but I would expect the cost of lexical_cast to come from two sources: 1) the need for string copying (std::stringstream maintains its own dynamically allocated buffer), and 2) the need for dynamic allocations (which are far slower in C/C++ than in managed languages)

The IOStreams (including stringstream) has a lot of flaws. `lexical_cast` just wraps it, so there's little it can do to improve the situation *in general*.

But how many `lexical_casts` are you performing? Does the performance really *matter*?

Comment: @jaif : "But how many lexical_casts are you performing? Does the performance really matter" : We do agree on this. ^_^ ...

Comment: @paercebal: +1 for the excellent specialisation idea. And sure, people often worry about performance when they don't need to. But I question your statement that increased generality usually leads to decreased runtime perf -- that was true before templates arrived, but in cases where all the relevant info is available at compile time (as here) that is no longer true. (A well-known example: std::sort() with a functor argument is more general than *and at least as fast as* qsort() due to inlining.) I think the problem here is not generality itself, but (avoidable) inefficiencies in IOstreams.

Comment: @j_random_hacker : An counter example would be the existence of the EASTL library, used instead of the STL, to take into account the constraints of game development. Another example would be using a house class instead of a std::vector when you know that your class will at most contain, say, 16 items, your house class allocating the array on the stack (i.e. "T t[16] ;" instead of "T * t ;" If this array happens to be a performance bottleneck, your house class will outperform std::vector because it won't use new/delete... ^_^ ...

Comment: I have to somewhat disagree. Yes, `lexical_cast` *is* slower than necessary. This has got **nothing** to do with its flexibility and extensibility. Rather, it’s due to the unfortunate fact that the string stream needs to be copied to a string rather than passing ownership of its content over to a string object. This is unfortunate, unnecessary and could be done better. It *is* arguably bad design – not necessarily by the Boost guys but rather by those designing the `stringstream` class without the option to relinquish ownership of its internal character buffer, arguably a poor choice indeed.

Comment: thanks a lot, we are using this in a project. but instead of `%f` we use `%.20g`, and a buffer size of 30. A good example why this is required is when you try to cast `-boost::numeric::bounds<double>::highest()`.

On one particular machine the lexical cast is about 100 times slower when used in multithreadding (I do not know why).

Comment: @martinus: I heard there was something likes locales that are mutexed global variables. I never went into the code, but if this is true, it could explain the degradation of performance when using different iostream objects from different threads, and still have each use wait for another to end before beginning. This would be a classical "convoy" pattern.

Comment: According to the boost documentation the current version is not slow at all: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html Maybe it is nice to update the answer with this?

Comment: @rve : Thanks! I was not aware of that. I edited my answer to provide your link, keeping the original answer for its "historical and technical value" (overloading lexical_cast for performance issues).

Comment: Warning! If you use this specialisation, and have a non-specialised instantiation of `lexical_cast<std::string, int>` linked in from some library that you're using, you may or may not be using your specialisation!

Comment: Do not use `char buffer[12];` in real code. It will cause a buffer overflow when run on 64-bit int system. (Even if you don't know of any now, there may be some in future).

Comment: @MattMcNabb : This is why I added the comment "...32-bit integers..." in the code. The purpose of this answer was to show how to specialize lexical casts, not to produce indestructible code for every platform, both present and future. In real code, this function would have a static assert making sure the sizeof(int) is 4 bytes, thus blocking compilation for problematic platforms.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : You're right. There is no easy way to make sure my application uses this specialization, unless I know no other library I link with uses Boost. One way to mitigate this would be to use another function (e.g. my_lexical_cast) to wrap lexical_cast, and specialize this other function.

Comment: @paercebal: Yepper - that's what I do.

Comment: Just found this answer since it was linked from a new closed question. If this is considered the canonical answer to the question why `boost::lexical_cast` is so slow, could the "solution" code actually work and not rely on implementation behavior (int being 32bit)? Otherwise replacing it with `return 0` would at least be obviously wrong instead of subtly broken on a few platforms. I think some template and macro trickery should do the trick and not be that complicated - certainly more than 5 minutes to come up with a version that will actually work in all circumstances though.

Comment: @Voo : My thoughts, exactly... Which is why I mentioned the 32-bit of my int... :-) ... because my point was to explain how overloading and/or specialization could make generic functions uses faster, not to provide the perfect solution for all past, present and future platforms on int-to-string conversion... I guess using a type traits could provide a "stronger" implementations, but I had yet to find a really reliable one that would describe the max size of the output of a sprintf for an int (numeric_limits::digit10 or its siblings seem a bit weak to me). If you have a more general solution...

Answer (score 20):

You could specialize `lexical_cast` for `int` and `double` types. Use `strtod` and `strtol` in your's specializations.

```
namespace boost {
template<>
inline int lexical_cast(const std::string& arg)
{
    char* stop;
    int res = strtol( arg.c_str(), &stop, 10 );
    if ( *stop != 0 ) throw_exception(bad_lexical_cast(typeid(int), typeid(std::string)));
    return res;
}
template<>
inline std::string lexical_cast(const int& arg)
{
    char buffer[65]; // large enough for arg < 2^200
    ltoa( arg, buffer, 10 );
    return std::string( buffer ); // RVO will take place here
}
}//namespace boost

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string str = "22"; // SOME STRING
    int int_str = boost::lexical_cast<int>( str );
    std::string str2 = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( str_int );

    return 0;
}
```

This variant will be faster than using default implementation, because in default implementation there is construction of heavy stream objects. And it is should be little faster than `printf`, because `printf` should parse format string.

Comment: Added int to string specialization.

Comment: Boost lexical_cast is extremely slow and painfully inefficient.

Comment: @Beh Tou Cheh, that's because default `boost::lexical_cast` uses streams, when my solution is not.

Comment: I've had problems with this approach when one shared library has such specialisations (and instantiates them), and another shared library has instantiations of the "original" Boost templates, and my program uses both libraries. It is unpredictable (to an extent) as to which implementation will be used. So I keep these out of the `boost` namespace and give them a different name.

Answer (score 14):

`lexical_cast` is more general than the specific code you're using in Java and Python. It's not surprising that a general approach that works in many scenarios (lexical cast is little more than streaming out then back in to and from a temporary stream) ends up being slower than specific routines.

(BTW, you may get better performance out of Java using the static version, `Integer.toString(int)`. [1])

Finally, string parsing and deparsing is usually not that performance-sensitive, unless one is writing a compiler, in which case `lexical_cast` is probably too general-purpose, and integers etc. will be calculated as each digit is scanned.

[1] Commenter "stepancheg" doubted my hint that the static version may give better performance. Here's the source I used:

```
public class Test
{
    static int instanceCall(int i)
    {
        String s = new Integer(i).toString();
        return s == null ? 0 : 1;
    }

    static int staticCall(int i)
    {
        String s = Integer.toString(i);
        return s == null ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // count used to avoid dead code elimination
        int count = 0;

        // *** instance

        // Warmup calls
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            count += instanceCall(i);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
            count += instanceCall(i);
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("10MM Time taken: %d ms\n", finish - start);


        // *** static

        // Warmup calls
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            count += staticCall(i);

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
            count += staticCall(i);
        finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("10MM Time taken: %d ms\n", finish - start);
        if (count == 42)
            System.out.println("bad result"); // prevent elimination of count
    }
}
```

The runtimes, using JDK 1.6.0-14, server VM:

```
10MM Time taken: 688 ms
10MM Time taken: 547 ms
```

And in client VM:

```
10MM Time taken: 687 ms
10MM Time taken: 610 ms
```

Even though theoretically, escape analysis may permit allocation on the stack, and inlining may introduce all code (including copying) into the local method, permitting elimination of redundant copying, such analysis may take quite a lot of time and result in quite a bit of code space, which has other costs in code cache that don't justify themselves in real code, as opposed to microbenchmarks like seen here.

Comment: You won't get better performance using static Integer.toString(int) because JIT works well.

Comment: stepancheg - not necessarily true. See the little benchmark test I added.

Comment: Barry, run "instance" test after "static" test and you have "instance" toString work faster.

Comment: I'll have to let others do the modifications to the code as I don't want the sample to get much longer, but that's not what I saw even after I reversed the pair, put it inside a loop, and unrolled the loop three times in its inner body. With both client VM I see the static call being a steady 10+% faster, with the margin being less but still present server VM.

Comment: @Barry. Thanks for the suggestion on the static case, it is about 20% faster in my case.

Comment: That's cumulative times over 9 iterations, i.e. 3x loop with 3x alternating pairs, with static running first. Sample timing: Totals: inst: 6174 ms, stat: 5483 ms

Comment: I don't quite get why you check for count being equal to 42. Can you please elaborate on it.

Comment: @batbrat - the comparison stops the compiler from potentially eliminating the code in staticCall, and avoiding calling it, etc. Probably javac and the JVM won't eliminate it, but if I never did anything with the return value, and the code in the methods doesn't do anything with global state, then it is legal for the compiler to eliminate the code, since it would have no observable side-effect. By checking count, I force the compiler to at least evaluate the code at compile time (I know it won't do that though, too complex), or else leave the code in to be executed at runtime (what I want).

Answer (score 9):

What lexical cast is doing in your code can be simplified to this:

```
string Cast( int i ) {
    ostringstream os;
    os << i;
    return os.str();
}
```

There is unfortunately a lot going on every time you call Cast():

- a string stream is created possibly allocating memory
- operator << for integer i is called
- the result is stored in the stream, possibly allocating memory
- a string copy is taken from the stream
- a copy of the string is (possibly) created to be returned.
- memory is deallocated

Thn in your own code:

```
 s = Cast( i );
```

the assignment involves further allocations and deallocations are performed. You may be able to reduce this slightly by using:

```
string s = Cast( i );
```

instead.

However, if performance is really importanrt to you, you should considerv using a different mechanism. You could write your own version of Cast() which (for example) creates a static stringstream. Such a version would not be thread safe, but that might not matter for your specific needs.

To summarise, lexical_cast is a convenient and useful feature, but such convenience comes (as it always must) with trade-offs in other areas.

Comment: +1, a static ostringstream is a good idea.  It may be possible to squeeze even more performance out by deriving a new stream buffer class from stringbuf that uses fixed-size, preallocated memory, and supplying that as the ostringstream's buffer with rdbuf() -- but then you'd be making some work for yourself ;)

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep yet to comment...

`lexical_cast` is not primarily slow because it's generic (template lookups happen at compile-time, so virtual function calls or other lookups/dereferences aren't necessary). `lexical_cast` is, in my opinion, slow, because it builds on C++ iostreams, which are primarily intended for streaming operations and not single conversions, and because `lexical_cast` must check for and convert iostream error signals. Thus:

- a stream object has to be created and destroyed
- in the string output case above, note that C++ compilers have a hard time avoiding buffer copies (an alternative is to format directly to the output buffer, like `sprintf` does, though `sprintf` won't safely handle buffer overruns)
- `lexical_cast` has to check for `stringstream` errors (`ss.fail()`) in order to throw exceptions on conversion failures

`lexical_cast` is nice because (IMO) exceptions allow trapping all errors without extra effort and because it has a uniform prototype. I don't personally see why either of these properties necessitate slow operation (when no conversion errors occur), though I don't know of such C++ functions which are fast (possibly Spirit or boost::xpressive?).

Edit: I just found a message mentioning the use of `BOOST_LEXICAL_CAST_ASSUME_C_LOCALE` to enable an "itoa" optimisation: http://old.nabble.com/lexical_cast-optimization-td20817583.html. There's also a linked [article](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1375#Boost) with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 8):

**lexical_cast** may or may not be as slow in relation to Java and Python as your bencharks indicate because your benchmark measurements may have a subtle problem.  Any workspace allocations/deallocations done by lexical cast or the iostream methods it uses are measured by your benchmarks because C++ doesn't defer these operations.  However, in the case of Java and Python, the associated deallocations may in fact have simply been deferred to a future garbage collection cycle and missed by the benchmark measurements. (Unless a GC cycle by chance occurs while the benchmark is in progress and in that case you'd be measuring too much).  So it's hard to know for sure without examining specifics of the Java and Python implementations how much "cost" should be attributed to the deferred GC burden that may (or may not) be eventually imposed.

This kind of issue obviously may apply to many other C++ vs garbage collected language benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

As Barry said, `lexical_cast` is very general, you should use a more specific alternative, for example check out [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) (`int->string`) and [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) (`string -> int`).

Comment: Your answer does not explain, why lexical_cast slow.

Answer (score 1):

if speed is a concern, or you are just interested in how fast such casts can be with C++, there's an interested [thread](http://www.nabble.com/-xpressive--Performance-Tuning--td24279587i180.html#a24798718) regarding it.

Boost.Spirit 2.1(which is to be released with Boost 1.40) seems to be very fast, even faster than the C equivalents(strtol(), atoi() etc. ).

Answer (score 1):

I use this very fast solution for POD types...

```
namespace DATATYPES {

    typedef std::string   TString;
    typedef char*         TCString;
    typedef double        TDouble;
    typedef long          THuge;
    typedef unsigned long TUHuge;
};

namespace boost {

template<typename TYPE>
inline const DATATYPES::TString lexical_castNumericToString(

                                const TYPE& arg, 
                                const DATATYPES::TCString fmt) {

    enum { MAX_SIZE = ( std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::digits10 + 1 )  // sign
                                                            + 1 }; // null
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE] = { 0 };

    if (sprintf(buffer, fmt, arg) < 0) {
        throw_exception(bad_lexical_cast(typeid(TYPE),
                                         typeid(DATATYPES::TString)));
    }
    return ( DATATYPES::TString(buffer) );
}

template<typename TYPE>
inline const TYPE lexical_castStringToNumeric(const DATATYPES::TString& arg) {

    DATATYPES::TCString end = 0;
    DATATYPES::TDouble result = std::strtod(arg.c_str(), &end);

    if (not end or *end not_eq 0) {
        throw_exception(bad_lexical_cast(typeid(DATATYPES::TString),
                                         typeid(TYPE)));
    }
    return TYPE(result);
}

template<>
inline DATATYPES::THuge lexical_cast(const DATATYPES::TString& arg) {
    return (lexical_castStringToNumeric<DATATYPES::THuge>(arg));
}

template<>
inline DATATYPES::TString lexical_cast(const DATATYPES::THuge& arg) {
    return (lexical_castNumericToString<DATATYPES::THuge>(arg,"%li"));
}

template<>
inline DATATYPES::TUHuge lexical_cast(const DATATYPES::TString& arg) {
    return (lexical_castStringToNumeric<DATATYPES::TUHuge>(arg));
}

template<>
inline DATATYPES::TString lexical_cast(const DATATYPES::TUHuge& arg) {
    return (lexical_castNumericToString<DATATYPES::TUHuge>(arg,"%lu"));
}

template<>
inline DATATYPES::TDouble lexical_cast(const DATATYPES::TString& arg) {
    return (lexical_castStringToNumeric<DATATYPES::TDouble>(arg));
}

template<>
inline DATATYPES::TString lexical_cast(const DATATYPES::TDouble& arg) {
    return (lexical_castNumericToString<DATATYPES::TDouble>(arg,"%f"));
}

} // end namespace boost
```