# Which class should be used by C++?

Tags: c++, class

To describe is a little tricky, I think. But I do my best...

Given:

A prog (Prog_A)

A lib (Lib_A) with
a class Class_A

And a lib (Lib_B) with (also) a class Class_A and has a member Class_A mClass_A

Both classes Class_A have the function

```
void Class_A::DoSome(){
...
}
```

For Class_A in Lib_A then

```
void Class_A::DoSome(){
std::cout << "LIB_A";
}
```

For Class_A in Lib_B then

```
void Class_A::DoSome(){
std::cout << "LIB_B";
}
```

Prog_A includes Lib_A, Lib_A includes Lib_B.
Lib_A and Lib_B is "connected" by Callback's.
If I now call mClass_A.DoSome() in *Lib_B* then it's printing

LIB_A

instead of my expectation 'LIB_B'.

Is this behavior correct, or must I be worried?

Comment: Learn more about `virtual` member functions & [vtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Comment: What namespaces classes Class_A belong to?

Comment: Does linux really have anything to do with the question? Make the names distinct or use namespaces to make things clearer for usage.

Comment: Which class is `Class_A mClass_A`  a member of?

Comment: This has more to do with .ELF executable format than with Linux itself. For this purposes C++ uses so called 'weak symbols'. These can be present "multiple" times in process image. Each library can define symbol of the SAME name, but the first one wins. PS: is it not an answer for your question. A real answer about name mangling and symbol mapping to .ELF format would be very long.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This question has nothing to do with virtual member functions & vtables. It's an ambiguous naming problem.

Comment: How could this even link?

Comment: @avakar: Dynamically. It wouldn't statically.

Comment: @ibre5041, there will be no weak symbols in the scenario described above. Weak symbols are used for inline functions and temploids, but not for every symbol in C++. Maybe you're thinking of ELF symbol interpositioning, which is independent of weak symbols.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely you're right. I read the question too quickly. The word "includes" made me think that the library includes headers of class - while the real meaning was that library contains symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You have defined `Class_A` twice, and the definitions do not match.

This is *not allowed*.

> `[C++11: 3.2/3]`: **Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required.** The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly defined (see 12.1, 12.4 and 12.8). An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.
>
> `[C++11: 3.2/5]`: **There can be more than one definition of a class type** (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function with external linkage (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), non-static function template (14.5.6), static data member of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for which some template parameters are not specified (14.7, 14.5.5) **in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements**. Given such an entity named D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - **each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens**;
> - *[..]*

If you were building the entire program straight up, you'd get a multiple definitions error at link-time; however, since you're linking dynamically, this is not possible and your program is simply broken.

Use namespaces to separate the definitions from each other.

I managed to accidentally cause this problem once when using [a custom `boost::lexical_cast` specialisation I'd found on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250795/very-poor-boostlexical-cast-performance/1251051#comment19144737_1251043) in a shared library, not realising that the original, "default" specialisation had been instantiated in a separate shared library. The behaviour I got from the main application was quite unpredictable.

Comment: Hi, thanks to all! Mainly I was unsure if I made a mistake and I "redirected" unknown, or it is, in this case, a normal behavior. So, all well. Meanwhile I changed one class name, which is "the same" as to use a namepsace. But good to know for the future. Thank you all very much! 

Greeting Earlybite