# Simple, Custom Parsing with c++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, numbers

I have been reading SO for some time now, but I truly cannot find any help for my problem.

I have a c++ assignment to create an IAS Simulator.

Here is some sample code...

```
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   c
3   1
10  begin
11  . load a, subtract b and offset by -1 for jump+
11  load M(0)
12  sub M(1)
13  sub M(3)
14  halt
```

Using c++, I need to be able to read these lines and store them in a "memory register" class that I already have constructed...

For example, the first line would need to store "1  a" in register zero.

**How can I parse out the number at the line beginning and then store the rest as a string?**

I have setup storage using a class that is called using `mem.set(int, string);`.  `int` is the  memory location at the beginning of the line and `string` is the stored instruction.

**Edit: Some Clarifications:**

- I must use standard libraries
- the grammar for the input file is here: http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~seker/courses/2150/iascode.pdf
- The loader will overwrite duplicate line entries.  That means the first line 11 in the sample will be overwritten by the second.

Comment: Reading files and parsing strings is so very annoying in C++ (much more difficult than C# or other modern languages). One little tip:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  I just emailed my professor, and we must use only STANDARD libraries, so this is going to be a pain.

Comment: @brad Looks like you have a hard teacher on your hands :)

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx They are very efficient and somewhat elegant. The String Toolkit Library makes complex string processing in C++ simple and easy.

Comment: Someone went and downvoted most of the answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the leading number and the rest of the line is not too difficult of a task.  Use something like [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) to read one line at a time from your input file, and store the line in a string  `char cur_line[]`.  For each line, try something like this:

- Declare a pointer `char* pString` and an integer `int line_num`
- Use the [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) function to find the first whitespace character, and assign the result to `pString`.
- Move `pString` forward one character at a time until it points to a non-whitespace character.  This is the start of the string containing the "rest of the line".
- Use [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) on `cur_line` to convert the first entry in the string to an integer, and store the results in `line_num`
- Now, you should be able to call your function like `mem.set(line_num, pString)`

Interpreting those strings is going to be much more difficult, however...

**Edit:** As Mike DeSimone mentions, you can combine the `strstr` and `atoi` steps above if you use one of the [`strto*`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/) functions instead of `atoi`.

Comment: This worked so well.  Thanks!  It took me forever to get `strstr` to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest taking a look at the [`<ifstream>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) library.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream> // #include <fstream> for file objects as others suggest
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<int, string> my_program;

int line_num;
string line_text;
while ( cin >> line_num ) { // or any input stream such as a file
    getline( cin, line_text ); // standard function defined in <string>
    my_program[ line_num ] = line_text; // store line for next phase
}
```

This will read lines of the file until either the end is encountered, or a line which begins with something besides a number. Use `cin.eof()` to verify that the entire file was read, if you care.

Of course, since `map` sorts its contents, the lines will be in numerical order for the next phase.

Comment: Detail: getline should be error-checked too. And for extra terseness, take advantage of operator>> returning the stream:`while(getline(std::cin>>line_num, line_text)){...`

Comment: @Eric: Sounds reasonable, but that would strip a final line with just a number. `getline` is guaranteed to clear the string if `(cin)` (which is guaranteed) and to return as much input as possible, even if the final state is `(!cin)`.

Comment: @Éric Malenfant: by the way, is it ok to address you as Eric? Does SO's mail system handle missing diacritics?

Comment: Recommending `using namespace std;`? How unusual. The compromise is, of course, saying `using std::string; using std::map;`, and so on. Having an explicit list of imports is surely better than the "import bloody everything" statement.

Comment: @Jon: that is a very old argument. My usual response is that `using namespace std;` is results in more maintainable code as there are fewer dependencies to specify, less incremental overhead to using standard tools, and less confusion about accidental aliased names. Use in a header file is unfriendly to other programmers, though.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I guess it depends on how you want to handle a line with a number only: Should it be really interpreted as a number plus an empty string or as a syntax error?
(And yes, the accent is necessary, I was only notified of your second comment)

Answer (score 1):

If the first part of the line is always a number, look at the `strtoul` function.  From the `man` page:

### strtoul -- convert a string to an unsigned long integer

#### LIBRARY

> Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

#### SYNOPSIS

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 unsigned long strtoul(const char *restrict str, char **restrict endptr, int base);
```

#### DESCRIPTION

The strtoul() function converts the string in str to an unsigned long
     value.  The conversion is done according to the given base,
     which must be between 2 and 36 inclusive, or be the special value 0.

The string may begin with an arbitrary amount of white space (as determined by `isspace(3)`) followed by a single optional `+` or `-` sign.  If
     `base` is zero or 16, the string may then include a `0x` prefix, and the
     number will be read in base 16; otherwise, a zero base is taken as 10
     (decimal) unless the next character is `0`, in which case it is taken as
     8 (octal).

The remainder of the string is converted to an unsigned long value in the
     obvious manner, stopping at the end of the string or at the first character that does not produce a valid digit in the given base.  (In bases
     above 10, the letter `A` in either upper or lower case represents 10, `B`
     represents 11, and so forth, with `Z` representing 35.)

If `endptr` is not `NULL`, `strtoul()` stores the address of the first invalid
     character in `*endptr`.  If there were no digits at all, however, `strtoul()`
     stores the original value of `str` in `*endptr`.  (Thus, if `*str` is not `\0`
     but `**endptr` is `\0` on return, the entire string was valid.)

#### RETURN VALUES

The strtoul() function returns
     either the result of the conversion or, if there was a leading minus
     sign, the negation of the result of the conversion, unless the original
     (non-negated) value would overflow; in the latter case, `strtoul()` returns
     `ULONG_MAX`.  In all cases, `errno` is
     set to `ERANGE`.  If no conversion could be performed, 0 is returned and
     the global variable errno is set to `EINVAL`.

---

The key here is the `endptr` parameter.  It sets a pointer to where you need to continue parsing.  If `endptr == str`, then you know the line didn't start with a number.

I like the `strto___` family of functions a lot more than the `ato__` functions because you can set the `base` (including the context-sensing "base 0") and because the `endptr` tells me where to continue from.  (And for embedded applications, `strto___` is a lot smaller footprint than `__scanf` functions.)

EDIT: Sorry to miss your comment.  To use `endptr`, write code like:

```
char* restOfLine = NULL;
unsigned long result = strtoul(lineBuffer, 10, &restOfLine);
if(restOfLine == NULL || restOfLine == lineBuffer)
{
     /* Handle error. */
}
else
{
    // Use result, and do further parsing starting at restOfLine.
}
```

Usually, the "handle error" clause returns or breaks or throws an exception or does something else to bail out of further processing, so you wouldn't need an explicit `else` clause.

Comment: This is working very well to parse the line numbers.  Currently, I'm feeding endptr NULL. What's with the double pointer (**).  How do I set up a variable to catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be a good use of the Boost.Spirit library.  It's an EBNF parser generator in C++, like flex and yacc without the extra compilation steps.

Comment: I can only use standard libraries--which is somewhat daunting.

Comment: Yes, that is daunting.  You should consider work elsewhere.  Working for firms with NDIH (not done in house) syndrome is just too painful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easy part:

```
std::string text_to_parse;
unsigned int register_number;

void Parse_Line(std::istream& data_file)
{
  // Read in the register number.
  if(data_file >> register_number)
  {
    // Read the remaining line as a string {variable}
    getline(data_file, text_to_parse);

    //  Now do something with the text...
  }
  return;
}
```

An issue with your data file, is that it is not following an easy grammar or syntax.  For example, you have two text lines that start with 11.  Line 10 is not a "memory register" line, but an instruction line.  Also, line 2 and 3 don't follow the same grammar as 0 and 1.

For more assistance, please post the grammar rules (preferable in BNF syntax or ASCII art).

Comment: My apologies!  I meant to include the IAS grammar.
http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~seker/courses/2150/iascode.pdf

I only need to complete the data transfer instructions (but I think I have those handled...)

If there are any lines that are stated more than once, the LAST LINE is loaded.  The two lines that start with 11 are a comment and an instruction...

The comment will be overwritten by the instruction, since they are loaded line-by-line...  All of these instructions and "memory registers" are merely loaded into my memory class.