# how to convert string value into double format in c++

Tags: c++

How do I convert a string value into double format in C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `stringstream` :

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream ss;
ss << "12.34";
double d = 0.0;
ss >> d;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using the boost libraries, [lexical cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm?sess=40eeb38f681b328a276027a075cd91e8) is a very slick way of going about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do with stringstream.
You can also catch invalid inputs like giving non-digits and asking it to convert to int.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream s;
    string input;
    cout<<"Enter number: "<<endl;
    cin>>input;
    s.str(input);
    int i;
    if(s>>i)
        cout<<i<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Invalid input: Couldn't convert to Int"<<endl;
}
```

If conversion fails, `s>>i` returns zero, hence it prints invalid input.

Comment: you seem to lack some spaces =)