# Char-array to int

Tags: c++, c, arrays, int

I have an array `char input[11] = {'0','2','7', '-','1','1','2', ,'0','0','9','5'};`

How do I convert input[0,1,2] to `int one = 27`, input[3,4,5,6] to `int two = -112` and input[7,8,9,10] to `int three = 95`?

thx, JNK

Comment: How can you have a `-` in a `byte[]`? And what about the blank entry? And why does your 27 only use 3 entries?

Comment: i'm not quite sure if its a byte or char array...:) thee array "includes" the following data heading(0->360 --> 3 digits), pitch(-180->180 --> 4 digits) and roll(-180->180 --> 4 digits)

Comment: Looks like it should be a char array and contain characters ('0','2','7', etc.)

Comment: it would be easier for you if all your entries would either share a common break signal (e.g a blank) or are the same size (e.g. four chars long).

Comment: @eckes Sometimes you're given data in a format you have no control over. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `strncpy()` to extract the character range and `atoi()` to convert it to an integer (or read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c) for more ways to convert a string to an int).

```
int extract(char *input, int from, int length) {
  char temp[length+1] = { 0 };
  strncpy(temp, input+from, length);
  return atoi(temp);
}

int main() {
  char input[11] = {'0','2','7','-','1','1','2','0','0','9','5'};
  cout << "Heading: " << extract(input, 0, 3) << endl;
  cout << "Pitch:   " << extract(input, 3, 4) << endl;
  cout << "Roll:    " << extract(input, 7, 4) << endl;
}
```

Outputs

```
Heading: 27
Pitch:   -112
Roll:    95
```

http://ideone.com/SUutl

Comment: `strncpy()` does not null-terminate the destination if it copied `length` characters, so you need to pre-fill the array with `0` (or set `temp[length] = 0` after the strncpy).

Comment: @caf Are you sure? If so, then why does the above code work? See the ideone link.

Comment: It's working by accident - see the ideone link I pasted as a comment to the other question.  `strncpy()` is designed for working with fixed-length string fields that are only null-terminated if they're short, rather than regular C strings (such fields were used in original UNIX directory entries).

Comment: Man page for `strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);` states that "The `strncpy()` function is similar [to `strcpy`], except that at most `n` bytes of `src` are copied.  **Warning: If there is no null byte among the first `n` bytes of `src`, the string placed in `dest` will not be null-terminated.**"

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your comment, you know that the first entry is 3 digits wide, the second and third are 4 digits wide:

```
// not beautiful but should work:
char buffer[5];
int  one   = 0;
int  two   = 0;
int  three = 0;
// read ONE
memcpy(buffer, input, 3); 
buffer[3] = '\0';
one = atoi(buffer);
// read TWO
input += 3;
memcpy(buffer, input, 4);
buffer[4] = '\0';
two = atoi(buffer);
// read THREE
input += 4;
memcpy(buffer, input, 4);
buffer[4] = '\0';
three = atoi(buffer);
```

Comment: Why use `memcpy()` when `strncpy()` was designed for strings and handles the null-terminating character for you?

Comment: ack. didn't have in mind that `strncpy()` adds the trailing \0. Fixing the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just be aware that strncpy() does not always produce a string. If the source hast the same length as the len param you pass in, no 0 terminator is added

Comment: @nos Yup, but in this case the string is of known length.

Comment: @marcog yes, and strncpy(buffer, input, 3); will leave buffer *not* 0 terminated given the array the op has in his question. Which means calling atoi on buffer is quite dangerous

Comment: @nos Which array are you referring to? The code works just fine: http://ideone.com/dV6wU

Comment: @marcog: Your code is reading uninitialised data from `buffer[3]` and `buffer[4]` (it's only working because that uninitialised data is happening to work fine) - you can see the error if you initialise `buffer` with: `char buffer[5] = { '9', '9', '9', '9', '9' };` [(see on ideone)](http://ideone.com/9vrSp).