# C++ separate int in to char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

I want to make a C++ method that separates an int to a char array.
And gives a part of the int back.

**Example:**

Input:

```
int input = 11012013;
cout << "day = " << SeperateInt(input,0,2); << endl;
cout << "month = " << SeperateInt(input,2,2); << endl;
cout << "year = " << SeperateInt(input,4,4); << endl;
```

output:

```
day = 11
month = 01
year = 2013
```

I thought it was something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498924/char-array-to-int). But that doesn't work for me so I wrote:

```
int separateInt(int input, int from, int length)
{
    //Make an array and loop so the int is in the array
    char aray[input.size()+ 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i ++)
        aray[i] = input[i];

    //Loop to get the right output 
    int output;
    for(int j = 0; j < aray.size(); j++)
    {
        if(j >= from && j <= from+length)
            output += aray[j];
    }

  return output;
}
```

But,

**1**) You can't call the size of the int this way.
   **2**) You can't just like a string say i want element i of the int, because then this method is useless

How can this be solved?

Comment: `input.size()` where `input` is `int`!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store an int in a char array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522994/store-an-int-in-a-char-array)

Comment: are you sure yor input is int an not string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int input = 11012013;
int year = input % 1000;
input /= 10000;
int month = input % 100;
input /= 100;
int day = input;
```

Actually, you can create required function quite easily with integer division and modulo operator:

```
int Separate(int input, char from, char count)
{
    int d = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < from; i++, d*=10);
    int m = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++, m *= 10);

    return ((input / d) % m);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", Separate(26061985, 0, 4));
    printf("%d\n", Separate(26061985, 4, 2));
    printf("%d\n", Separate(26061985, 6, 2));
    getchar();
}
```

Result:

```
1985
6
26
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is formatting the int into a string and then parsing only the part of it that you want. For example, to get the day:

```
int input = 11012013;

ostringstream oss;
oss << input;

string s = oss.str();
s.erase(2);

istringstream iss(s);
int day;
iss >> day;

cout << "day = " << day << endl;
```

Comment: Oh my, using stringstream for simple mathematical operations is like using a bazooka to kill an ant...

Answer (score 1):

First convert your integer value to char string. use `itoa()` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

then just traverse you new char array

```
int input = 11012013;
char sInput[10];
itoa(input, sInput, 10);
cout << "day = " << SeperateInt(sInput,0,2)<< endl;
cout << "month = " << SeperateInt(sInput,2,2)<< endl;
cout << "year = " << SeperateInt(sInput,4,4)<< endl;
```

then change your `SeprateInt` to handle char input

use `atoi()` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/
to convert back to integer format if required.

Comment: what do you want to stop in cInput?

Comment: it is misspelled, it is `sInput` not `cInput`

Comment: You can't calculate the length of the input here, inside the method. Because it's char by char

Comment: `itoa()` returns `null` terminated string. have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/