# Getting a hex value from a "0x4000" (for example) string and storing it in a variable.

Tags: c, type-conversion

Here's my issue:

I have written a function to detect if a string is hex based off of the "0x####" format:

```
int lc3_hashex(char *str)
{
    int val = 0;      
    char *to;
    to = strndup(str+2, 10);
    val = sscanf(to, "%x", &val); 
    if (val)
    {
        return val;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming the parameter is of the form "0x####", it returns the decimal version of the post "0x" numbers. But is there any built in way (or a way I am just overseeing) to get the integer value of the hexidecimal number "0x4000" as opposed to the integer value of "4000"?

Thanks.

Comment: The string returned by `strndup` must be `free`d once you're done using it.

Comment: ... I think @jonsca answeres the question -- but on a side note, make sure you free the memory you allocate (C is not like Java) -- i.e. strdup mallocs memory, you need to free it rather than leak it.

Comment: There is a similar discussion if C++ is a possibility http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c For 'C' Mat's answer is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) from `stdlib.h` and specify the base as 16.

The only downside is that this function returns 0 upon failure, so you'll want to check to make sure the input to it is not 0.

Answer (score 6):

You can reduce that function to:

```
int cnt = sscanf(str, "%x", &val);
if (cnt == 1) {
  // read a valid `0xNNNN` string
}
```

`scanf` with the `%x` format already does the hex conversion, and deals with the `0x` prefix just fine. Also, it's return value is the number of items matched, so you can use that to determine if it did find a hex value in `str` or not.

With this you have both pieces of information you need: whether or not the string was formatted as you expected it, and what value it was (properly converted). It also avoids a string allocation (which you're not freeing), and the bug your code has if `strlen(str)` is less than two.

If you change your function signature to:

```
int check_and_get_hex(const char *str, int *val);
```

(or something like that), update the `sscanf` call accordingly (passing `val` rather than `&val`), and return `(cnt == 1)`, you can get both the "it's a valid hex string" and the value to the caller in a single shot.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to understand why the string is being cut short before doing `sscanf`. If you want the string in hex value to be converted to the decimal integer, you can give it directly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char sHex[7] = "0x2002";
  int nVal = 0;
  sscanf( sHex, "%x", &nVal );
  printf( "%d", nVal );
  return 0;
}
```

This will print 8194, the decimal value for 0x2002. By giving `"%x"` to `sscanf`, you are specifying the input string as hexadecimal. so, the preceding "0x" is fine.