# Decimal string to char

Tags: c++, string, char

Is there a way to convert numeric string to a `char` containing that value? For example, the string "128" should convert to a `char` holding the value `128`.

Comment: What should happen if the numeric value in the string is `< 0` or `> 255`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

Comment: @WTP the numbers are in that range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the C-style [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/), but it converts to an `int`. You 'll have to cast to `char` yourself.

For a C++ style solution (which is also safer) you can do

```
string input("128");
stringstream ss(str);
int num;
if((ss >> num).fail()) { 
    // invalid format or other error
}

char result = (char)num;
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes... atoi from C.

```
char mychar = (char)atoi("128");
```

A more C++ oriented approach would be...

```
template<class T>
    T fromString(const std::string& s)
{
     std::istringstream stream (s);
     T t;
     stream >> t;
     return t;
}

char mychar = (char)fromString<int>(mycppstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If `char` is signed and 8 bits, you cannot convert "128" to a `char` in base 10. The maximum positive value of a signed 8-bit value is 127.

This is a really pedantic answer, but you should probably know this at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `atoi`.  That will get you the integer 128.  You can just cast that to a `char` and you're done.

```
char c = (char) atoi("128");
```