# C++: How to convert wstring with md5 hash to byte* array?

Tags: c++, hash, wstring

```
std::wstring hashStr(L"4727b105cf792b2d8ad20424ed83658c");

//....

byte digest[16];
```

How can I get my md5 hash in digest?
My answer is:

```
wchar_t * EndPtr;

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
std::wstring bt = hashStr.substr(i*2, 2);
digest[i] = static_cast<BYTE>(wcstoul(bt.c_str(), &EndPtr, 16));
}
```

Comment: It's a `byte` array, not `byte*` array, and it will be too small for that string.

Comment: @jrok : `digest` is sufficient size; 32 hex characters is 16 bytes.

Comment: I need digest[0]==0x8c, digest[1]==0x65, ...

Comment: The answer here is a good one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c

Comment: @ildjarn What am I missing here? `hashStr.length()` is 32, right?

Comment: @jrok : Yes, and each two characters represents one byte in hex; 32 / 2 == 16.

Comment: Oh, I get it now (*shakes head*), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read two characters from `hashStr`, convert them from hex to a binary value, and put that value into the next spot in `digest` -- something on this order:

```
for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
    std::wstring byte = hashStr.substr(i*2, 2);
    digest[i] = hextobin(byte);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C-way (I didn't test it, but it should work (though I could've screwed up somewhere) and you will get the method anyway).

```
memset(digest, 0, sizeof(digest));

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    wchar_t numwc = hashStr[i];
    BYTE    numbt;

    if (numwc >= L'0' && numwc <= L'9')             //I assume that the string is right (i.e.: no SGJSGH chars and stuff) and is in uppercase (you can change that though)
    {
        numbt = (BYTE)(numwc - L'0');
    }
    else
    {
        numbt = 0xA + (BYTE)(numwc - L'A');
    }

    digest[i/2] += numbt*(2<<(4*((i+1)%2)));
}
```