# Problems converting a string to int in C++

Tags: c++, string

I do not understand why the following code is returning `*end=='\0\'`?

```
bool isValue(const string &token,int &output_value) //czy string jest wartoscia
{
  char *end = 0;
  errno=0;
  output_value = strtol(token.c_str(),&end,10); //converts string to int
  if (errno!=0) return false;
  return *end=='\0';
}
```

EDIT: And stupid question but I don't know why there is

```
bool isValue(const string &token,int &output_value)
```

instead of

```
bool isValue(string &token,int &output_value)
```

and

```
bool isValue(string token,int output_value)
```

Comment: @op Out of curiosity - in the original version of the question, was `errno` declared as a local variable?

Comment: Unfortunately, `strtol` is totally broken. Don’t use it! In particular, it’s not required that `errno` is set if the conversion was unsuccessful because a non-numerical value was passed to it (e.g. `"xyz"`). Luckily, some implementations still set `errno` under these circumstances but it’s not required, the function could just fail silently.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Not only is it not required, it's forbidden (at least in Posix).  However, in such cases, `strtol` is required to set `end` to the address passed into it, even if internally, it has skipped some leading space, etc.  So it's possible to detect this condition as well.

Comment: @James True. But libstdc++ (glibc?) luckily ignores this and does the sensible thing.

Comment: Not answering your specific question, but [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194465/237483) gives good suggestion how you can do it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Does it?  That may be where I mislearned it, then.  I thought like you until a couple of weeks ago, when a colleague pointed it out as an error in my code, and I looked it up in the standard.  What the standard requires isn't sensible (I think we agree there), **but**... once the standard has spoken, for an implementation to do anything else is simply wrong (and standards do often require things that aren't sensible, witness `gets`).

Comment: @James [This example code](http://ideone.com/FrZNX) prints errno = 22 on my computer (OS X 10.7, g++ 4.7, no idea which glibc version).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Interesting.  On Linux (but I'm not sure what version of libc I have either), I get `errno == 0` for all of `"1"` (normal), `"1a"`, `"x"`, `""` and `"   "`.  Also with VC++ (2010).  I don't like it, but it's what the C (and Posix) standards require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>The `errno` part is probably legacy code. It could have been used at some point, but the code that used it could have been removed, but `errno` forgotten. You're right, it does nothing and will probably be optimized out.</del> <--- thought `errno` was a local variable (stealth edit?)

`end` is

> [a pointer to the first character following the integer representation in str is stored in the object pointed by endptr.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)

so basically the condition checks whether there were any other characters in the string after the number.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I could have swore `errno` was declared as a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

Would it be wrong to suggest the use of stringstream?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isValue(const string &input, int &output)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << input;
    return(ss >> output)
}
```

Comment: No. But it’s wrong to suggest `if (x) return true; else return false;` ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good point: There was a mismatch between what I was suggesting and what I was doing.

Comment: [This top rated and accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154614/237483) is suggesting `strtol` instead of `stringstream`. With `stringstream` you have problems with strings like `1234abc`.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer it can be needed, but can not... So, usage of strtol instead of stringstream should have real reasons.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer That was very informative. I'm glad I phrased my answer the way that I did.

Comment: @Christian You can adapt for that but checking for `eof` on the string stream (see `boost::lexical_cast`). `strtol` is just so brittle (se discussion in other comments) that I wouldn’t suggest ever using it.

Answer (score 2):

`strtol` may set global variable `errno` to some code. http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/.

**If the correct value is out of the range of representable values, LONG_MAX or LONG_MIN is returned, and the global variable errno is set to ERANGE.**

Your function returns true if end points on '\0' (end of string) and false otherwise.

**Finally, a pointer to the first character following the integer representation in str is stored in the object pointed by endptr**

Comment: The second is only true if `strtol` manages to convert something.  If the string doesn't contain any digits, `strtol` sets `end` to it's argument and returns 0 (without changing `errno`).

Answer (score 1):

`errno` is an old C hack.  It's a global variable (today thread local).
`strtol` sets it to a non-zero value if there is a (detected) error (and
unchanged if there is no error, or if its original value wasn't
0—it's designed so that you can enchain a number of calls, and
only check at the end).

Note that the code in question is wrong.  (I know because I recently
made the same error.  The semantics of `strtol` in case of error are
strange, to put it mildly.)  You need something like:

```
bool
intValue( std::string const& token, int& toReturn )
{
    char* end = NULL;
    char const* s = token.c_str();
    errno = 0;
    long results = strtol( s, &end, 10 );
    bool error = errno != 0
        || end != s
        || *end == '\0'
        || results <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
        || results >= std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    if ( !error ) {
        toReturn = results;
    }
    return error;
}
```

Note that 1) you have to ensure that `end != s`; and 2) you have to
range check if the results are to be written to an `int`.  WRT the
first, the specification of `strtol` says that if it doesn't find any
characters to convert (i.e. the string doesn't contain any digits), it
returns 0, sets `end` to the beginning of the string, and doesn't modify
`errno`.

Comment: Why do you  combine these checks by `&&`? `errno != 0` should definitely suffice. On the other hand, `errno == 0` may still mean an error if the input was invalid and not out of range.

Comment: @Component10 Yes, they should be `||`.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Still a tiny error: `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` is a valid value. The comparisons should be strict.