# Skip non-integers from text file C++

Tags: c++

I have a program which reads integers from a text file and skips non-integers and strange symbols. Then text file looks like:

```
# Matrix A   // this line should be skipped because it contains # symbol
1 1 2
1 1$ 2.1      // this line should be skipped because it contains 2.1 and $
3 4 5
```

I have to print out the matrix without strange symbols and non-integers line. That is the output should be:

```
1 1 2
3 4 5
```

My code

```
ifstream matrixAFile("a.txt", ios::in); // open file a.txt
if (!matrixAFile)
{
      cerr << "Error: File could not be opened !!!" << endl;
      exit(1);
}

int i, j, k;
while (matrixAFile >> i >> j >> k)
{
      cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << k;
      cout << endl;
}
```

But it fails when it gets the first # symbol. Anyone helps please ?

Comment: It wouldn't be much of an assignment if all you had to do was `>>` a few numbers...

Comment: You have to read the whole line into a string, make a stringstream from it and try to parse with `>>` the same way as you do it now. If the parsing fails, the string didn't contain what you looked for.

Comment: @Vlad I used istringstream but it did'nt work. the istringstream still convert "5$" to "5" while it is supposed to skip it.

Comment: @Harry: but you can check if the is something left in the stream, correct? So for `3 4 5` stream is finished, but for `3 4 5$` there is still `$` in the stream. The case `3$ 4 5` is even easier, since it won't be able to get `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this code.

```
int i, j, k;
while (matrixAFile >> i >> j >> k)
```

The **assignment** is *"Find out if the line contains integers"*

But your **code** is saying *"I already know that the line contains integers"*

Answer (score 1):

If you are set to three integers per row, I suggest this pattern:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::ifstream infile("matrix.txt");

for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); )
{
    int a, b, c;

    if (!(std::istringstream(line) >> a >> b >> c))
    {
        std::cerr << "Skipping unparsable line '" << line << "'\n";
        continue;
    }

    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << std::endl;
}
```

If the number of numbers per line is variable, you could use a skip condition like this:

```
line.find_first_not_of(" 0123456789") != std::string::npos
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an assignment, I'm not giving full answer.

```
Read the data line by line to a string(call it str),
Split str into substrings,
In each substring, check if it's convertible to integer value.
```

Another trick is to read a line, then check that every char is between 0-9. It works if you don't need to consider negative numbers.

Comment: try/catch is a kind of overkill, given that the standard read operations don't throw

Comment: well, but the simple conversion could be just reading with `istream::operator >>`. since failures are expected, I wouldn't treat them as exceptional, so IMHO just a boolean flag would be enough

Comment: The problem is; when you are reading you also assume to read integers. Read all the line together, then try to get what you want from it.

Comment: I already tried your way. I used istringstream to convert substrings into integers but when I converted "4$", it is still converted into "4", while it is supposed to skip it.

Comment: @user1642488 I added another trick, it can work. Also with some more trick you can handle negative numbers, too.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı btw, how could you check if a substring is convertible to integer value ? I used istringstream but it did'nt work

Comment: @Harry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this fails at the `#` character: The `#` isn't an integer and, thus, reading it as an integer fails. What you could do is try to read three integers. If this fails and you haven't reached EOF (i.e., `matrixAFile.eof()` yields `false`, you can `clear()` the error flags, and `ignore()` everything up to a newline. The error recovery would look something like this:

```
matrixAFile.clear();
matrixAFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Note, that you need to bail out if you failed because `eof()` is `true`.

Comment: For increased robustness, you should also check if the stream has gone `bad()` and exit the loop.

Comment: Well, using something like `matrixAFile >> val1 >> val2 >> val2` with `int`s `val1`, `val2`, and `val3` attempts to read three integers. This expression fails (i.e., sets `std::ios_base::failbit` on `matrixAFile`) if it can't read three `int`s.

Comment: @DietmarKühl well if you could provide a short code, that would be great. I'm not an expert of C++ and I never see failbit before. Tks

Comment: @Harry: I already privided the crucial ingredients! Well, I didn't mention that a stream converts to `false` if `std::ios_base::failbit` is set but this is easily revealed by using Google. Any further help and I should get the score for having done your homework! The main reason for mentioning this approach is that I think it is overkill to read lines and then parse them using string streams.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd just read a line at a time as a string. I'd copy the string to the output as long as it contains only digits, white-space and (possibly) `-`.