# Basics of strtol?

Tags: c++, string, int, strtol

I am really confused. I have to be missing something rather simple but nothing I am reading about strtol() is making sense. Can someone spell it out for me in a really basic way, as well as give an example for how I might get something like the following to work?

```
string input = getUserInput;
int numberinput = strtol(input,?,?);
```

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=strtol ?

Comment: Or http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/ ?

Comment: Any particular reason for using `strtol` instead of a `stringstream` to read a number?

Comment: Have you tried `int number = strtol(input.**c_str()**, ...);`?

Comment: @nneonneo no need for a stringstream when we have `std::stol`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Awesome, more C++11 shininess I didn't know about. Thanks!

Comment: Trust the one of the masters and forget about rest, read -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176593/4990642

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first argument is the string. It has to be passed in as a C string, so if you have a `std::string` use `.c_str()` first.

The second argument is optional, and specifies a `char *` to store a pointer to the character after the end of the number. This is useful when converting a string containing several integers, but if you don't need it, just set this argument to NULL.

The third argument is the radix (base) to convert. [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) can do anything from binary (base 2) to base 36. If you want `strtol` to pick the base automatically based on prefix, pass in 0.

So, the simplest usage would be

```
long l = strtol(input.c_str(), NULL, 0);
```

If you know you are getting decimal numbers:

```
long l = strtol(input.c_str(), NULL, 10);
```

`strtol` returns 0 if there are no convertible characters at the start of the string. If you want to check if `strtol` succeeded, use the middle argument:

```
const char *s = input.c_str();
char *t;
long l = strtol(s, &t, 10);
if(s == t) {
    /* strtol failed */
}
```

---

If you're using C++11, use [`stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead:

```
long l = stol(input);
```

Alternately, you can just use a `stringstream`, which has the advantage of being able to read many items with ease just like `cin`:

```
stringstream ss(input);
long l;
ss >> l;
```

Comment: Ok so this got my code to work. Just to check passing a string with no number in it would yield what exactly? Also what is the difference between a string and a C string?

Comment: If you don't have a number in the string, `strtol` returns 0. Since that's a legal return value, you have to use the middle parameter to disambiguate.

Comment: @JamesThompson: A `string` (`std::string`) is a C++ object that represents a string. It is the preferred way to handle strings in C++. A C string is a sequence of characters which ends in a null terminator (`\0`) and is represented by a pointer to the first character in the sequence (a `char *`). C functions (like `strtol`) don't take `string` objects, so you have to pass a C string instead.

Comment: oh no that's a problem then. I need to be able to catch when a number is not entered, however for my project 0 is a valid number so I can't just do a if(int = 0)

Comment: Ok so it works, and I thank you. But I don't actually get it. Probably because Im not use to pointers. What is actually being compared in the statement (s==t)

Comment: `strtol` saves a pointer to the first non-numeric character in `t`. If `s==t`, then it means the first character in the string is non-numeric, i.e. the string doesn't start with a number.

Comment: Ok that make sense. One last question. I actually have to do the same thing with doubles I know there is a strtod by using the same code isn't working does strtod use diff params? or what am i missing

Comment: Google for the function. Does it have different parameters?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you're given a string `char const * str`. Now convert it like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>

char * e;
errno = 0;

long n = std::strtol(str, &e, 0);
```

The last argument `0` determines the number base you want to apply; `0` means "auto-detect". Other sensible values are `8`, `10` or `16`.

Next you need to inspect the end pointer `e`. This points to the character after the consumed input. Thus if all input was consumed, it points to the null-terminator.

```
if (*e != '\0') { /* error, die */ }
```

It's also possible to allow for partial input consumption using `e`, but that's the sort of stuff that you'll understand when you actually need it.

Lastly, you should check for errors, which can essentially only be overflow errors if the input doesn't fit into the destination type:

```
if (errno != 0) { /* error, die */ }
```

---

In C++, it might be preferable to use `std::stol`, though you don't get to pick the number base in this case:

```
#include <string>

try { long n = std::stol(str); }
catch (std::invalid_argument const & e) { /* error */ }
catch (std::out_of_range const & e)     { /* error */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/):

```
long int strtol ( const char * str, char ** endptr, int base );
```

Convert string to long integer

Parses the C string str interpreting its content as an integral number of the specified base, which is returned as a long int value. If endptr is not a null pointer, the function also sets the value of endptr to point to the first character after the number.

So try something like

```
long l = strtol(pointerToStartOfString, NULL, 0)
```

Comment: Im new to C++ so im not use to pointers although i aware of the concept. How to i find pointerToStartOfString for my string and what should it look like

Comment: How it works in C is like this: `char` is a variable containing a character. `char*` is a variable containing a pointer. The pointer, when dereferenced, points to a character (usually the start of many characters in memory, called a 'string'). So if you have `char* MyPointer`, then you can do `strtol(MyPointer, NULL, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I always use simply `strol(str,0,0)` - it returns long value. 0 for radix (last parameter) means to auto-detect it from input string, so both `0x10` as hex and `10` as decimal could be used in input string.

Comment: Trying to use strol(input,0,0) gave me the error of 

    "cannot convert `std::string' to `const char*' for argument `1' to `long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'"

Comment: Yes, C++ has `std::string` which is not `char*`. Even though they're used for the same thing (holding strings) functions that work on one do not work on the other.

Comment: for std::string use `strtol(str.c_str(),0,0)`

Comment: True about `0`  leads to auto-detect the base.  With "0109" the result is `8` as 8 is the auto-detected base.