# Converting a string to a number in C++

Tags: c++, stl, string-conversion

I'm seeing a lot of options for converting a string to a number in C++.

Some of which are actually recommending the use of standard C functions such as `atoi` and `atof`.

I have not seen anyone suggesting the following option, which relies solely on C++ STL:

```
int Str2Num(const string& str) // can be called with a 'char*' argument as well
{
    int num;
    istringstream(str)>>num;
    return num;
}
```

Or more generally:

```
template <typename type>
type Str2Num(const string& str) // can be called with a 'char*' argument as well
{
    type num;
    istringstream(str)>>num;
    return num;
}
```

What are the disadvantages in the above implementation?

Is there a simpler / cleaner way to achieve this conversion?

Comment: If this is not a duplicate I would be deeply surprised.

Comment: Have a look at `boost::lexical_cast`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html

Comment: @user2672165, here is the first sentence in my question: "I'm seeing a lot of options for converting a string to a number in C++". And here is the third sentence in my question: "I have not seen anyone suggesting the following option, which relies solely on C++ STL". So obviously, I have posted this question after not being able to find an answer which fits the "pure C++ STL" requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

Comment: @Ali, hi. Please read my comment to user2672165 above.

Comment: @barakmanos If you look at that question I linked, you will see that [the most upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154614/341970) discusses (basically) your code snippets first and tells you why they are flawed and what to use instead.

Comment: @Ali, thanks. The 'What not to do' part is good, because it refers directly to my code snippet and answers my question about the disadvantages in this implementation. The 'The best solution' part actually "falls back" to the use of standard C functions, which in my question, I am (implicitly) hoping to avoid.

Comment: @barakmanos If efficiency is not a major concern, then there is no problem with `std::stoi()` and friends. Nevertheless, I think it is good to know your alternatives, even if you decide to use `std::stoi()` in the end.

Comment: @Ali: thanks very much. I agree about knowing the alternatives. Efficiency is not the issue in this case, as I was merely looking for the simplest and cleanest way to achieve this conversion. "`std::stoi()` and friends" where suggested here in one of the answers below, and they're exactly what I was aiming for. I didn't see this option in any of the related posts that I have visited.

Comment: @barakmanos Well, [it is the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11354496/341970) of the above linked question. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: @barak: The best reason why you should avoid atoi() et al wasn't even stated yet. You cannot check errors with them; they return 0 if they cannot parse the input, so you cannot distinguish between, say "0" and "xxx". std::stoi() and the other new functions fix this defect and throw an exception if the input is invalid.

Comment: @Christian Hackl: nowhere within the question did I express my desire to use `atoi`. If anything, I pretty much stated the opposite (though I didn't do so explicitly).

Comment: @barak: I know. I thought it was interesting for others reading the question and answers.

Comment: @Christian Hackl: OK, I understand now. It was my assumption to begin with, and the main reason for asking this question (otherwise I would have just used `atoi` and `atof`). Thank you for the info :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since C++11, we have had [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
std::stoi(str)
```

There is also `std::stol` and `std::stoll`.

Comment: Great!!! That's what I was looking for when I said "Is there a simpler / cleaner way to achieve this conversion?"... `stod` for `double`?

Comment: @barakmanos Yeah, there are [floating point alternatives](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) too.

Answer (score 4):

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) there's a number of numeric conversion functions defined in the `std::string` class itself:

> [**Numeric conversions**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
>   stoi  (C++11)
>   stol  (C++11)
>   stoll (C++11)
>
> converts a string to a signed integer
>
> stoul  (C++11)
>   stoull (C++11)
>
> converts a string to an unsigned integer
>
> stof  (C++11)
>   stod  (C++11)
>   stold (C++11)
>
> converts a string to a floating point value

As for pre c++11 standards, I can't see any disadvantages from your template function sample.

Answer (score 1):

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string str = "123";
    int num;

    // using stoi() to store the value of str1 to x
    num = std::stoi(str);

    std::cout << num;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <sstream>
template <typename T>
inline bool StringToNumber(const std::string& sString, T &tX)
{
    std::istringstream iStream(sString);
    return !(iStream >> tX).fail();not
}
```

Then call

```cpp
double num{};
StringToNumber(std::string{"580.8"}, num);

float fnum{};
StringToNumber(std::string{"5e+1.0"}, fnum);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How this answers the question asked by OP?

Comment: what does `not` in `    return !(iStream >> tX).fail();not`?