# Taking integers out of a string C++

Tags: c++, string, integer

I wanted to know how I can grab numbers out of a string in C++.  I'm getting the string from an input and will be getting multiple lines, but I already have the line reading working.
Note: the lines always have an even number of ints

Here's what I'd like the code to look something like:

```
std::getline(std::cin, line);// line looks something like "10 3 40 45 8 12"
int a, b;
while(!line.empty() /*line still has ints to extract*/) {
    a = someMethod(line);//gets first int.  So, 10 first loop, 40 second, 8 third
    b = someMethod(line);//gets second int. So, 3 first loop, 45 second, 12 third
    myMethod(a,b);//a method from elsewhere in my code.  It's here so you know that I need both a and b
}
```

Anything similar would help. Thank you very much!

Comment: How about `std::stringstream`?

Comment: How could I use stringstream for this? I'm only a little familiar with it.

Comment: @user2670028: You'd construct it from `line` and then use it in just the same way as you'd extract integers from `std::cin`. The library is nicely orthogonal this way. However, there are things to watch out for - see [How to parse a string to an int in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c).

Comment: @Simon I think I've come up with a way that will work using this idea, thanks!

Comment: Did you do any research before asking here. This has so many answers, just search: parse space delimited numbers c++ and google has many many solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete example.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    std::string line = "2 4 56 6";
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    int i;
    while (stream >> i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The following works fine also, so reading multiple lines should not be a problem.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    std::string line = "2 4 56 6";
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    int i;
    while (stream >> i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    line =  "32 62 44 6 22 58 34 60 71 86";
    stream.clear();
    stream.str(line);
    int a,b;
    while(stream >> a && stream >> b){ 
        std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(!stream.eof())` is broken - `eof` isn't set until after a read operation fails - it doesn't promise that the next read will not fail (how could it - it doesn't know what you'll try to read yet).  You should use `while (stream >> i)` directly.

Comment: @TonyD, Fair point, fixed.

Comment: @merlin2011 thanks, this is a lot like what I've created based on another comment.  The only thing missing (which I guess wasn't entirely specified inthe question, sorry) is that I need the stringstream to work for the next line as well.  Do I have to create a new stringstream or do you know how to grab the next version of "line"?

Comment: @user2670028, You should be able to reuse it by doing `stream.clear()` followed by `stream.str(line)`.

Comment: @merlin2011 I'm core dumping at the end.  My Code: 
`while(stream >> a && stream >> b){
    cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
    myMethod(a,b);
}`

output with line "32 62 44 6 22 58 34 60 71 86":
32 62
44 66
22 58
34 60
Segmentation fault

BTW thanks for all your help.  I can probably figure this out on my own now but I still got this error.

Comment: @user2670028, Testing. Also, is this on a subsequent line?

Comment: @user2670028, Could not reproduce. I assume the accept means you figured out that the segfault was in `myMethod(a,b);`?

Comment: @Merlin2011 You mean is there code around it? Yeah.  I'm thinking it's probably something about my code that isn't present here, but I don't know why it would be having a seg fault during the loop if that was the case.  Thanks for your help again

Comment: @user2670028, I assume it is in your other code. I just updated with an example of reading multiple lines, reusing the `stringstream`.

Comment: @merlin2011 I know myMethod works.  I don't know why this isn't working.  I use this strategy a few times in my code and it worked for at least one of them, so I accepted your answer.  No idea why it isn't working at this spot.  I assume it has something to do with my code and that you can't help me without seeing my actual code.  Thanks for your help a lot.  I'll try to figure this out on my own if I can.  Thank you!!

Comment: @user2670028 so, do you have `std::string line; std::stringstream stream; while (std::cin >> line) { stream.str(line); while (stream >> aa >> b) { cout...; myMethod(a,b); } stream.clear(); }`?  It shouldn't segfault - though we can't see your `myMethod` to see if it has bugs.

Comment: @Merlin2011 Thank you so much for your help, my code is working fine and has been for a while.  I thought myMethod was working as intended because I used a lot of tests on it but it did have a very rare error that happened to exist for the particular input that gave the seg fault.  I thought the error was somewhere in my code and it was.  Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: @user2670028, Glad it worked it for you. :)

Comment: @TonyD Yes, the error was a very rare case in myMethod.  I stated that I thought myMethod worked fine, but I also said the error was probably somewhere in my code.  Thanks a lot for trying to help though!  My code is working fine and has been for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
string line;
getline(std::cin, line);// line looks something like "10 3 40 45 8 12"
int a,  b;

vector<string> tokens;
istringstream iss(line);

copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), 
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter<vector<string> >(tokens));

stringstream s;
for (int i=0;i<tokens.size()/2;i++)
{   
  s<< tokens[i];
  s>>a;
  s.clear();
  s<<tokens[i+2];
  s>>b;
  s.clear();
  myMethod(a,b);
}
```

Comment: `strstream` has been deprecated since C++98, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream

Comment: @TonyD, thanks for pointing out. used `stringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

Get tokens from string line and use them as you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> >
    tokenizer;


void myMethod(int a, int b)
{
    cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
}

void getNumber(string line)
{            
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(" ");
    tokenizer tokens(line, sep);    
    string evenStr, oddStr;

    for(tokenizer::iterator iterToken=tokens.begin();
          iterToken != tokens.end(); ++iterToken)
    {
        evenStr = *iterToken;                       
        ++iterToken;
        if(iterToken != tokens.end())
        {
            oddStr = *iterToken;                                   
        myMethod(atoi(evenStr.c_str()), atoi(oddStr.c_str()));
        }        
    }    
}

int main()
{
   string line("10 3 40 45 8 12");
   getNumber(line);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. I prefer to use boost.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string line = "10 3 40 45 8 12 9"; //std::getline(std::cin, line);// line looks something like "10 3 40 45 8 12"

    std::vector<std::string> intNumbers;
    std::string s;
    boost::split(intNumbers, line, boost::is_any_of(" "), boost::token_compress_on);

    unsigned int i=0;
    while(i < intNumbers.size())
    {
        try{
            int a = boost::lexical_cast<int>(intNumbers[i++]);

            if(i >= intNumbers.size())
            {
                std::cout << "invlaid values" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            int b = boost::lexical_cast<int>(intNumbers[i++]);

            std::cout << "value a: " << a << std::endl;
            std::cout << "value b: " << b << std::endl;

            std::cout << "my method (multiply) a*b: " << (a*b) << std::endl;
        }
        catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast &e)
        {
            std::cout << "invlaid values" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```