# casting main arguments to int

Tags: c++

Simple question I'm having an annoying time with:

My main is set up as such:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   int i = (int) argv[1];
   cout << "Inputted value: " << i << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

If I compile and execute with `g++ main.cc -o main` and `main 5` I get a garbage result back on `cout`. How do I fix this casting issue?

Comment: Command line arguments are received as strings (even if they're strings of digits). To convert the string to a number, you'd use something like `std::stoi`.

Comment: This is why C-style casts are dangerous.

Comment: @remyabel: A cast from `char*` to `int` is perfectly legal, though the result is at best implementation-defined. And the "loses precision" warning probably depends on relative sizes of `char*` and `int`; on many systems, they're both 32 bits. (Though "precision" doesn't really apply to pointer values.)

Comment: Please update your question to indicate what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get the `int` value `42` if the command line argument is the string `"42"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to cast a string to int, which will not work. You need to use one of the string to integer conversion functions.

```
int atoi (const char * str);
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c.aspx)

Comment: No, he's trying to cast a *pointer* to `int`.

Comment: zZShort_CircuitZz's intent was to cast a string to integer, which is not what actually happens.

Comment: `atoi` is a terrible choice.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154614/103167

Comment: I am fully aware that there are safer functions than atoi. I was merely pointing @zZShort_CircuitZz to the existence of conversion functions. If atoi is unsafe depends on the situation it is used in.