# C++ - Alternative to Integer.parseInt() and String.valueOf()

Tags: java, c++

In C++. What are the alternatives to **Integer.parseInt()** and **String.valueOf()** of Java in C++.

Comment: `std::stoi` and `std::to_string`.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `Integer.parseInt` you can use [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), [std::istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/), [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/?kw=sscanf), [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi) etc.

For `String.valueOf()` alternatives, you can [std::ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/), [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/?kw=sprintf), [std::tostring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) etc.

Recommendations:
[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) `stoi` and `tostring`
[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) `istringstream` and `ostringstream`
[c](/questions/tagged/c) `atoi` and `sprintf`

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use [sstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/).

Answer (score 0):

You may use atoi c++ function.

```
int atoi (const char * str);
```

> Convert string to integer Parses the C-string str interpreting its
>   content as an integral number, which is returned as a value of type
>   int.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/