# How to parse a part of a string, which have characters other than digits, to integer

Tags: c++, delimiter, ifstream

I am currently trying to read information from an .txt file and essentially store this appropriately. Data from the input file would look something like this

```
10 10 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 20 30 20 15 15 10 10 10
765DEF 01:01:05:59 enter 17
ABC123 01:01:06:01 enter 17
765DEF 01:01:07:00 exit 95
ABC123 01:01:08:03 exit 95
```

My question is that, assuming I have read "01:01:05:59" into a string, how do I parse this to store the numbers in an int variable. In addition, all I really need is the third pair of numbers in that string(from the left) and I was also wondering how to skip the first two and last pair of numbers in that string. I have read on delimiters but I'm a little confused on how to use them. The code I have so far is shown below and is basically that information to strings.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int arr[25];


    ifstream File;
    File.open("input.txt");

    for (int a = 0; a < 25; a++)
    {
        File >> arr[a];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    { 
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    string license, datetime;
    File >> license >> datetime; // reads in license plate and datetime information into two separte strings
    cout << license << endl << datetime;


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please use either Stack Overflow's search feature or Google. there are answers all over the place on how to read integers and convert strings to integers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

Comment: He asks a specific case of parsing some part of string to int not the whole string.

Comment: Yes as erol said, I want only part of that string and not the whole thing. Also that example contains a string of purely numbers from what I can see and mine includes colons to account for which is why I was thinking of using delimiters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Background:**
If we know the start and end indices (or the length) of the sub-string we need, then we can read it by using `std::string::substr`.

Its usage is as follows:

```
#include <string>

...

std::string foo = "0123456789stack:overflow";

// start index = 4, length = 2
std::string subStr1 = foo.substr(4,2); // result = "45"

// start index = 3, end index = 5 => length = 5 - 3 + 1 = 3
std::string subStr2 = foo.substr(3,3); // result = "345"
// The first parameter is the start index whereas the second one is 
// the length of the wanted sub-string. 

// If only the start index is known:
std::string subStr2 = foo.substr(9); //  result = "9stack:overflow"
// In that case we get the rest of the string starting from the start index 9.
```

For more information on that please refer to: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

**Suggested solution to the OP:**
Since you said "all I really need is the third pair of numbers" then you need two characters starting from index 6:

```
std::string a  = "01:01:05:59";

std::string sub = a.substr(6, 2); // will give you "05"
```

then convert them using:

```
int number = std::stoi(sub);
```

These steps can be shortened to:

```
int number = std::stoi( a.substr(6, 2) );
```

Further references:

First part: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Second part: [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

PS: if you want to use character `array` instead of `std::string` then you just can get the characters with their corresponding indices. For example: `i = 6` and `i = 7` in your specific case. Then, get `yourArray[6]=0` and `yourArray[7]=5`. Then perform integer conversion on them.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do:
`int num = std::stoi(string.substr(6, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

> assuming I have read `"01:01:05:59"` into a string

One easy way is using streams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int n[4];
    std::istringstream iss("02:30:41:28");
    if (iss >> n[0] && iss.get() == ':' &&
        iss >> n[1] && iss.get() == ':' &&
        iss >> n[2] && iss.get() == ':' &&
        iss >> n[3] >> std::ws && iss.eof())
        std::cout << n[0] << ' ' << n[1] << ' ' << n[2] << ' ' << n[3] << '\n';
    else
        std::cerr << "parsing error\n";
}
```

On [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/MkAsLu)

Comment: That`s another nice way of doing it. Vote up for you!