# Convert string to unsigned short int C++ in uEFI

Tags: c++, string, casting, type-conversion, uefi

I want to convert a string to unsigned short int.

Below is the code:

```
unsigned short int file2[3072]={0};
string file1;
file1="hello";
```

Not sure how to proceed further.Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: C++ in uEFI environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

Comment: Updated title and tags with language.

Comment: What value do you expect to get after converting the string "hello" to unsigned short?