# Load variable from string

Tags: c++

How should i go about loading a variable from a string?:
for example, this is my text file:

*int: 10

int: 25

int: 30*

How could i load these into a array? this is the code i use to load the strings:

```
string loadedB[100];
ifstream loadfile;
loadfile.open("ints.txt");

if(!loadfile.is_open()){
    MessageBoxA(0, "Could not open file!","Could not open file!", MB_OK);
    return;
}

string line; int i = -1;
while(getline(loadfile, line)){ i++;
    loadedB[i] = line;
}
loadfile.close();

for(int x = 0; x < count(loadedB); x++){
    cout << loadedB[x] << endl;
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
int intarray[100];   
loadfromstringarray(loadedB, intarray);
```

That code would take the part of the string ( the numeric one ) and would put that value into the array, like `intarray[0] = 10;` and so on

EDIT: istringstream is the solution!

Comment: You want a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Comment: But then the question is, how does he convert the stringstream data into individual ints? std::stoi() can work with your existing approach - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, that's what i was looking for!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194465/34255360)

Comment: @CorneliusAurel Glad to help. You're well encouraged to write your own answer here showing the now working code, instead of stating that your problem was solved in your question. You should note that the site is primarily about building a FAQ like repository, rather providing a personal help desk.

Comment: @CorneliusAurel If you're accepting that `istringstream` is the answer please accept [Thomas Matthews' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37355396/2642059)

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the good old `std::istringstream` object:

```
const std::string  example = "int: 10";
std::string prompt;
int value;
std::istringstream parse_stream(example);
std::getline(parse_stream, prompt, ':');
parse_stream >> value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the good old sscanf C function:

```
int intarray[100];
int i = 0;
while(getline(loadfile, line) && i < sizeof(intarray)/sizeof(*intarray))
{
    sscanf(line.c_str(), "int: %d", intarray + i++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
vector<int> ints;
ifstream loadfile("ints.txt");

string line;
while(getline(loadfile, line)) {
    ints.push_back(stoi(line.substr(5))); // skip the first 5 chars of each line
}

for(int i : ints) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
10
25
30
```