# Parse string containing numbers into integers

Tags: c++, string, parsing

How can I parse numbers 4648, 4649, 4650 from this string into three int variables without using regex.h?

```
* SEARCH 4648 4649 4650
a3 OK SEARCH completed
```

Comment: Wasn't this just asked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `std::istringstream`:

```
static const std:string    test_string = "* SEARCH 4648 4649 4650";
char asterisk;
std::string label;
unsigned int value1, value2, value3;
std::istringstream input(test_string);
input >> asterisk >> label >> value1 >> value2;
```

**Edit 1:**
For inputing more than one number:

```
input >> asterisk >> label;
std::vector<unsigned int> numbers;
unsigned int value;
while (input >> value)
{
  numbers.push_back(value);
}
```

Comment: I can't determinate how many numbers there will be.

The string can be like this "* SEARCH 454 446 456 45645 46465"

Comment: If you don't know how many numbers, then use `std::vector` and a while loop, such as `while (input >> value) { number_vector.push_back(value);}`.

Comment: Can you add all code please?

Comment: Added code for inputting more than one value.