# C++ splitting string input into two ints

Tags: c++, string, parsing, fractions

How do I split a `string` input into two different `int`s?

I am writing a program to input two different fractions (like `2/3`) and am wanting to read in the `2/3` as a string and split it by a delimiter (the `/`).

Example:

```
Input: 2/3
Values:
int num = 2;
int denom = 3;
```

Example 2:

```
Input: 11/5
Values:
int num = 11;
int denom = 5;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well you can do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c to split the string and you can do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c  to convert the strings to an int.

Comment: For simple tasks you can do this `int a, b;  char c; std::cin >> a >> c >> b;`

Comment: I forgot to add that you can use `stringstream` object instead `cin`

Answer (score 1):

For something quite simple like "2/3" you could use [string.find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and [string.substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

[string.find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) will return the position in your string that the '/' character resides. You can then use [string.substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to split the string both before and after the '/' character. Don't have time to write a code example but if you're really stuck, PM me and I'll knock something up when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following with the -std=c++ 11 flag specified if using g++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void find_num_denom(int& num, int& denom, std::string input) {
    int slash_index = input.find("/");
    num = std::stoi(input.substr(0, slash_index));
    denom = std::stoi(input.substr(slash_index + 1, input.length()));
}

int main() {
    int n,d;
    find_num_denom(n, d, "23/52");
    std::cout<<n<<"  "<<d<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

this returns 23   52 for me. Let me know if you have any problems