# How can I change Char digits to integer value

Tags: c++, function, c-strings

Since I am a newbie in this c++ programming. I kind a confuse with this question. If there is "const char str[]", How can I return this with integer value ??

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        n = rand () % 98 + 1;

        str [i] = n + '0';
    }
```

Do I have to do str[i] = n -'0' ?
How can I return this character digit with integer value ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: you just do the oppisite direction,  instead of doing n + '0' in your for loop you will do n - '0'

Comment: Offtopic : Your rand for this function might be wrong,
Ontopic: do another for loop and - '0' in the other function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if str is declared as a `const char[]` it means that the content of str is constant. Therefore you cannot modify it.
You could try to `const_cast` str, but it is usually a bad idea.

Secondly you can simply convert a `char` to an `int` by assigning your `char` variable to an `int`variable.

```
char c = 'a';
int c_value = c;
```

You can find more inforation about const-correcteness [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness), and about type-casting [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).