# How to parse serial data into int values

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to ideally send a few bytes of serial data from a computer to an Arduino. There has to be a better way than what I have chosen to do but my experience with serial data sent byte by byte and c++ is limited. I want to append each byte to definable variable values that are multiple bytes long. for example if the first 3 bytes of a serial stream are '3', '5', and '7' I want that to read as a single int of value 357. I am using Serial.readBytesUntil.

I have tried using Serial.readStringUntil() but I was having the same problem but converting string type to an integer. I feel like there is an easier way than what I am doing.

```
size_t input = Serial.readBytesUntil('\r', sentdata, sizeof(sentdata)-1);
dist[0] = sentdata[0];
dist[1] = sentdata[1];
dist[2] = sentdata[2];
dist[3] = sentdata[3];
distance = dist[0]*1000 + dist[1]*100 + dist[2]*10 + dist[3];
```

distance should equal any number sent from 0000 to 9999. just as an fyi this value is related to steps performed by a stepper motor.

Comment: ... so, you are sending ascii? othrwise it wouldn't make sence to use a whole byte to send [0,9]

Comment: I believe I am using utf-8 as python .encode() defaults to that. Should I be doing something else?

Comment: Ah, yes. Well, a safe and common way is to send data, also numbers as fixed-width character data.  The thing with UTF-8 is, is not fixed width. So you don't know how many bytes you are sending. 8-bit ASCII is a good alternative for simple data. Then, basically what you are receiving can be put in a string, but, your way also works (although ascii values are not converted like that). Note: if you need high performance you should only do binary data.

Comment: So if I use 8-bit ASCII how would that work in terms of outputs for sentdata and would that change how I transmit the data as well or would I just say .encode("ascii")?

Comment: First you must agree on a way to know if you have collected all data of a specific value (since it's split up). As for the conversion: here are the numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Okay but it seems that even with ascii conversion I would somehow have to append the digits together to form a single integer and I am back at the same starting point.

Comment: Your main error seems to be that you don't appreicate that the ASCII (or UTF-8) value of a digit is not the same as it's numerical value. The code you've written above should be `distance = (dist[0]-'0')*1000 + (dist[1]-'0')*100 + (dist[2]-'0')*10 + (dist[3]-'0');` By subtracting `'0'` from each digit you convert it's ASCII value to it's numerical value.

Comment: You can either do your calculation, which is fine (but do take the ascii `0`value into account). Or convert your input into a string and do [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) which is similar to your conversion.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you. I guess I will make the changes about the ascii 0 value but leave the line otherwise unchanged.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Serial.parseInt()`?

Comment: Because of the encoding in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a string to an int in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c)